# Colocar retorno de método antes de um bloco "finally"

Tags: java, exceção, return, controle-de-fluxo, try-finally

Considerando:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Parte 1");
    return false;
} finally {
    System.out.println("Parte 2");
}
```

Qual vai ser o *output* e o que acontece por baixo dos panos para que o *output* saia dessa forma?

Comment: Tem certeza que essa é a pergunta que você deseja fazer? Não seria algo como perguntar por que isso acontece, por exemplo?

Comment: @Piovezan, concordo, mas creio que seja tarde demais para alterar a pergunta neste nível.

Comment: Discordo. Se vc alterar, daí sim as resposta farão sentido, pois elas já respondem isso mesmo sem vc ter colocado em sua pergunta. Do jeito que ela está, está muito pobre.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A intenção do `finally` é garantir que este bloco seja executado em qualquer circunstância (a não ser que toda plataforma tenha algum comportamento catastrófico, claro, ou por um `System.exit()`). Então não importa o que aconteça no método, ele será executado. Não importa se ele vai sair por `return` ou `throw`.

Então a saída será:

```
Parte 1
Parte 2
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/psfr3x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/wphckhmg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Finally.java).

[Documentação](https://web.archive.org/web/20150222093101/https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html).

## Reescrita

Este bloco é reescrito pelo compilador (é algo parecido com isto, em C# é assim). Ficaria algo assim:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Parte 1");
} finally {
    System.out.println("Parte 2");
}
return false;
```

Já

```
try {
    System.out.println("Parte 1");
    return false;
} finally {
    System.out.println("Parte 2");
    return true;
}
```

Será transformado em:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Parte 1");
} finally {
    System.out.println("Parte 2");
}
return true;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Return.java).

Note que a execução de um `finally` tem precedência quando as instruções são conflituosas. Se houver um `return` dentro de um `catch`, será precedente ao `return` do `try` mas perderá para o `finally`.

## Conclusão

De qualquer forma há a garantia da execução. A implementação real não é importante já que ela poderia mudar. O importante é saber que **há a garantia da execução do bloco `finally` antes de sair do método**, portanto antes do `return` do `try`. Evidentemente se houver alguma expressão no `return` ela será salva em variável temporária para evitar a execução no momento errado na reordenação das instruções.

Answer (score 5):

O output vai ser:

```
Parte 1
Parte 2
```

E em seguida `false` vai ser retornado.

O bloco `finally` executa sempre que o bloco `try` termina, mesmo se ele tiver lançado uma exceção, retornado, abortado um laço ou qualquer coisa assim.

Internamente, a JVM salva o valor retornado em uma variável local que ela inventa para isso, executa o `finally` e depois retorna o valor da variável local. Ela faz o mesmo para exceções.

Comment: Qualquer coisa assim menos um `System.exit()`.

Comment: @Piovezan Sim, `System.exit()` é o grande botão vermelho. Mas neste caso, o bloco `try` nem mesmo chega a terminar.