# Ao utilizar recursão método retorna 0

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, método, recursão

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
public int lerInt() {
    String entrada = "";
    int saida = 0;
    try {
        entrada = input.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Falha critica.");
    }
    try {
        saida = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Você digitou uma entrada invalida.");
        lerInt();
    }
    return saida;
}
```

Supondo que o usuário digite algo com letra, ele cairia no `NumberFormatException` e teria que digitar de novo. Porém na segunda tentativa o método retorna 0, independente do número que ele digitar.

Eu precisava que ele fosse executado até o usuário digitar algo valido, e não sei porque ele está retornando 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem alguns problemas no seu código.

Eu criei a variável `input` aí no método mesmo, você deve ter criado em outro lugar. Pode até ter algum motivo para você ter feito isto, mas eu acho que dentro do método é o melhor lugar para declarar esta variável. Não vejo sentido em criar fora dele algo que parece ser usado só dentro dele. Use melhor o escopo.

Haviam variáveis desnecessárias. O código é mais simples. A única coisa que você precisava fazer era **tentar** retornar uma valor inteiro convertido dos caracteres lidos no teclado.

Se essa tentativa falha ela vai tentar executar algum `catch`. Não necessariamente estes dois listados aí, poderia ser algum outro `catch` no *call stack* da sua aplicação (inclusive o `catch` oculto que toda aplicação Java tem para proteger sua aplicação de qualquer exceção não tratada).

Normalmente você só usa um único bloco de `try` nessas situações. Você coloca quantos `catch`es forem necessários para dar o tratamento correto para cada erro que você sabe como tratar.

Se der um destes dois problemas indicados pelo seu código ao invés de retornar o resultado, antes de concluir o `return` ele vai desviar para um dos blocos que sabem como tratar o problema. No caso ambos apenas mostram a mensagem personalizada indicando para o usuário o que ocorreu de errado.

Como isto está dentro de um *loop* todo o processo será tentado novamente. No momento que deu tudo certo o `return` é executado até o fim sem um desvio para um `catch`, então o método é finalizado com o resultado adequado.

Este `while` é chamado *loop* infinito. Será executado até que seja verdadeiro e eu estou dizendo que é verdadeiro sempre. Mesmo ele sendo infinito, é claro que existe um meio de escapar dele, que no caso é o `return`.

Eu fiz ele um pouco diferente:

```
public int lerInt() {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Falha critica.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Você digitou uma entrada invalida.");
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/OKg35I). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jvmktkxl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Typing/Validation.java).

Note que sua tentativa de fazer recursão do método `lerInt()` pode trazer problemas de estouro da pilha em casos extremos de muitos dados inválidos. [Raramente recursão é a solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101).

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42313/101) deve te interessar. Ela explica melhor sobre o uso do `return` antes de um `finally` que é praticamente a mesma coisa de um `catch`.

Comment: eu criei o input na classe, tem outros metodos que utilizam ele. e não posso criar o metodo estatico (até queria) por causa de UML

Comment: seu código funcionou mas até agora não entendi o `while (true)`. até o que ser verdadeiro?

Comment: Eu coloquei `static`só para testar. Não importa se você vai usar essa variável em outro lugar, a não ser que explique porque precisa disto não faz sentido ter ela compartilhada por toda classe. Um `while` espera um `true` ou `false`, você não precisa comparar nada com "alguma coisa" para obter esses valores. E por favor, nunca compare "alguma coisa" com `true` ou `false`, se essa "alguma coisa" já é um tipo booleano, use essa "alguma coisa" direto.

Comment: olhei melhor e entendi o que aconteceu. mas apesar de agora eu ter percebido que minha abordagem não era correta não entendi porque ele retornava 0, o metodo não deveria retornar o que aconteceu na ultima recursão?

Comment: Não, ele deveria retornar o que executou na primeira execução. A última e todas as outras estão sendo jogadas fora pelo seu código. Talvez um `return lerInt();` conseguisse o que você quer mas eu não arriscaria.