# Return dentro do try... catch não funciona

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, try-catch

Fiz esse método:

```
public int VerificaUltimaAnalise()
        {
            //Desenvolvimento
            WFExecutor vcmpExecutor = null;
            WFAnalise vcmpAnalise = null;
            Core vmpaCore = null;
            int vintCdTransacao = 0;
            int vintCdProxProcesso = 0;
            int vintCdAnalise = 0;

            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializalções
                vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();
                vcmpAnalise = new WFAnalise();
                vmpaCore = (Core)Page.Master;

                //Desenvolvimento
                //vintCdTransacao = vcmpExecutor.ConsultarTransacao(Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

                vintCdProxProcesso = vcmpAnalise.ProximoProcessoAnalise(vintCdTransacao, int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value), ref vintCdAnalise);

                return vintCdProxProcesso;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
                Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

E em design ainda, me dá esse erro:

> Not all code paths return a value

Isso sempre acontece quando eu tento um return dentro de um bloco try... catch. O que devo fazer para resolver isso?

Comment: A função exige um retorno. Dentro do try você tem um, mas caso caia no erro e entre no catch você não tem retorno. Por isso o erro.

Comment: **Relacionado:** [not all code paths return a value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202124/3635)

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar [Para que servem os Blocos Try/Catch e quando devem ser utilizados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58536/para-que-servem-os-blocos-try-catch-e-quando-devem-ser-utilizados/424523#424523)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema é a falta de um `return`. Você deve fazê-lo no `catch` também, assim se houver uma exceção um `return` sempre será executado. Na forma atual o `return` só será executado se nenhuma falha ocorrer. Isto é inconsistente. De acordo com a assinatura do método ele sempre deverá retornar algo, mesmo que aconteça uma falha.

A tradução da mensagem de erro já ilustra o problema "nem todos os caminhos retornam um valor". Lembre-se que o `try-catch` é um controle de fluxo, ele desvia a execução do código, ele cria caminhos diferentes de execução de acordo com os acontecimentos.

Provavelmente você deseja retornar nada, assim:

```
public int VerificaUltimaAnalise() {
    //Desenvolvimento
    WFExecutor vcmpExecutor = null;
    WFAnalise vcmpAnalise = null;
    Core vmpaCore = null;
    int vintCdTransacao = 0;
    int vintCdProxProcesso = 0;
    int vintCdAnalise = 0;
    try {
        //Instâncias e Inicializalções
        vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();
        vcmpAnalise = new WFAnalise();
        vmpaCore = (Core)Page.Master;
        //Desenvolvimento
        //vintCdTransacao = vcmpExecutor.ConsultarTransacao(Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));
        vintCdProxProcesso = vcmpAnalise.ProximoProcessoAnalise(vintCdTransacao, int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value), ref vintCdAnalise);
        return vintCdProxProcesso;
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
        Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
        Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/ReturnOnTryCatch.cs).

Só lembrando que [capturar `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) não costuma ser uma boa ideia na maior parte dos casos.

[Sugestão de leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42317/101).

Comment: Queria saber o erro que tem na resposta para merecer um -1.

Answer (score 5):

Isto acontece porque o código pode nunca chegar ao `return` de fato. Usando seu próprio código, por exemplo:

```
        try
        {
            //Instâncias e Inicializalções
            vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();
            vcmpAnalise = new WFAnalise();
            vmpaCore = (Core)Page.Master;

            // Suponha que ocorra uma exceção na linha abaixo:
            vintCdProxProcesso = vcmpAnalise.ProximoProcessoAnalise(vintCdTransacao, int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value), ref vintCdAnalise);

            return vintCdProxProcesso;
        }
```

Comentei uma linha no seu código. Repare que se ocorrer exceção nessa linha, o programa vai direto para o `catch`, e seu `catch` não possui instrução de retorno de coisa alguma:

```
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
            Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Tem duas maneiras de resolver:

## 1. Colocando um `return` em `try` e outro em `catch`

Por exemplo:

```
    public int VerificaUltimaAnalise()
    {
        //Desenvolvimento
        WFExecutor vcmpExecutor = null;
        WFAnalise vcmpAnalise = null;
        Core vmpaCore = null;
        int vintCdTransacao = 0;
        int vintCdProxProcesso = 0;
        int vintCdAnalise = 0;

        try
        {
            //Instâncias e Inicializalções
            vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();
            vcmpAnalise = new WFAnalise();
            vmpaCore = (Core)Page.Master;

            //Desenvolvimento
            //vintCdTransacao = vcmpExecutor.ConsultarTransacao(Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

            vintCdProxProcesso = vcmpAnalise.ProximoProcessoAnalise(vintCdTransacao, int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value), ref vintCdAnalise);

            return vintCdProxProcesso;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
            Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

## 2. Colocando um `return` na última linha de execução da função ou método

```
    public int VerificaUltimaAnalise()
    {
        //Desenvolvimento
        WFExecutor vcmpExecutor = null;
        WFAnalise vcmpAnalise = null;
        Core vmpaCore = null;
        int vintCdTransacao = 0;
        int vintCdProxProcesso = 0;
        int vintCdAnalise = 0;

        try
        {
            //Instâncias e Inicializalções
            vcmpExecutor = new WFExecutor();
            vcmpAnalise = new WFAnalise();
            vmpaCore = (Core)Page.Master;

            //Desenvolvimento
            //vintCdTransacao = vcmpExecutor.ConsultarTransacao(Request.Path.Substring(Request.Path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1));

            vintCdProxProcesso = vcmpAnalise.ProximoProcessoAnalise(vintCdTransacao, int.Parse(hdfCdUsuario.Value), ref vintCdAnalise);

            return vintCdProxProcesso;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Mensagem = (wucMensagens)Page.Master.FindControl("wucMasterMensagens");
            Mensagem.ExibirMensagem(wucMensagens.TipoAlerta.Erro, Ex.Source, Ex.Message, Ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Sem entrar no mérito do padrão que você escolheu para tratar exceções...

Você limpou a exceção no **catch**, então o método sempre executará com sucesso.

Como é uma função, ela exige um retorno. Para resolver o erro de compilação, inclua um **return** dentro do **catch** retornando um valor padrão.

Answer (score -1):

Insira um bloco Finally:

```
Finally
{
 return vintCdProxProcesso;
}
```

Como o Finally, o código sempre passará por esse trecho, em caso de sucesso ou falha, como sua variável foi inicializada com zero, então você terá o retorno int esperado pelo método.

Espero ter ajudado!!!

Comment: Se for analisar estritamente erro de sintaxe como fizeram com a outra resposta negativada, esta também. Em C#, a linguagem da pergunta, não há palavra chave `Finally` (note o maiúsculo).

Comment: Nao e' possivel retornar dentro do corpo de um bloco `finally`.

Answer (score -3):

Coloca um

```
finaly{
   return retorno
}
```

Isso faz com que sempre retorne algo mesmo que seja `null`.

Comment: A sua resposta está errada por faltar o `;` e um `l` no `finally` mas é um grande exagero de quem deu -1 por isto, bastava avisar para consertar. Eu só não consertei porque não gosto de alterar conteúdo em resposta, apesar que tenho certeza que a sua intenção era ter colocado. De qualquer forma da maneira colocada ficou faltando um contexto maior. Talvez negativaram também porque já tem uma resposta igual. Também acho o motivo injusto, mas sei lá o que se passa na cabeça de cada um.

Comment: Nao e' possivel retornar dentro do corpo de um bloco `finally`.