# Pra que serve o finally no PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch, try-finally

O PHP 5.5 implementou um recurso (que eu já ouvi falar que existe em outras linguagens) chamado `finally`, no tratamento de exceções (juntamente com o `try/catch`)

Temos o seguinte exemplo:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline); 

});

try{

    $b = (new stdClass)->non_exists; // gera um erro de propósito

} catch(Exception $e) {

 echo  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL; // imprime a mensagem da captura da exceção

} finally {

   echo 'acabou!'; // imprime "acabou" (indepentende de entrar no catch ou não
}
```

Na prática, em quê poderia ser útil utlizar o `finally`? (pois não entendo porque ele é executado mesmo quando não cai no `catch`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essencialmente é para garantir que o fluxo daquele bloco sempre seja executado. Mesmo que ocorra um exceção no bloco iniciado pelo `try`, o bloco do `finally` será executado antes de  sair da função e começar derrubar a pilha de chamadas de funções.

Em geral ele é usado para encerrar recursos alocados, por exemplo fechar um arquivo.

Pode surgir aí uma dúvida de qual é a diferença para o `catch` que também é executado quando há uma exceção. A diferença é que o `catch` só é executado quando há a exceção. O `finally` é executado com ou sem exceção. O fluxo de execução do programa vai do `try` para o `finally` sempre, seja por que o `try` encerrou normalmente, seja porque ele gerou uma exceção. O `catch` é um bloco de execução condicionada (pelo lançamento de uma exceção), o `finally` é de execução obrigatória.

Lembrando que **o lançamento de uma exceção** forçará a execução tanto do bloco do `catch`, quanto do `finally`, mas qualquer código que venha depois do todo esse bloco `try-catch-finally` nada será executado.

Talvez passe uma impressão de pouca utilidade dele por causa de exemplos que não fazem nada útil efetivamente.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Bom exemplo genérico:

```
    $recurso = abrir_recurso();
    try {
        $resultado = use_rercurso($rercurso);
    } finally {
        libere_rercurso($rercurso); //acontecendo ou não uma exceção, o recurso será fechado
    }
    return $resultado;
```

Exemplo real retirado [desse *blog*](http://sheriframadan.com/2012/08/finally-keyword-in-php/):

```
function addRecord($record, $db) {
    try {
      $db->lock($record->table);
      $db->prepare($record->sql);
      $db->exec($record->params);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $db->rollback($record);
        if (!write_log($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString())) {
            throw new Exception('Unable to write to error log.');
        }
    } finally {
        $db->unlock($record->table);
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Exception/Finally.php).

O exemplo é [ruim porque captura `Exception`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/30168/101) e lança de novo mas a ideia geral é esta.

[Sugestão de leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48032/101). Não é a mesma linguagem mas funciona da mesma forma.

Comment: +1. faz sentido. Por isso é que eu tinha visto um exemplo tratando de uma escrita de um `log`, onde o finally finaliza a abertuda do arquivo

Comment: "talvez passa uma impressão ruim dele por causa de exemplos que não fazem nada útil" me lembra a resposta que você deu quando perguntei do `Array Dereferencing`. O Manual do PHP tinha que mostrar de uma forma onde ele poderia ser usado para uma refatoração (ou uma simplificação, talvez)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o manual do PHP é bem malfeito. E a versão em português é medonha.

Comment: nos meus testes, depois do `finally`, o código foi executado normalmente.  Foi isso mesmo que eu entendi? _" mas qualquer código que venha depois do todo esse bloco try-catch-finally nada será executado"_ ?

Comment: Veja se a ênfase ajuda entender melhor. No seu caso **não** houve lançamento de uma exceção, então o resto do código será executado normalmente.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Detalhe importante é que o `finally` é executado _sempre_. Mesmo se você der um `return` dentro do bloco `catch` o return será executado depois do código em `finally`.

Comment: "Em geral ele é usado para encerrar recursos alocados, por exemplo fechar um arquivo."+1

Answer (score 4):

**Try** => É o bloco de comando que você quer executar

**Catch** = > É o bloco de comando que executar caso aconteça algum erro (Exception). Você Pode Tratar várias `exceptions`. `Catch` só será executado quando ocorre uma exceção.

**finally** = > Como `catch` é o bloco que executa somente quando ocorre uma exceção, o bloco `finally` sempre vai executar, independente de erro. 
Uma boa utilidade de `finally` é fechar conexão com o banco de dados.