# Para que serve o "with" no Python?

Tags: python, with

Estou dando uma estudada no Python e me deparei com esse tal de `with`.

Conheço ele do JavaScript. Porém,  não sei como ele funciona no Python.

A maioria dos exemplos que vi mostram ele sendo usado em leitura de arquivos.

Exemplo:

```
with open("my_file.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    # faça algo com "data"
```

Comment: Conheço pouco Python, mas tá com cara de ser como o `using` do C#, que libera o recurso automaticamente no fim do bloco.

Comment: tava pensando a mesma coisa, parece o using.

Comment: @Solkarped Antes de continuar com as edições (vi que vc fez um monte), por favor leia [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7387/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7293/112052). Basicamente, só edite se de fato tiver melhorias substanciais a serem feitas (no caso, mudar "mas" para "porém" não se encaixa nesse critério: não melhora - nem piora - o entendimento da pergunta; se for pra mudar **só** isso, por favor não edite).

Comment: @hkotsubo, boa tarde! Entendido suas observações. Forte abraço!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Ele é usado para garantir finalização de recursos adquiridos.

Um arquivo, por exemplo é aberto. Quem garante que ele será fechado? Mesmo que você coloque no código de forma explícita que ele deve ser fechado, se ocorrer uma exceção, o código sai de escopo sem executar o resto do código que está em escopo, ele pula o fechamento.

Para evitar isto usamos um `try finally`. O `finally` garante a finalização. Como o código fica um pouco longo e este caso é bastante frequente a linguagem providenciou uma forma simplificada com o `with`.

Ele consegue manipular objetos que contenham os métodos [`__enter__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__) e [`__exit__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__). Eles são chamados internamente logo no início da execução do bloco criado e dentro do `finally` interno criado no bloco.

No exemplo citado deve ficar algo parecido com isto internamente:

```
try:
    __enter__()
    open("my_file.txt") as file:
        data = file.read()
        #faça algo com "data"
finally:
    __exit__()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/WithUnderlying.py).

Certamente dentro do `__exit__()` tem um `close()` para fechar o arquivo.
Sobre o `finally` você já sabe como funciona de acordo com [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48279/101) feita anteriormente. O funcionamento em PHP e Python como em quase qualquer linguagem que tenha esse recurso é praticamente idêntico.

Para ajudar o que foi falado nos comentários, é análogo mas não idêntico ao comando [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) do C# e VB.NET (não confundir com a diretiva) ou `try ()` *with resources* do Java (não confundir com o `try` normal).

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Ajudou pra caramba!

Comment: os métodos `__enter__` e `__exit__` chamados são do objeto `file`, não "soltos".

Comment: Então é basicamente o `try-with-resources` do Java?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado isso mesmo, é o padrão *disposable* dele.

Comment: Ajudou pra caramba, muito obrigado irmão!

Answer (score 29):

O comando `with` serve para facilitar a escrita de qualquer bloco de código que envolva recursos que precisam ser "finalizados" (isso é, restaurados, liberados, fechados, etc... ) depois que o bloco for encerrado - e ele permite que isso seja feito de forma automática, com a lógica de finalização dentro do objeto utilizado.

Então primeira coisa: o código de finalização do  `with` sempre é executado - não importa se um erro ocorreu dentro do bloco do `with` ou não.

Mas isso já podia ser feito com o bloco `finally` e uma cláusula `try...finally` - não importa o resultado do bloco dentro do `try`, o `finally` sempre é executado.

O grande diferencial do `with` é que o programador que está *usando* os objetos que precisam de finalização não tem que se preocupar em chamar esses métodos explicitamente.

No caso de um arquivo, em geral as pessoas sabem que tem que ser chamado o  `close` - mas o mais comum, como já se usa o `close` é que ninguém acaba programando um trecho que manipula arquivo com  chamada ao `close`, sem usar o `with` lembrando de colocar isso dentro de um `finally`. Ou seja, o `with` de cara incentiva o código a ser escrito de forma que se comporte da forma correta:

jeito errado:

```
f = open("data.txt", "w")
# codigo usando o arquivo f
f.close()
```

jeito certo, sem o with:

```
try:
   f = open("data.txt", "w")
   # codigo usando o arquivo f
finally:
   f.close()
```

jeito certo com o with (recomendado):

```
with open("data.txt", "w") as f:
   # codigo usando o arquivo f
```

(o arquivo é fechado automaticamente ao final do bloco).

Então note que o código "certo" ainda fica uma linha mais curta que o jeito "errado".  Mas - como eu mencionei acima, o `close` de arquivos não é a coisa mais legal do `with` - por que todo mundo sabe e lembra do `close` (espero)  - mas é que para qualquer objeto que precise de uma finalização - locks de threads, transações de banco de dados, alterar o estado do terminal para ler teclas sem precisar do `<enter>`, monkey patch de funções e métodos em testes, o `with` executa a finalização de forma transparente - sem o usuário precisar saber se precisa chamar o método `close`, `release`, `undo` de cada objeto (na verdade, ele obriga os programadores das classes dos objetos que funcionam com with a implementarem uma interface comum, com os métodos `__enter__` e `__exit__`.

Mais ainda, quando você está programando suas próprias classes que vão poder ser usadas com `with` pode tratar dentro do seu código da função `__exit__` os erros mais comuns, ou esperados que poderiam acontecer no bloco: o método `__exit__` recebe informações sobre a exceção que ocorreu dentro do bloco, e o `__exit__` pode optar por tratar o erro e suprimir a exceção, ou simplesmente liberar o recurso e passar o erro pra frente: ou seja um monte de código que seria sempre o mesmo que alguém teria que escrever dentro da cláusula `except` **toda** vez que fosse usar o seu objeto pode ficar dentro do `__exit__` e as pessoas usarem seu objeto sem se preocupar com o código que iria dentro do `except`.

Segue um exemplo simples de uma "conta bancária" que faz operações temporárias com o saldo, mas só permite que as transações se efetivem no final do bloco do `with` se houver saldo positivo em todas as contas:

```
class ContaBancariaTransacional:
    def __init__(self, titular, saldo_inicial=0):
        self.titular = titular
        self.saldo = saldo_inicial

    def deposito(self, valor):
        self.temp += valor

    def retirada(self, valor):
        if self.saldo - self.temp - valor < 0:
            raise ValueError("Não há saldo suficiente")
        self.temp -= valor
        return valor

    def __enter__(self):
        self.temp = 0

    def __exit__(self, tipo_excecao, valor_excecao, traceback):
        if tipo_excecao is None:
            # Não ocorreu nenhum erro no bloco, e podemos
            # atualizar o saldo definitivo
            self.saldo += self.temp
        del self.temp

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"conta de {self.titular}. Saldo: {self.saldo:.02f}"

def transferir(conta1, conta2, valor):
    with conta1, conta2:

        conta2.deposito(conta1.retirada(valor))
```

E numa sessão interativa podemos ver:

```
In [96]: conta1 = ContaBancariaTransacional("João", 100)

In [97]: conta2 = ContaBancariaTransacional("José", 0)

In [98]: conta1, conta2
Out[98]: (conta de João. Saldo: 100.00, conta de José. Saldo: 0.00)

In [99]: transferir(conta1, conta2, 100)

In [100]: conta1, conta2
Out[100]: (conta de João. Saldo: 0.00, conta de José. Saldo: 100.00)

In [101]: transferir(conta1, conta2, 50)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
(...)

ValueError: Não há saldo suficiente

In [102]: conta1, conta2
Out[102]: (conta de João. Saldo: 0.00, conta de José. Saldo: 100.00)
```

**Disclaimer**: esse código não está completo para ser um "two phase transaction" - e na verdade, ele só funciona por que a conta de onde sai o saldo está *antes* no comando `with` - quando o `__exit__` da primeira conta é chamado, ele levanta a exceção, que então impede o aumento de saldo na conta2. Ademais, para colocar em produção seria bom ter algumas locks por thread nessa classe de Conta também, por mais de brinquedo que ela seja. Mas acredito que dê para ver como o `with` pode funcionar com classes definidas pelo próprio programador.

Agora, sem ser para transferência-  imagine que esse objeto "conta" é usado por um sistema que está dentro de uma máquina de saque (no caso o acesso ao objeto conta seria remoto, com algum protocolo de chamada remota de métodos, claro) - mas supondo-se uma biblioteca Pythonica  para operar o hardware da máquina - o código para saque poderia ser simplesmente:

```
def saque(atm, conta, valor):
    with conta:
        valor = conta.retirada(valor)
        atm.disponibilizar_notas(valor)
        atm.abrir_gaveta()
        atm.esperar(10)
        atm.fechar_gaveta()
        if not atm.gaveta_vazia():
            raise RuntimeError("Usuario nao retirou o dinheiro")
```

Pronto - se qualquer dos métodos que envolvem inclusive partes mecânicas da máquina der um erro, o saldo real da conta não é debitado. (Note que se não houver o valor desejado na conta,  o próprio método de retirada já aborta a transação)

Answer (score 18):

### Sintaxe

A sintaxe da declaração `with` é:

```
with EXPR as VAR:
    BLOCK
```

`with` e `as` são palavras reservadas da linguagem. `EXPR` é uma expressão arbitrária (mas não uma lista de expressões) e `VAR` é um alvo único para atribuição (um objeto, de forma simplificada). `VAR` não pode ser uma lista de variáveis separadas por vírgulas, mas pode ser uma lista de variáveis separadas por vírgulas entre parenteses (será explicado mais tarde). A parte `as VAR` é opcional, portanto a sintaxe abaixo continua válida:

```
with EXPR:
    BLOCK
```

A partir da versão 2.7 da linguagem é possível utilizar múltiplos gerenciadores de contextos:

```
with EXPR1 as VAR1, EXPR2 as VAR2:
    BLOCK
```

Que é análogo a criar declarações `with` aninhadas:

```
with EXPR1 as VAR1:
    with EXPR2 as VAR2:
        BLOCK
```

### Funcionamento

A ordem de execução é:

1. A expressão dada por `EXPR` é avaliada a fim de obter-se o gerenciador de contexto;
2. O método `__exit__` do gerenciador de contexto é carregado para uso futuro;
3. O método `__enter__` do gerenciador de contexto é chamado;
4. Se `VAR` estiver definida, é atribuido à `VAR` o retorno do método `__enter__`;
5. O bloco de código definido por `BLOCK` é executado;
6. O método `__exit__` é chamado. Se alguma exceção foi disparada por `BLOCK`, o tipo (*type*), valor (*value*) e informações de rastreamento (*traceback*) da exceção são passadas como parâmetro. Caso contrário, se `BLOCK` for executado sem gerar erros, for finalizado com as instruções `break`, `continue` ou `return`, o método `__exit__` será executado com os três parâmetros iguais a `None`.

A tradução mais próxima da primeira declaração acerca de seu funcionamento é:

```
# 1. A expressão é avaliada para obter o gerenciador de contexto:
mgr = (EXPR)

# 2. O método __exit__ é carregado
exit = type(mgr).__exit__

# 3. O método __enter__ é executado:
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)

exc = True
try:
    try:
        # 4. O retorno de __enter__ é atribuído a VAR:
        VAR = value

        # 5. O bloco de código é executado:
        BLOCK
    except:
        # Captura os erros ocorridos durante a execução de BLOCK:
        exc = False

        # 6. Executa o método __exit__ passando as informações de erro:
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
finally:
    # 6. Executa o método __exit__ passando None para os parâmetros:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

Os detalhes da execução podem variar conforme características dos objetos envolvidos.

Se a expressão dada em `EXPR` não possuir pelo menos um dos métodos `__enter__` e `__exit__`, uma exceção do tipo `AttributeError` será disparada, primeiro para `__exit__`, segundo para `__enter__`.

### Exemplo

Considere o exemplo:

```
class Foo (object):

    def __enter__ (self):
        print("Enter")
        return 1

    def __exit__ (self, exit, value, exc):
        print("Exit")

with Foo() as foo:
    print(foo)
```

A saída do código será:

```
Enter
1
Exit
```

> Código funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/0qboqJ).

A execução é a mesma que:

```
import sys

mgr = Foo()
exit = Foo.__exit__
value = Foo.__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        foo = value
        print(foo)
    except:
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
finally:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

> Código funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/R5zNgR).

Se o método `__enter__` retornar uma lista de valores:

```
class Foo (object):

    def __enter__ (self):
        print("Enter")
        return 1, 2, 3

    def __exit__ (self, exit, value, exc):
        print("Exit")
```

É possível atribuir à uma lista de variáveis separadas por vírgulas entre parenteses dentro da declaração do `with`:

```
with Foo() as (a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
```

A saída seria:

```
Enter
1 2 3
Exit
```

> Código funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/FjlZnd).

### Compatibilidade

A declaração de `with` foi adicionado na versão 2.5 da linguagem, porém, é necessário habilitá-la através do código:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

A partir da versão 2.6, a declaração já está habilitada por padrão. Versões anteriores à 2.5 não possuem suporte a esta declaração.

### Gerenciadores de Contexto

É possível, de forma prática, definir novos gerenciadores de contextos a partir da biblioteca `contextlib`, utilizando o decorador `contextmanager`.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tag(name):
    print("<%s>" % name)
    yield
    print("</%s>" % name)

with tag("h1"):
    print("Stack Overflow")
```

A saída gerada é:

```
<h1>
Stack Overflow
</h1>
```

O funcionamento é análogo considerando o que está antes de `yield` como o método `__enter__` e o que está após o método `__exit__` (apenas para mérito de resultado, mas NÃO são análogas).

### Exemplos

Os exemplos abaixos foram retirados da própria PEP 343, não são inteiramente funcionais, mas expressam muito bem o uso, embora não limitado somente a, da declaração em questão.

1. Quando o recurso utilizado necessita ser bloqueado no início da execução e liberado ao final da mesma:

   ```
   @contextmanager
   def locked(lock):
       lock.acquire()
       try:
           yield
       finally:
           lock.release()

   with locked(myLock):
       # Código executado com myLock bloqueado. O recurso será
       # liberado quando o bloco de código ser executado.
   ```
2. Quando é necessário que um arquivo aberto pelo programa seja fechado ao final do mesmo:

   ```
   @contextmanager
   def opened(filename, mode="r"):
       f = open(filename, mode)
       try:
           yield f
       finally:
           f.close()

   with opened("/etc/passwd") as f:
       for line in f:
           print line.rstrip()
   ```

> Este comportamento já é nativo da função `open` do Python.

3. Quando trabalhado com transações no banco de dados:

   ```
   @contextmanager
   def transaction(db):
       db.begin()
       try:
           yield None
       except:
           db.rollback()
           raise
       else:
           db.commit()
   ```
4. Quando você deseja redireciar temporariamente o alvo de saída:

   ```
   @contextmanager
   def stdout_redirected(new_stdout):
       save_stdout = sys.stdout
       sys.stdout = new_stdout
       try:
           yield None
       finally:
           sys.stdout = save_stdout

   with opened(filename, "w") as f:
       with stdout_redirected(f):
           print("Hello world") # Será escrito no arquivo filename
   ```

Outros exemplos podem ser encontrados nas outras respostas à esta pergunta, na PEP 343 ou em outras referências.

**Referências:**

[PEP 343 -- The "with" Statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

[Compound statements - The with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: Opa-  você aproveitar que est'tão completo e acrescentar o uso com mais de um objeto no bloco, separados por `,` no `with`.

Comment: O coamndo with também pode ser usado na forma `with object1 as var1, object2 as var2: ` - você pode documentar isso - e as versões a partir das quais isso é válido.

Comment: @jsbueno Saberia dizer do motivo do método `__exit__` ser carregado antes da execução? Seria para garantir que uma exceção seja disparada caso o método não esteja definido, prevenindo que o recurso seja *bloqueado* sem uma maneira de *desbloqueá-lo*?

Comment: toda a idéia do comando `with` é  a garantia de que o código dentro do `__exit__` será executado. Pra mim parece natural que o runtime do Python verifique se o método existe e é chamável antes de sequer chamar o `__enter__` de um objeto.