# Qual a finalidade do WITH?

Tags: python, with

Eu estou estudando um pouco de Python por aqui, e sempre me deparo com o comando `with`.

Procurei na documentação e em outros sites, li matérias em inglês e também acessei a uma resposta sobre este comando aqui mesmo, no [pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49238/para-que-serve-o-with-no-python), porém ainda não consegui entender a funcionalidade do comando.

Comment: O que especificamente você não entendeu? Tem que ser mais claro nesse ponto para evitar que seja fechada como duplicata.

Comment: @diegofm - tentei ser vem claro, a ponto de quase dizer que não entendi a função do comando :/

Comment: mais facil seria tirar a duvida no post original, via comentários, ou no chat da rede. Ou quando tiver mais pontos, oferecer um bonus na original na tentativa de atrair nova resposta. Sem saber qual parte você entendeu fica dificil ajudar. O máximo que consigo imaginar é que se deixasse as 2 abertas, teriamos respostas com a mesma informação nos 2 lugares. o @jsbueno chegou a postar uma aqui e removeu, talvez fosse o caso dele repostar lá. Se bem que ainda assim é a mesma coisa, mas com outras palavras (o que pode ser interessante como complemento)

Comment: @Bacco - Olha a data da pergunta original: perguntada: 2 anos, 2 meses atrás , se eu comentar lá, vai ser cerca de 1% de ser respondido de volta.

Comment: Não vejo onde essa sua estatistica muda a situação. E no caso do bonus, ele traz a questao para os destaques do site

Comment: Exatamente como o @Bacco disse, pode comentar para o autor da resposta se foi algo que não entendeu, se achar que poderia ter mais detalhes pode oferecer um bônus https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, se for algo muito especifico então ae sim poderia formular uma pergunta nova, mas no caso da pergunta atual não é algo especifico e sim dificuldade de entender o que já foi explicado. ;)

Comment: @Félix dado a data daquela resposta, estou tentando formular uma [nova](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/201171/5878). Veja se lhe é útil.

Comment: @Felix, se você deixar um comentário na resposta explicando o que não entendeu, o autor será notificado e terá a oportunidade de te responder. Se ele acabar editando-a para esclarecer os pontos que você teve dificuldade, ela volta pra frente do site e mais gente tem a oportunidade de vê-la, assim como seu comentário. Além disso, numa situação como a sua, você também poderia pegar trechos da resposta que não entendeu, colocar aqui e explicar porque eles não fazem sentido pra você.

Comment: (Eu escrevi a resposta que tinha iniciado aqui lá. Talvez esse mecanismo de criar uma pergunta duplicada para movimentar a original não seja tão ruim a ponto de ser cerceado. Essa pergunta está apagada, a questão original tem mais duas respostas, e estão todos felizes)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss - Muito obrigado pela explicação, com a sua explicação e do jsbueno eu compreendi o que eu estava penando para achar.

Comment: @jsbueno - Obrigado por tirar um tempo para poder formular uma resposta, como foi falado a cima, com a sua resposta e do Anderson eu pude compreender a funcionalidade do comando.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, não vai ajudar só a mim, mas a outros entusiastas também. O posto original estava com uma resposta muito vaga.

Comment: E de quebra ainda ganhei a medalha de "necromante" por ter feito pontos com uma resposta a uma pergunta de mais de 60 dias.   :-)