# Como escrever em um arquivo sem apagar as coisas antigas?

Tags: python, arquivo

Exemplo: no meu arquivo tem

```
joao
maria
carla
```

se eu usar:

```
arq = open('nomes.txt')
arq.write('jose')
arq.write('\n')
arq.close
```

ele vai apagar os anteriores que era joao, maria,como faço pra escrever sem apagar os anteriores do txt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passe como segundo parâmetro a *string* `'a'`, isso diz que você está abrindo o arquivo para atualizá-lo.

O segundo parâmetro da função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) é uma *string* que indica como o arquivo deve ser aberto, o mais comum é usar `w` que serve para escrita, truncando o arquivo, caso ele já exista, `r` para leitura do arquivo e `a` que serve para adicionar conteúdo ao arquivo.

Existem também os modos `r+`, `w+` e `a+`. Todos eles abrem o arquivo para **leitura e escrita**.

**`r+`**: abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita. O *stream* é posicionado no início do arquivo.

**`w+`**: abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita. O *stream* é posicionado no início do arquivo e o arquivo será criado caso não exista.

**`a+`**: abre o arquivo para leitura e escrita. O arquivo será criado caso não exista e o *stream* é posicionado no final do arquivo.

Seria legal também fazer uso do `with`.

Você pode ver mais sobre ele [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/18246)<sup>1</sup>.

```
with open('nomes.txt', 'a') as arq:
    arq.write('jose')
    arq.write('\n')
```

<sup>1</sup>[Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/18246)

Comment: Valeu!, isso mesmo que eu estava querendo.

Comment: Se importa de documentar os modos "w+" e "r+" de abrir um arquivo também? - sempre acho difícil de achar informação sobre abrir um arquivo para atualização a partir do começo ("r+"  ) e estar em um lugar a mais não faria mal.

Comment: @jsbueno Agradeço o _feedback_. Fiz a edição adicionando estes três modos de forma que não alongasse muito a resposta. Qualquer sugestão é bem-vinda.