# Como atualizar linhas com o open() em python?

Tags: python

o método open() do Python tem funções pra ler e escrever mas não tem para atualizar, como posso fazer?

Comment: Eu não entendi a sua pergunta. O que você quer dizer com "atualizar"? Por favor, você poderia ser mais claro na sua dúvida, e se possível colocar alguns exemplos na sua pergunta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como escrever em um arquivo sem apagar as coisas antigas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201303/como-escrever-em-um-arquivo-sem-apagar-as-coisas-antigas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A própria chamada ao método `write` pode atualizar arquivos de texto - o que acontece é que se o conteúdo do arquivo for "texto", é praticamente impossível mudar o seu conteúdo de forma que seja útil - o melhor é re-escrever o arquivo todo. Aqui eu explico bem o porque: [Como deletar um entrada de um arquivo Python sem precisar ler todo o arquivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266899/como-deletar-um-entrada-de-um-arquivo-python-sem-precisar-ler-todo-o-arquivo/266962#266962)

Agora, sim, para mudar o conteúdo de um arquivo existente sem re-escrever o arquivo todo, a chave é que o arquivo tem que ser aberto no modo `"r+b"`. Apesar do "r", normalmente usado para leitura, o caractere "+" muda o modo para "leitura e escrita". (poderia ser sem o "b", mas não faz sentido para arquivos de texto em que você não sabe a priori o tamanho que uma string terá em bytes no arquivo - quem vai fazer isso tem que ter controle completo sobre cada byte escrito e isso só é possível se você codificar o conteúdo manualmente - arquivos abertos no modo texto tem um passo transparente de codificação do texto em bytes que pode alterar o tamanho da string).

A chave para as mudanças é saber que dado um arquivo aberto em Python, ele existe como um "objeto" no sistema operacional, e o próprio sistema operacional mantém um "apontador" para a posição do arquivo onde será feita a escrita. Do lado do Python, ou de qualquer outra linguagem, além de `read` e `write`, um programa pode mudar a posição desse apontador usando o método `.seek`. Uma vez que o apontador esteja no ponto exato em que você quer escrever, você pode usar o `write`, e o número de bytes que você escrever vai sobre-escrever aquele exato tanto de bytes no arquivo.

Um exemplo rápido, vamos escrever os bytes que correspondem as letras maiúsculas "ABCD" num arquivo de 4 bytes, e mudar apenas a terceira letra "C" para "E" e ler de novo:

```
open("teste.bin", "wb").write(b"ABCD")
print(open("teste.bin", "rb").read().decode())
arq = open("teste.bin", "r+b")
arq.seek(2)
arq.write(b"E")
arq.close()
print(open("teste.bin", "rb").read().decode())
```

Quando eu colo essas linhas para sua execução imediata no modo interativo, temos:

```
>>> open("teste.bin", "wb").write(b"ABCD")
4
>>> print(open("teste.bin", "rb").read().decode())
ABCD
>>> arq = open("teste.bin", "r+b")
>>> arq.seek(2)
2
>>> arq.write(b"E")
1
>>> arq.close()
>>> print(open("teste.bin", "rb").read().decode())
ABED
>>>
```

Então dê uma olhada na documentação do "seek" - https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html para fazer mais experiências, mas enfatizo que você não deve usar essa abordagem em programas simples.

## Porque não fazer isso

Mesmo que seja possível alterar um único, ou poucos, bytes em um arquivo ja existente, é preferível recria-lo por inteiro.

Os dois motivos principais são: é difícil saber qual comprimento *texto* vai ter dentro de um arquivo, como expliquei acima. Mas principalmente não há nenhum ganho de recursos ou eficiência em fazer isso: você não economiza tempo, nem desgasta menos seu HD (ou SSD): mesmo que você altere um único byte em um arquivo, a menor unidade de escrita para o HD que o sistema operacional usa (seja Windows, LInux, Mac ou outro Unix) é um "bloco" - e esses blocos em geral tem 4KB (4096 bytes). Ou seja - mesmo na escrita de uma única letra "E" no meu exemplo acima, mesmo que o Python, e o runtime do Python (a parte em código nativo, escrito em C) tenham manipulado um único byte com o código da letra "E", quando foi feita a chamada ao "write", o sistema operacional obrigatoriamente executa esses passos:

1. lê todo o bloco do arquivo onde está o byte que vai ser alterado (4KB)
2. muda aquele único byte na memória
3. aloca no sistema de arquivos, um novo bloco
4. escreve o bloco inteiro (4KB - sendo 4 bytes de informação e 4092 bytes de lixo, nesse caso) na nova posição
5. altera as tabelas do sistema de arquivos de forma que o arquivo use o novo bloco escrito
6. retorna o controle do programa para o runtime do Python.

Tudo isso acontece de forma transparente para o programador, mesmo se fosse um programador C.

E por fim, há um terceiro motivo para não querer alterar um arquivo já existente: não dá para *inserir* conteúdo em um arquivo - você só pode sobre-escrever bytes que já estão lá. Se é um arquivo com 4 linhas de texto, e você quer inserir uma segunda linha, entre a primeira e a segunda(orignal), não tem nenhuma chamada do sistema para "empurrar" o restante do arquivo para frente, e colocar seus bytes novos naquela posição.

## Como alterar o conteúdo de um arquivo

A abordagem correta é para a *grande maioria* dos casos é:

1. ler todo o arquivo para a memória do computador
2. Alterar o conteúdo do arquivo na memória (aqui você tem várias formas diferentes de inserir conteúdo, trocar, sobre-escrever, etc...)
3. criar um novo arquivo e gravar o conteúdo alterado.

É claro que nos computadores atuais (e mesmo nos de 25 anos atrás), escrever milhares de bytes em um novo arquivo é **muito eficiente** - por isso não há perda de performance ao se fazer essa abordagem.

Se você desejar mais segurança para código em produção, pode, no momento de escrever o arquivo, em vez de criar um arquivo novo com o mesmo nome fazer:

1. criar um arquivo com um nome diferente
2. gravar o novo conteúdo
3. verificar que a gravação ocorreu sem problemas
4. apagar o arquivo antigo
5. renomear o arquivo novo para o nome do antigo

(Isso é bem fácil de fazer. Por exemplo, o passo de "verificar se foi tudo bem com a gravação", em Python é automático - se der algum problema na gravação o Python vai gerar uma exceção e seu código nem vai tentar apagar o arquivo antigo. As chamadas `os.unlink` e `os.rename` do módulo `os` permitem apagar o arquivo antigo  e renomear o arquivo novo).

O exemplo anterior fica assim:

```
import os
nome_original = "teste.txt"
arq.open(nome_original, "wt").write("ABCD")
conteudo = arq.open(nome_original).read()
novo_conteudo = conteudo[0:2] + "E" + conteudo[3:]
arq.open("nome_novo", "wt").write(novo_conteudo)
os.unlink(nome_original)
os.rename("nome_novo", nome_original)
```

## Por que você não precisa **mesmo** alterar um arquivo existente

Qualquer que seja sua aplicação, se você está tratando centenas de milhares (ou milhões de vezes mais que isso) de dados, e quer manter isso organizado, você não vai estar inventando essa organização do zero, em um arquivo seu: em geral você vai usar um Banco de Dados - que já faz exatamente isso - organiza esses dados da forma mais eficiente possível. Se as pessoas que estão há décadas desenvolvendo o sistema de banco de dados resolveram que para algumas situações é vantajoso mudar o conteúdo de um arquivo sem re-escrever o mesmo, o código pra isso está dentro do banco de dados, não no seu sistema.

Da mesma forma se você está trabalhando com arquivos grandes como imagem ou vídeo: você vai estar usando bibliotecas de acesso ao conteúdo desses arquivos - essas bibliotecas fazem a abstração pra você - tudo oque você vê são os dados de imagem descomprimidos na memória.

Para arquivos pequenos de texto (e nesse caso, "pequenos" é até uns 50MB), a abordagem de ler tudo pra memória e gravar tudo de volta funciona perfeitamente. (Mas, se você tem mais de 100KB de dados em arquivo texto, já é hora de pensar em migrar suas informações para um sistema de banco de dados de qualquer forma)

Comment: vlw, eu estava tentando usar o open como um mini banco de dados já que estou começando agr em python, vou tentar alguma opção como o sqlite