# Abrir vários arquivos com "with open"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

É possível abrir mais de arquivo em um programa com

```
with open("meutexto.txt", "r") as f:
```

Eu não encontrei nada sobre isso (ou não procurei direito). Sei que é possível fazer de outra forma:

```
var = open("meutexto.txt", "r")
var_dois = open("meu_segundo_texto.txt", "r")
var_tres = open("meu_terceiro_texto", "r")
```

Mas gostaria de saber se é possível com o *with open*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível, sim, a partir da versão 2.7 do Python. Veja:

[Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

A sintaxe para várias expressões no `with` é separá-las com uma vírgula:

```
with EXPR1 as VAR1, EXPR2 as VAR2:
    BLOCK
```

Ou seja, para abrir múltiplos arquivos, basta fazer:

```
with open("texto_1.txt") as var_1, open("texto_2.txt") as var_2:
    # código
```

Ao sair do bloco do `with`, todos os arquivos serão devidamente fechados.