# Como faço o python ler linha por linha?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Vamos supor que eu tenho um arquivo txt, com algumas dados:

[Arquivo.txt]

```
Oie
Olá
Tudo bem?
```

Eu quero algo (em python) que leia linha por linha e imprima(print).

Comment: Você esta usando python 2 ou 3?

Comment: Usando python 2.7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O modo mais [*pythonico*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878) de se realizar esta tarefa é através de um [gerenciador de contexto](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) com o `with`.

```
with open("arquivo.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

Com o gerenciador de contexto, você não precisa se preocupar em fechar o arquivo ao final, pois é garantido que este será devidamente fechado ao final do `with`. Também, vale comentar que o retorno da função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) é um [gerador](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) e pode ser iterado linha a linha, não precisando armazenar todo o conteúdo do arquivo em memória - isso faz muita diferença dependendo do tamanho do arquivo.

[Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

Comment: Obrigado anderson! :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLima Convido-te a fazer o [tour] pelo site e ler o guia [O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Obrigado, vou fazer o Tour :D

Answer (score 2):

Ele abre o arquivo como somente leitura 'r', carrega todas as linhas na variável arq e printa linha por linha:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
arq = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
texto = arq.readlines()
for linha in texto :
    print(linha)
arq.close()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :D