# Como salvar o resultado em um arquivo?

Tags: python-3.x

Bom, eu estou fazendo um programa que tira os espaços de frases, letras, palavras, e coloca cada "frase/letra/palavra" um embaixo do outro.

Por exemplo:
A "frase/letra/palavra": 
BAB BBA ACA AAB BCB CBB ABC CBC BBB ACA BCB CBA CBA CCB ACB BAA BBC ACB BCB

Ele tira os espaços, e coloca um embaixo do outro. Vou deixar uma print, mostrando, pra ficar mais fácil.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código fonte

```
string_qualquer = input("Digite o texto: ")

for x in string_qualquer.split():
    print(x)
```

Como eu faço pra salvar o resultado, ao invés de só printar na tela?

Programa em Execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `print` possui um argumento chamado `file`, que define o destino da mensagem. Por padrão, o valor do argumento é `sys.stdout`, que é responsável por exibir as mensagens da tela. Se deseja escrever em arquivo, basta passar como parâmetro o ponteiro para o arquivo:

```
string_qualquer = input("Digite o texto: ")

with open("resultado.txt", "w") as stream:
    for x in string_qualquer.split():
        print(x, file=stream)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GrotesqueUnripeIchidna)</sup>

Assim o resultado será armazenado no arquivo `resultado.txt`

Comment: Funcionou direitinho amigo, obrigado! O trecho "with open("resultado.txt", "w") as stream:" é um modo de abertura de arquivo, certo? Outra perguntinha, tem nos docs do python explicando esse tipo de abrir o arquivo? Porque eu uso aquele convencional. Ex: "Arquivo = open("qualquernome.txt", "w")".

Comment: @BRKappa de certa forma, sim. Leia mais em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878

Comment: Obrigado por ter resolvido minhas dúvidas!!!