# Soma de Números Inteiros em um Arquivo txt

Tags: python, string, lista, iterator

Estou com dois arquivos txt que contém apenas números (número por linha), então quero somar linha 1 + linha 1 assim sucessivamente até a ultima linha de cada arquivo. Cada arquivo tem o mesmo numero de linha.

**Neste código consigo apenas imprimir a primeira soma da primeira linha **

```
arq = open ("Lista1.txt")
arq2 = open ("Lista2.txt")
x = [linha.strip() for linha in arq]
arq.close()
y = [linha.strip() for linha in arq2]
arq2.close()


for linha in x:
   indice = 0
   while indice<len(x):
     soma = (int(x[indice]) + int(y[indice]))
     indice+=1
   print soma
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sabendo que os dois arquivos teriam sempre o mesmo tamanho, tu pode iterar sob o `range` do tamanho(`len`) da lista anteriormente lida, por exemplo a lista `y`. Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
arq = open ("txt1.txt")
arq2 = open ("txt2.txt")
x = arq.readlines()  #[linha.strip() for linha in arq]
arq.close()
y = arq2.readlines() #[linha.strip() for linha in arq2]
arq2.close()
novalista = [] #caso queira adicionar as somas em uma lista 

for i in range(len(y)):
    soma = int(x[i]) + int(y[i])
    novalista.append(soma) #adiciona somas na lista 
    print(soma) #imprime as somas individuais
#print(novalista)
```

Assim você não precisa utilizar um `while` dentro do `for` para limitar a iteração até o tamanho do arquivo.

Também utilizei a função `readlines()`, ela já retorna uma lista considerando as quebras de linha do txt como divisões.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Embora a solução apresentada possa gerar o resultado esperado, ele está longe de ser [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878), embora acredito que tenha sido útil para comparar com o código apresentado na pergunta e auxiliado a identificar os erros. Assim sendo, proponho uma solução um pouco mais elegante para a linguagem em questão:

```
with open("numbers_1.txt") as numbers_1, open("numbers_2.txt") as numbers_2:
    for pair in zip(numbers_1, numbers_2):
        print(sum(map(int, pair)))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SlipperyHandsomeNature)</sup>

Com o [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878) abro os dois arquivos no modo leitura, instanciando os dois geradores responsáveis por cada arquivo, `numbers_1` e `numbers_2`, respectivamente. Após, itero com um laço `for` sobre o resultado de [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), que faz a associação entre os elementos dos dois geradores: o n-ésimo termo de `numbers_1` é associado ao n-ésimo termo de `numbers_2` em uma tupla, onde *n* varia de 0 até o comprimento da sequência (menos um). Após, exibo o resultado da soma, através da função [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum), que recebe um iterável responsável por converter os valores do par em valores inteiros.

De certa forma, o código ainda pode ser melhorado construindo um gerador a partir desta estrutura:

```
def sum_of_files(file_1, file_2):
    with open(file_1) as numbers_1, open(file_2) as numbers_2:
        for pair in zip(numbers_1, numbers_2):
            yield sum(map(int, pair))

for s in sum_of_files('numbers_1.txt', 'numbers_2.txt'):
    print(s)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/StalePureRectangles)</sup>

A vantagem desta segunda solução é que você não precisa, em momento algum, manter a sequência de valores armazenado, por completo, na memória, o que otimiza muito caso seus arquivos cresçam esponencialmente, podendo chegar a milhares de linhas ou mais. A primeira solução teria a sequência final armazenada na memória (considerando que não fosse utilizada o `print`) e a solução da outra resposta teria três vezes a sequência armazenada (demanda muito mais recursos).

É possível ainda melhorar o código, quebrando a limitação de apenas dois arquivos, permitindo quantos arquivos forem necessários:

```
def sum_of_files(*files):
    streams = map(open, files)
    for numbers in zip(*streams):
        yield sum(map(int, numbers))
    for stream in streams:
        stream.close()

for s in sum_of_files('numbers_1.txt', 'numbers_2.txt', 'numbers_3.txt'):
    print(s)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PuzzledUnknownSynergy)</sup>

E ainda é possível melhorar quebrando a limitação de que os arquivos precisam ser do mesmo tamanho substituindo a função `zip()` pela função `itertools.zip_longest()`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def sum_of_files(*files):
    streams = map(open, files)
    for numbers in zip_longest(*streams, fillvalue=0):
        yield sum(map(int, numbers))
    for stream in streams:
        stream.close()

for s in sum_of_files('numbers_1.txt', 'numbers_2.txt', 'numbers_3.txt'):
    print(s)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HelpfulCriminalSweepsoftware)</sup>

Os arquivos menores, que não possuem a sequência completa de valores, terão seus números iguais a 0 devido ao parâmetro `fillvalue`. Desta forma, você será capaz de efetuar a soma de quantos arquivos forem necessários, independente do tamanho de cada um deles, desde que possuam valores válidos, sem ter que armazenar em memória a sequência, sendo o código bastante eficiente mesmo para arquivos com milhões de linhas.

Comment: Boa Anderson, obrigado pela resposta, me ensinou muito também, show de bola. Abraço!!!