# Destacar principais palavras de um texto em ordem de uma lista ja pronta

Tags: python

Tenho uma base bem básica que gostaria de destacar as principais palavras de cada linha de uma lista de priorização, exemplo:

Base:

```
Bom dia 
que dia lindo 
vamos embora 
vamos chutar o dia
```

Lista de priorização: `bom dia vamos lindo`

Resultado esperado:

```
Bom dia - Bom 
que dia lindo - Dia 
vamos embora - vamos 
vamos chutar o dia - dia
```

Consegui achar apenas com uma variável e não um lista. Código:

```
texto = 'dia' 

for lin in open(r"C:\Users\guilgig\Desktop\teste.txt"): 
    if texto in lin: 
        print (texto, lin)
```

Comment: Por quê "*Bom dia*" possui apenas "*Bom*" destacado se "*dia*" também pertence à lista de priorização?

Comment: Obrigado por editar! então seguindo a lista de priorização pois s preciso da mais importante então quando ele acha uma das palavras ja está ok, porem se houver uma forma mostrando todas as palavras tudo bem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código que você fez já está bem próximo do que você precisa, basta você definir a lista de priorização e percorrê-la buscando as palavras na frase:

```
with open('teste.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        for word in ['bom', 'dia', 'vamos', 'lindo']:
            if word in line:
                print(line.strip(), '-', word)
                break
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/DirectAppropriateFormula)</sup>

Quanto ao `with` para abrir o arquivo, você pode ler em: [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878). Para micro-otimações, você poderá definir sua lista de palavras com uma tupla (`tuple`) ou até um conjunto (`set`), que, para este fim, possuem vantagens tanto em relação ao armazenamento em memória quanto em velocidade de acesso aos elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer usando dois `for`:

```
principais_palavras = "bom dia vamos lindo"

base = """Bom dia
que dia lindo
vamos embora
vamos chutar o dia"""

lista_prioritaria = principais_palavras.lower().split(" ")
linhas = base.lower().split("\n")

for linha in linhas:
  for palavra in lista_prioritaria:
    if (palavra in linha):
      print(linha + " - " + palavra)
      break
```

A lógica da leitura do arquivo não faz parte do algoritmo, portanto ficou de fora, mas é só adaptar ao seu caso.

Comment: Se me permite o comentário, a ideia de utilizar o `lower()` é boa caso a intenção seja desconsiderar as caixas do texto, mas o `split()` na linha para converter em uma lista de palavras é desnecessário. O operador `in` funciona também para *string*, servindo para buscar se existe a *substring*.

Comment: Quando ao `lower()`, coloquei porque presumi que a caixa deve ser desconsiderada na busca, baseando-me no exemplo dado pelo AP. Quando ao `split()`, tem toda a razão. Não sei onde estava com a cabeça. Vou simplificar. Obrigado. :)