# Verificar a linha que contém uma string dentro de um arquivo TXT

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso de um ajuda com um programa que leia um arquivo e me responda em que linha contém uma string dentro dele.

**Exemplo**

Eu tenho um arquivo .txt e dentro dele eu tenho 5 linhas:

**Arquivo.txt:**

```
arroz
batata
feijão
carne
laranja
```

Eu preciso que o programa me retorne, por exemplo, se eu procurar laranja linha 5, se eu procurar batata, linha 2.

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer o seguinte:

```
with open('Arquivo.txt') as f:
    for l_num, l in enumerate(f, 1): # percorrer linhas e enumera-las a partir de 1
        if 'laranja' in l: # ver se palavra esta na linha
            print('laranja foi encontrada na linha', l_num)
            break
    else: # caso não haja break
        print('nao foi encontrada a palavra')
```

Usando uma função:

```
def get_line(word):
    with open('Arquivo.txt') as f:
        for l_num, l in enumerate(f, 1): # percorrer linhas e enumera-las a partir de 1
            if word in l: # ver se palavra esta na linha
                return l_num
        return False # não foi encontrada

print(get_line('laranja')) # 5
print(get_line('feijão')) # 3
print(get_line('banana')) # False
```

Se quiseres verificar se a linha é exatamente igual à palavra podes mudar a condição para ([`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)):

```
...
if word == l.strip(): # retirar quebra de linha
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazê-lo em uma versão um pouco mais extensa:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

arquivo = 'arquivo.txt'
pesquisa = 'batata'

achei = False

with open(arquivo,'r') as f:
    linha = 1
    for texto in f:
        if pesquisa == texto.strip():
            achei = True
            break
        linha+=1
f.close()

if achei:
    print('Encontrado "{}" na linha {}'.format(pesquisa, linha))
else:
    print('Não encontrei "{}"'.format(pesquisa))
```

Ele lê o arquivo linha a linha, procurando pela texto colocado em **pesquisa**, esta versão não é a mais rápida porém é mais didática.

Comment: De fato, a solução funciona, mas não é a versão mais idiomática. Se foi proposital, por favor, ignore o comentário, mas, caso desconheça mesmo, te convido a ler a [resposta do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288005/5878) que é uma versão mais *pythonica*.

Comment: Para simplificar: quando utilizas o gerenciador de contexto para abrir o arquivo não existe a necessidade de fechá-lo manualmente. O próprio `with` se encarrega disso (veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)); a contagem da linha pode ser simplificada utilizando o `enumerate`; e, por fim, não há a necessidade de utilizar uma *flag* `achei` para verificar o resultado da busca se utilizar o `else` do `for` para tratar o caso de insucesso.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

lines = open("arquivo.txt").readlines()
for i in range(0, len(lines)):
    if sys.argv[1] in lines[i].strip():
        print("%s na linha %d" % (lines[i].strip(), i + 1))
        break
```

Modo de usar:

```
$ ./teste.py lara
laranja na linha 4
```

Se quiser trocar o teste do fragmento por um teste exato, substituta "in lines..." por "== lines...".