# Ordenar sequência de números a partir de um arquivo TXT

Tags: python, array

Tenho um arquivo TXT com números separados por espaços e eu quero sequenciar do menor número para o maior, apenas os números da primeira linha desse arquivo. A lógica do sequenciamento eu acredito ter conseguido:

```
tam_entrada = len(lista)

for i in range (tam_entrada):
    for j in range (1, tam_entrada-i):
        if lista[j] < lista[j-1]:
            lista[j], lista[j-1] = lista[j-1], lista[j]


print(lista)
```

Mas não consigo importar a primeira linha do arquivo como um vetor que denominei `lista`. Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor?

Comment: Insira na sua pergunta a parte do arquivo em questão e também a parte do código que lê este arquivo e transforma em lista.

Comment: fnands para importar a primeira linha do arquivo basta inserir: with open(r'CAMINHO DO ARQUIVO') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com arquivos, aconselho você utilizar os gerenciadores de contextos:

[Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    linha = arquivo.readline()
```

Porém, `linha` será uma *string* e, para ordenar, será interessante você possuir uma lista de números. Para tal, basta converter os valores:

```
numeros = [int(numero) for numero in linha.split()]
```

E a ordenação, propriamente dita, pode ser feita com a função nativa `sorted` ou com o método `sort` da lista:

```
numeros.sort()
```

Assim, uma função que retorna a primeira linha de um arquivo de forma ordenada ficaria:

```
def linha_ordenada(caminho):
    with open(caminho) as arquivo:
        linha = arquivo.readline()
    numeros = [int(numero) for numero in linha.split()]
    numeros.sort()
    return numeros
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HotpinkStimulatingScope)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que seu arquivo de entrada (`arquivo.txt`) seja algo como:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
5 3 1 9 7 5 9 8 1
3 4 5 8 3 0 1 0 0
1 2 3 3 2 1 10 11 12
6 3 8 15 20 1 4 2 9
```

Você pode implementar uma função capaz de carregar e ordenar todas os valores contidos nas linhas do arquivo para uma lista bidimensional:

```
def obter_linhas_ordenadas( arq ):
    with open(arq) as arquivo:
        lst = []
        for linha in arquivo:
            lst.append(sorted([int(n) for n in linha.split()],key=lambda x:x))
    return lst;

lista = obter_linhas_ordenadas( 'arquivo.txt' );

print(lista[0])  # Exibe Linha 1
print(lista[2])  # Exibe Linha 3
print(lista[4])  # Exibe Linha 5
```

Saída:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Crie o arquivo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
arquivo = open('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/numeros.txt','r'); #Abre arquivo no modo 'read'.

linha = arquivo.readline() #lê uma linha do arquivo

arquivo.close() #Fecha o arquivo

lista = linha.split(" ") #Cria uma lista separando por " " (espaço) Ex.: "1 2 3".split(" ") == ['1','2','3']

tam_entrada = len(lista)

for i in range (tam_entrada):
    for j in range (1, tam_entrada-i):
        if lista[j] < lista[j-1]:
            lista[j], lista[j-1] = lista[j-1], lista[j]
print(lista)
```

**Saída:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]