# Programa de comparação de arquivos em python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida e uma grande dificuldade de criar um programa que leia 2 arquivos, exemplo `doc1.txt` e `doc2.txt`, dentro dos arquivos possui os seguintes dados:

```
doc1.txt   doc2.txt
1            1
1            2
2            5
3            6
4            7
5            7
10           8
             9
```

Ele deve ser linha por linha e comparar, exemplo se o dado 1 do doc1 for == ao dado 1 do doc2, doc1 > doc2 ou <, grave o dado em um doc chamado resultado.txt em sequencia com cada dado em linha por linha. Ele deve gravar os dados em sequência.

Segue o meu código:

```
#Arquivos de Texto
with open('doc1.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as doc1:
    arq1: int= doc1.readline()

with open('doc2.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as doc2:
    arq2: int = doc2.readline()

if arq1 == arq2:
    with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as res:
         r: int = res.write(arq1)

elif arq1 > arq2:
    with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as res:
         r: int = res.write(arq1)

elif arq1 < arq2:
    with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as res:
         r: int = res.write(arq2)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Ele só compara o primeiro dado 1 == 1 e grava no arquivo `resultado.txt` e depois ele não le mais nenhum dado dos arquivos.

Não sei o que estou fazendo de errado.

Comment: Você utilizou o método `readline` que, como o nome diz, lê uma linha. Se quer comparar todas as linhas, precisa iterar sobre elas. Não ficou claro o que precisa ser gravado no arquivo de resultado. Será sempre o maior entre os valores ou o nome do arquivo?

Comment: Então eu devo utilizar readlines, para ler todas as linhas, as dados que serão gravados no arquivo de resultado serão comparado, exemplo ambos os arquivos doc1 e doc2 possuem 1, então os arquivos serão comparados, se 1 for igual a 1, será gravado no arquivo resultado, ai ela ira comparar a proxima linha 1 é igual a 2, não, 1 é maior que 2, não, 1 é menor do que 2 sim então grava no resultado, ele sempre le o primeiro arquivo e fica gravado na variavel para depois comparar com a proxima, até todo o resultado ficar em sequencia ex: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. é mais ou menos isso.

Comment: @GuiScholzPortela: E se os arquivos não possuirem a mesma quantidade de linhas ? Qual é a saída esperada para o exemplo que você deu ?

Comment: Pior que eu não sei, eu fazia um programa em cobol chamado balance line, ou seja ele fazia comparação de numeros em linha por linha, como expliquei em cima, ai ele ia gravando em sequencia em ordem numerica em linha por linha, independente da quantidade de dados dentro dos arquivos, alguns arquivos tinham 1000 linhas e outros 500 linhas, e mesmo assim funcionavam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como comentado, o problema de ler apenas a primeira linha é que você utilizou o método `readline`, que lê apenas uma linha. Para ler todas, você precisará iterar sobre o arquivo com um laço de repetição.

Como explicado em [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878), você pode utilizar vários gerenciadores de contextos no mesmo `with`, o que simplificaria o seu programa:

```
with open('entrada_1.txt') as arquivo_1, \
     open('entrada_2.txt') as arquivo_2, \
     open('saida.txt', 'w') as saida:
    numeros_arquivo_1 = (int(numero.strip()) for numero in arquivo_1)
    numeros_arquivo_2 = (int(numero.strip()) for numero in arquivo_2)
    for a, b in zip(numeros_arquivo_1, numeros_arquivo_2):
        saida.write(f'{a}\n' if a >= b else f'{b}\n')
```

Visto que está lendo um arquivo, é natural que os dados venham como *string*, então é necessário convertê-los para numéricos. Os objetos `numeros_arquivo_1` e `numeros_arquivo_2` são exatamente isso - o `strip` é para remover a quebra de linha.

Com o `zip`, agrupamos os valores dos dois arquivos para facilitar a comparação entre `a` e `b`. Se o valor no arquivo 1 for maior ou igual ao do arquivo 2, é gravado no arquivo de saída o valor de `a`, senão, é gravado o valor de `b`. É importante salientar que o `zip` utiliza o menor arquivo como referência, ignorando os valores extras do maior. Se necessitar comparar com base no maior arquivo, utilize a função `itertools.zip_longest`.

Comment: Entendi, vou seguir o seu concelho, vou testar, e conforme alguma dúvida surja eu posto aqui, e também depois que terminar o programa, eu posto ele aqui, pode ajudar alguém no mesmo problema que eu. Muito obrigado, vou lhe mantendo informado.