# como excluir uma coluna em um arquivo csv python

Tags: python, csv

Como faço para excluir uma coluna de um arquivo csv?
exemplo:

```
nome;nota;idade
joao;10;12
maria;8;13
jose;6;8
```

para ficar assim:

```
nome;idade
joao;12
maria;13
jose;8
```

e como faco para colocar uma nova coluna desse arquivo para outro arquivo?

estou ainda aprendendo programação desculpa se for algo muito simples para o forum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Python existe o módulo nativo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para trabalhar com arquivos CSV. Nesse são definidas as classes `csv.DictReader` e `csv.DictWriter` que facilitam trabalhar com os dados nomeados.

Veja um exemplo:

```
import csv

with open('original.csv') as stream, \
    open('resultado.csv', 'w') as output:

    reader = csv.DictReader(stream, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=';', fieldnames=['nome', 'idade'])

    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        del row['nota']
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Com [gerenciadores de contextos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878) são abertos os dois arquivos, o original e o que será gerado. É definido o objeto `reader` que será responsável por ler o arquivo de entrada e gerar um dicionário para cada linha. O objeto `writer` será responsável por escrever o novo dicionário no arquivo de saída. Percorre-se, então, o arquivo de entrada, exclui-se a coluna desejada e escreve-a no arquivo de saída.

Você pode abstrair isso facilmente para uma função, que recebe como parâmetro o nome da coluna que deseja remover, bem como buscar as colunas do arquivo original a partir do `reader`, desta forma você cria uma solução mais versátil que funcionará para diferentes arquivos, com diferentes colunas, mas isso deixo para você fazer sozinho :D

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples de trabalhar com csv é usando Pandas. Dá uma olhada nesse tutorial [https://medium.com/data-hackers/uma-introdução-simples-ao-pandas-1e15eea37fa1](https://medium.com/data-hackers/uma-introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-simples-ao-pandas-1e15eea37fa1)

O código:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('csv.csv', sep=';')\
    .drop(columns=['nota'])\
    .to_csv('csv_sem_nota.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Comment: não quero usar isso, só tem como resolver usando ele? isso é um exercício da faculdade e ainda não aprendi sobre isso

Comment: Você pode fazer usando lib "csv" padrão do python, mas se é um exercício da faculdade e você não quer aprender coisas novas, então vai pra humanas :P

Comment: nao é questao de aprender coisas novas ou nao, mas meu professor pediu que usemos oque ele ta ensinando e que nao pulemos materia, mas obrigado mesmo assim.