# Insert no Postgres com Python não está surtindo efeito

Tags: python, postgresql

Preciso incluir dados e um banco de dados meu, mas não consigo e não estou sabendo resolver o problema.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='teste' user='postgres' host='localhost' password=''")
c = conn.cursor()

data = list(myarraywhit128values)

c.execute("INSERT INTO faces (id, cadastro, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, p26, p27, p28, p29, p30, p31, p32, p33, p34, p35, p36, p37, p38, p39, p40, p41, p42, p43, p44, p45, p46, p47, p48, p49, p50, p51, p52, p53, p54, p55, p56, p57, p58, p59, p60, p61, p62, p63, p64, p65, p66, p67, p68, p69, p70, p71, p72, p73, p74, p75, p76, p77, p78, p79, p80, p81, p82, p83, p84, p85, p86, p87, p88, p89, p90, p91, p92, p93, p94, p95, p96, p97, p98, p99, p100, p101, p102, p103, p104, p105, p106, p107, p108, p109, p110, p111, p112, p113, p114, p115, p116, p117, p118, p119, p120, p121, p122, p123, p124, p125, p126, p127, p128) VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW()," + str(data[0]) + "," + str(data[1]) + "," + str(data[2]) + "," + str(data[3]) + "," + str(data[4]) + "," + str(data[5]) + "," + str(data[6]) + "," + str(data[7]) + "," + str(data[8]) + "," + str(data[9]) + "," + str(data[10]) + "," + str(data[11]) + "," + str(data[12]) + "," + str(data[13]) + "," + str(data[14]) + "," + str(data[15]) + "," + str(data[16]) + "," + str(data[17]) + "," + str(data[18]) + "," + str(data[19]) + "," + str(data[20]) + "," + str(data[21]) + "," + str(data[22]) + "," + str(data[23]) + "," + str(data[24]) + "," + str(data[25]) + "," + str(data[26]) + "," + str(data[27]) + "," + str(data[28]) + "," + str(data[29]) + "," + str(data[30]) + "," + str(data[31]) + "," + str(data[32]) + "," + str(data[33]) + "," + str(data[34]) + "," + str(data[35]) + "," + str(data[36]) + "," + str(data[37]) + "," + str(data[38]) + "," + str(data[39]) + "," + str(data[40]) + "," + str(data[41]) + "," + str(data[42]) + "," + str(data[43]) + "," + str(data[44]) + "," + str(data[45]) + "," + str(data[46]) + "," + str(data[47]) + "," + str(data[48]) + "," + str(data[49]) + "," + str(data[50]) + "," + str(data[51]) + "," + str(data[52]) + "," + str(data[53]) + "," + str(data[54]) + "," + str(data[55]) + "," + str(data[56]) + "," + str(data[57]) + "," + str(data[58]) + "," + str(data[59]) + "," + str(data[60]) + "," + str(data[61]) + "," + str(data[62]) + "," + str(data[63]) + "," + str(data[64]) + "," + str(data[65]) + "," + str(data[66]) + "," + str(data[67]) + "," + str(data[68]) + "," + str(data[69]) + "," + str(data[70]) + "," + str(data[71]) + "," + str(data[72]) + "," + str(data[73]) + "," + str(data[74]) + "," + str(data[75]) + "," + str(data[76]) + "," + str(data[77]) + "," + str(data[78]) + "," + str(data[79]) + "," + str(data[80]) + "," + str(data[81]) + "," + str(data[82]) + "," + str(data[83]) + "," + str(data[84]) + "," + str(data[85]) + "," + str(data[86]) + "," + str(data[87]) + "," + str(data[88]) + "," + str(data[89]) + "," + str(data[90]) + "," + str(data[91]) + "," + str(data[92]) + "," + str(data[93]) + "," + str(data[94]) + "," + str(data[95]) + "," + str(data[96]) + "," + str(data[97]) + "," + str(data[98]) + "," + str(data[99]) + "," + str(data[100]) + "," + str(data[101]) + "," + str(data[102]) + "," + str(data[103]) + "," + str(data[104]) + "," + str(data[105]) + "," + str(data[106]) + "," + str(data[107]) + "," + str(data[108]) + "," + str(data[109]) + "," + str(data[110]) + "," + str(data[111]) + "," + str(data[112]) + "," + str(data[113]) + "," + str(data[114]) + "," + str(data[115]) + "," + str(data[116]) + "," + str(data[117]) + "," + str(data[118]) + "," + str(data[119]) + "," + str(data[120]) + "," + str(data[121]) + "," + str(data[122]) + "," + str(data[123]) + "," + str(data[124]) + "," + str(data[125]) + "," + str(data[126]) + "," + str(data[127]) + ")")
```

Alguém pode me apontar onde esta o erro? A variável `myarraywhit128values` está sendo recebida corretamente com todos valores.

Comment: E qual é o erro que aparece?

Comment: na linha de comando nenhum

Comment: já tentaste colocar o `conn.commit()` depois do `insert`?

Comment: ainda não vou fazer e te aviso.

Comment: fucnionou ^^muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Faltou você chamar `conn.commit()`. Por padrão, a biblioteca `psycopg2` irá iniciar uma transação antes de executar a primeira SQL. Se a função `commit`não for chamada, a transação será ignorada e as alterações não surtirão efeito no banco de dados.

Você pode melhorar a estrutura do seu código utilizando os [gerenciadores de contexto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878). Nesse caso é ainda mais interessante pois as transações são *commitadas* quando o contexto é encerrado.

```
DNS = "dbname='teste' user='postgres' host='localhost' password=''"
SQL = '''
    INSERT INTO faces (id, cadastro, p1, p2, ...)
    VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW(), %s, %s, %s, ...)
'''

with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL, data)
```

Os dados em `data` serão tratados e substituídos onde há coringa `%s` na SQL.

Como dito na [documentação oficial](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement):

> *When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of exception the transaction is rolled back.*

Em tradução livre: quando uma conexão encerra o bloco `with`, se nenhuma exceção foi lançada pelo bloco a transação será *commitada*. Em caso de exceção, a transação será desfeita.

Porém, se precisar executar mais consultas ou garantir que a conexão seja fechada em um determinado ponto do código, você poderá fazer:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)

with conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute(SQL, data)

conn.close()
```

Pois o gerenciador de contexto age apenas sobre a transação atual, não sobre a conexão em si.

Answer (score 0):

A resolução do problema foi a seguinte

```
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='teste' user='postgres' host='localhost' password=''")
c = conn.cursor()

data = list(myarraywhit128values)

c.execute("INSERT INTO faces (id, cadastro, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, p26, p27, p28, p29, p30, p31, p32, p33, p34, p35, p36, p37, p38, p39, p40, p41, p42, p43, p44, p45, p46, p47, p48, p49, p50, p51, p52, p53, p54, p55, p56, p57, p58, p59, p60, p61, p62, p63, p64, p65, p66, p67, p68, p69, p70, p71, p72, p73, p74, p75, p76, p77, p78, p79, p80, p81, p82, p83, p84, p85, p86, p87, p88, p89, p90, p91, p92, p93, p94, p95, p96, p97, p98, p99, p100, p101, p102, p103, p104, p105, p106, p107, p108, p109, p110, p111, p112, p113, p114, p115, p116, p117, p118, p119, p120, p121, p122, p123, p124, p125, p126, p127, p128) VALUES (DEFAULT, NOW()," + str(data[0]) + "," + str(data[1]) + "," + str(data[2]) + "," + str(data[3]) + "," + str(data[4]) + "," + str(data[5]) + "," + str(data[6]) + "," + str(data[7]) + "," + str(data[8]) + "," + str(data[9]) + "," + str(data[10]) + "," + str(data[11]) + "," + str(data[12]) + "," + str(data[13]) + "," + str(data[14]) + "," + str(data[15]) + "," + str(data[16]) + "," + str(data[17]) + "," + str(data[18]) + "," + str(data[19]) + "," + str(data[20]) + "," + str(data[21]) + "," + str(data[22]) + "," + str(data[23]) + "," + str(data[24]) + "," + str(data[25]) + "," + str(data[26]) + "," + str(data[27]) + "," + str(data[28]) + "," + str(data[29]) + "," + str(data[30]) + "," + str(data[31]) + "," + str(data[32]) + "," + str(data[33]) + "," + str(data[34]) + "," + str(data[35]) + "," + str(data[36]) + "," + str(data[37]) + "," + str(data[38]) + "," + str(data[39]) + "," + str(data[40]) + "," + str(data[41]) + "," + str(data[42]) + "," + str(data[43]) + "," + str(data[44]) + "," + str(data[45]) + "," + str(data[46]) + "," + str(data[47]) + "," + str(data[48]) + "," + str(data[49]) + "," + str(data[50]) + "," + str(data[51]) + "," + str(data[52]) + "," + str(data[53]) + "," + str(data[54]) + "," + str(data[55]) + "," + str(data[56]) + "," + str(data[57]) + "," + str(data[58]) + "," + str(data[59]) + "," + str(data[60]) + "," + str(data[61]) + "," + str(data[62]) + "," + str(data[63]) + "," + str(data[64]) + "," + str(data[65]) + "," + str(data[66]) + "," + str(data[67]) + "," + str(data[68]) + "," + str(data[69]) + "," + str(data[70]) + "," + str(data[71]) + "," + str(data[72]) + "," + str(data[73]) + "," + str(data[74]) + "," + str(data[75]) + "," + str(data[76]) + "," + str(data[77]) + "," + str(data[78]) + "," + str(data[79]) + "," + str(data[80]) + "," + str(data[81]) + "," + str(data[82]) + "," + str(data[83]) + "," + str(data[84]) + "," + str(data[85]) + "," + str(data[86]) + "," + str(data[87]) + "," + str(data[88]) + "," + str(data[89]) + "," + str(data[90]) + "," + str(data[91]) + "," + str(data[92]) + "," + str(data[93]) + "," + str(data[94]) + "," + str(data[95]) + "," + str(data[96]) + "," + str(data[97]) + "," + str(data[98]) + "," + str(data[99]) + "," + str(data[100]) + "," + str(data[101]) + "," + str(data[102]) + "," + str(data[103]) + "," + str(data[104]) + "," + str(data[105]) + "," + str(data[106]) + "," + str(data[107]) + "," + str(data[108]) + "," + str(data[109]) + "," + str(data[110]) + "," + str(data[111]) + "," + str(data[112]) + "," + str(data[113]) + "," + str(data[114]) + "," + str(data[115]) + "," + str(data[116]) + "," + str(data[117]) + "," + str(data[118]) + "," + str(data[119]) + "," + str(data[120]) + "," + str(data[121]) + "," + str(data[122]) + "," + str(data[123]) + "," + str(data[124]) + "," + str(data[125]) + "," + str(data[126]) + "," + str(data[127]) + ")")

conn.commit()
```