# Problemas ao tentar acessar arquivo JSON no Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

Olá, estou tentando ler determinados dados de um arquivo JSON no Python, porém estou com alguns problemas...

Esse é o arquivo JSON:

```
{
   "linguagem":"Python",
   "dados":"JSON"
}
```

Implementando o arquivo JSON diretamente dentro do script em Python, funcionou, e o programa em Python ficou assim:

```
import json
test = '{"linguagem": "Python", "dados": "JSON"}'
arquivo = json.loads(test)
print(arquivo [linguagem])
```

Porém, gostaria de acessar o arquivo JSON externamente. Tentei o seguinte comando, que não funcionou:

```
import json
arquivo = json.loads(TesteJSON.json)
print(arquivo [linguagem])
```

Neste último caso, "TesteJSON.json" é o nome do arquivo JSON que tentei acessar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) possui o S no final justamente para indicar "load String".

> `json.loads(s, *, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)`
>
> Deserialize `s` (a `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

O que você precisa é carregar a partir de um arquivo. Para isso existe a função [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), sem o S.

> `json.load(fp, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw)`
>
> *Deserialize `fp` (a `.read()`-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.*

```
with open('TesteJSON.json') as stream:
    dados = json.load(stream)

print(dados['linguagem'])
```

Sem o gerenciamento de contexto poderia ser apenas:

```
dados = json.load(open('TesteJSON.json'))
```

Comment: Não sabia essa do `.load` +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Está lá na documentação xD

Answer (score 2):

Para abrir um arquivo no `Python` você pode usar a função `open` combinado com a palavra chave [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49238).

Veja:

```
import json

with open('TesteJSON.json', 'r') as f:
    dados = json.loads(f.read())


print(dados['linguagem'])
```

- Através do método `read` o Python lê os arquivos para uma string
- A variável `dados` recebe o valor do `json.loads`, que retorna um [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).
- O `dict` deve ter o índice acessado através de uma string como o nome da propriedade do seu JSON. Da forma que você fez, poderia gerar um erro.