# Pegar string dentro de um arquivo de texto usando regex em Python

Tags: python, regex

Gostaria de saber como pegar uma string nesse formato ' XXXX ' dentro de um arquivo de texto, usando regex. Já tentei vários métodos mas sem sucesso:

```
import re
f = open('infos', 'r')
padrao = re.findall(r'\sSSBR\s', f)
if padrao in f:
    print(padrao)
else:
    print("Padrão não encontrado!")
```

Quando executo retorna esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "analiseInfos.py", line 3, in <module>
    padrao = re.findall(r'\sSSBR\s', f)
  File "C:\Users\Matheus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line
 223, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Trecho do arquivo 'infos':

```
20190401 00:01:25.371 00000084 SSBR 186701000125370c 0000 0000 D P C S N 0 3 RV 1e->000010413400000000000SSSSBR1010000091107200KP006287927455DF0

20190401 00:01:25.729 000000ff SSBR 175601000125370c 0000 0001 D R S S N 0 3 RV 1e<-000010413400000000000SSBRSS1022300091000107200KP006287927455

20190401 00:01:26.984 00000076 SSBR 176401000125984c 0000 0000 D P C S N 0 3 RV 1e->000011413400000000000SSSSBR1010000091107200CJ003363907455DF0

20190401 00:01:27.700 000000ff SSBR 190401000126984c 0000 0001 D R S S N 0 3 RV 1e<-000011413400000000000SSBRSS1236500091000107200CJ003363907455
```

Comment: Poste um trecho do que tem dentro do arquivo infos

Comment: Pronto, amigo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) retorna um [`file object`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), enquanto a função [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) deve receber uma string. É isso que a mensagem de erro está dizendo:

> TypeError: **expected string** or bytes-like object

Você passou o retorno de `open` (ou seja, um *file object*), em vez de uma string.

Para verificar o conteúdo do arquivo, você deve primeiro usar o *file object* para ler o conteúdo do arquivo e obtê-lo como uma string. Em seguida, você passa essa string para `findall`. Também recomendo usar `with`, [pois ele já fecha o arquivo automaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052):

```
with open('infos', 'r') as f:  
    for line in f: # para cada linha do arquivo
        print(re.findall(r'\sSSBR\s', line))
```

Lembrando que `findall` retorna uma lista com as ocorrências da regex na string em questão, então basta você imprimi-la para obter os resultados (se não tiver nada, retorna uma lista vazia).

O código acima faz um *loop* por todas as linhas do arquivo, e para cada uma, verifica a regex em questão. Mas se quiser, também pode colocar todo o conteúdo do arquivo de uma vez em uma única string, e em seguida usar a regex:

```
with open('infos', 'r') as f:  
    tudo = f.read()

print(re.findall(r'\sSSBR\s', tudo))
```

Mas para arquivos muito grandes, carregar tudo de uma vez pode consumir muita memória, então é melhor usar a primeira abordagem, de ler uma linha de cada vez.

---

Só lembrando que `findall` retorna uma lista dos trechos encontrados na string. Mas a sua regex contém um texto "fixo" (as letras "SSBR", exatamente nesta ordem, e com um espaço antes e outro depois), então o retorno de `findall` será uma lista com uma ou mais strings `" SSBR "` (ou uma lista vazia, se não for encontrado).

Se você só quer saber se a linha contém "SSBR" ou não, pode usar [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
with open('infos', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'\sSSBR\s', line):
            print('linha contém SSBR')
        else:
            print('linha não contém SSBR')
```

---

Quando for usar a mesma regex várias vezes, é interessante compilá-la antes, usando o método [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
r = re.compile(r'\sSSBR\s')
with open('infos', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if r.search(line):
            print('linha contém SSBR')
        else:
            print('linha não contém SSBR')
```

Assim você reaproveita a regex, pois ela não precisa ser recompilada várias vezes dentro do *loop* (se bem que a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) cita que existe um *cache* das regex usadas mais recentemente, então para programas pequenos e/ou com poucas regex que não são usadas muitas vezes não fará tanta diferença).

---

Outro detalhe é que você usou `\s` (que corresponde a espaços, <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha, [veja a documentação para a lista completa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30)), e os espaços fazem parte do retorno de `findall` (ou seja, retornará `" SSBR "`, com os espaços antes e depois). Se quiser que somente a string "SSBR" esteja nos resultados, você pode trocar a regex para `r'\s(SSBR)\s'`: os parênteses formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) e quando estes estão presentes, `findall` retorna somente os grupos.

Ou você pode usar `r'\bSSBR\b'`. O `\b` [significa "*word boundary*"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26) (algo como "fronteira entre palavras"), e corresponde à posições em que há um caractere alfanumérico antes e outro não-alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa). Ou seja, ela pega a string "SSBR" inclusive se tiver outras coisas além de `\s` antes ou depois (como sinais de pontuação, o início ou fim da string, etc).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era isso mesmo!