# Como imprimir e salvar em um TXT

Tags: python

Bom dia, gostaria de pegar os `print`s imprimir dentro de um arquivo txt, já salvando automaticamente.

```
print ("Informe o CNPJ: ", cnpj) 
print ("Resumo do Chamado: ", resumo)
print ("Nome do correspondente: ", nome)
print ("E-mail: ", email)
print ("Descrição da solicitação/Incidente: ", problema)
print ("Troubleshooting: ", trouble)
print ("Solução: ", solucao)
print ("Caminho do HelpFile: ", caminho)
```

Comment: Você deseja redirecionar o seu print direto pra um arquivo ou deseja imprimir a mesma coisa na tela e no arquivo de forma independente?

Comment: Poderia nos explicar melhor sua ideia? Não está muito claro pra mim o que você quer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria salvar o que seriam estes prints numa variável e depois salvar num arquivo. Por exemplo:

```py
textoParaSalvar = '''Informe o CNPJ: %s
Resumo do Chamado: %s
Nome do correspondente: %s
E-mail: %s
Descrição da solicitação/Incidente: %s
Troubleshooting: %s
Solução: %s
Caminho do HelpFile: %s 
''' % (cpf, resumo, nome, email, problema, trouble, solucao, caminho)

with open("ARQUIVO.TXT", 'w')  as arquivo:
    arquivo.write(textoParaSalvar)
```

#### Explicando o código

Eu crio a variável `textoParaSalvar` e atribuo uma string. Repare que usei `%s` para indicar a posição onde eu devo inserir outra string dentro dela. Isto é a formatação de strings, [veja aqui](https://pyformat.info/) um site interessante sobre isso.

Para abrir o arquivo, eu utilizei [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49238/para-que-serve-o-with-no-python)`open(arquivo, modo) as nome:`.
Para a função [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) eu chamei com dois argumentos. O primeiro deve indicar o nome do arquivo que eu quero salvar, o segundo o modo que estou abrindo ele.

Existem basicamente quatro modos para abertura de arquivos:

- **r**: Usa-se para abrir em modo de leitura (padrão, pode ser omitido se quiser usar ele)
- **w**: Usa-se para abrir em modo de escrita
- **a**: Usado para quando quiser abrir em modo `append`, que seria um modo de leitura que não apague o conteúdo já existente.
- **x**: Usado apenas para criação do arquivo.

Os modos podem ser expandidos, para saber mais consulte a [documentação oficial.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Faltou o `s` do %s na segunda linha

Comment: Acabei de corrigir

Comment: Ele não precisa dar \n para pular?

Comment: Quando eu uso aspas triplas não é necessário. A própria quebra de linha no código já indica quebra de linha na saída.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: Amigo, porque o uso do 'w' no - with open......

Comment: Complementei a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode executar do terminal e salvar os outputs. 
Tipo, se estiver no Ubuntu:

```
python3 meuprograma.py -> touch outputs.txt
```

Isso salva todos os seus prints executados no programa num arquivo de texto (chamado outputs, no caso).

Comment: Mas e para fazer isso no Windows mesmo? tem como? Ele salvar os prints sem apagar os outros?

Comment: Tem, mas vc tem que configurar o python pra funcionar no cmd.
Aí vc usa python meuprograma.py >> output.txt

Dessa maneira aí, vai sobrescrever tudo, mas tem como agregar tabém. Esse recurso de direcionar os outputs de um comando pra outro se chama pipe, vc pode pesquisar melhor pra usar outros recursos.