# Como recuperar um trecho específico de um texto

Tags: python, string, regex

Tenho um arquivo de configuração e preciso pegar um trecho específico de uma configuração, qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

No exemplo abaixo preciso pegar o trecho que começa em "config system interface" e termina no próximo "end".

```
config system accprofile
    edit "prof_admin"
        set mntgrp read-write
        set admingrp read-write
        set updategrp read-write
        set authgrp read-write
        set sysgrp read-write
        set netgrp read-write
        set loggrp read-write
        set routegrp read-write
        set fwgrp read-write
        set vpngrp read-write
        set utmgrp read-write
        set wanoptgrp read-write
        set endpoint-control-grp read-write
        set wifi read-write
    next
end
config system interface
    edit "port1"
        set vdom "root"
        set ip 192.168.0.150 255.255.255.0
        set allowaccess ping https ssh http telnet
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 1
    next
    edit "port2"
        set vdom "root"
        set type physical
        set role wan
        set snmp-index 2
    next
end
```

Comment: Existem varias maneiras de fazer isso, mas usando essa "estrategia" qq uma delas seria mais lento e "confuso" do que se vc usar uma abordagem mais apropridada para aquivo de configuração (json, ini, yaml, etc), no caso do python eu usaria yaml, uma boa referencia é [esse link](https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/)

Comment: Alias, olhando atentamente esse arquivo ja está quase formatdo no padrão yaml, se fazer alguns ajustes, agora... Se vc não puder alterar o arquivo, ai vai ter que fazer um 'parse' de acordo com o padrao fornecido.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o arquivo segue sempre esta estrutura (assumindo, por exemplo, que não haverá um bloco "config" dentro de outro), você pode simplesmente ler o arquivo linha a linha.

Quando encontrar a linha contendo `config system interface`, você marca que foi iniciado um bloco de configuração. A partir daí, basta ir guardando todas as linhas subsequentes, até encontrar uma linha que só tem `end`:

```
configuracoes = [] # guarda todos os trechos 'config system interface' encontrados

with open('arquivo_de_configuracao.txt') as file:
    dentro_do_bloco = False # verifica se está dentro de um bloco de config desejado
    config = [] # guarda a config atual

    for linha in file: # lê o arquivo linha a linha
        linha = linha.strip('\n') # retirar quebra de linha
        if linha == 'config system interface':
            dentro_do_bloco = True # iniciou o bloco
            config.append(linha)
        elif dentro_do_bloco:
            config.append(linha)
            if linha == 'end':
                dentro_do_bloco = False # terminou o bloco
                # junta tudo e guarda na lista de configs encontradas
                configuracoes.append('\n'.join(config))
                config = []

# imprime as configurações encontradas
for c in configuracoes:
    print(c)
```

Esta solução assume que não há blocos de configuração aninhados (e portanto não há nenhum `end` dentro do próprio bloco, já que ele é que determina que a config atual terminou).

Repare também no uso de `with`: [isso garante que o arquivo será fechado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052), mesmo que ocorra um erro durante a execução.

---

#### Regex

A solução acima eu considero a opção mais simples, mas como você usou a *tag* [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) na pergunta, segue uma alternativa, usando o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

with open('/tmp/arq.txt') as file:
    conteudo = file.read()
    r = re.compile('^config system interface$(?:(?!^end$).)+^end$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    configuracoes = r.findall(conteudo)

# imprime as configurações encontradas
for c in configuracoes:
    print(c)
```

Apesar de ter menos linhas que a solução anterior, não é necessariamente mais simples e/ou mais eficiente¹.

Primeiro que esta solução usa o método `read`, que carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória (diferente da solução anterior, que lê uma linha de cada vez). Para arquivos pequenos não fará tanta diferença, mas se estiver processando arquivos grandes, pode ser que tenha problemas de alto consumo de memória, ao ler tudo de uma vez.

Quanto à regex, ela usa os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string. Mas graças à *flag* [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), eles também correspondem ao início e fim de uma linha.

Por isso o trecho `^config system interface$` verifica uma linha que contém exatamente "config system interface" (nem um caractere a mais, nem a menos, a linha deve ter exatamente isso). O mesmo vale para `^end$`.

No meio temos `(?:(?!^end$).)+`. Explicando de dentro para fora:

- `(?!^end$)` é um [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que serve para verificar se algo **não** existe à frente. No caso, ele verifica se não existe `^end$`, ou seja, se a linha não é "end". Com isso, garantimos que não estamos no fim de um bloco de configuração.
- o ponto, por padrão, [corresponde a qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Mas graças à *flag* [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL), ele também corresponde a quebras de linha.

Então o *negative lookahead* combinado com `.` significa "qualquer caractere, desde que não esteja em uma linha com `end`". Ou seja, qualquer coisa que esteja dentro do bloco que queremos.

Tudo isso está entre parênteses, seguido do [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, estou pegando vários caracteres, desde que não sejam uma linha com "end".

Os parênteses usam a sintaxe `(?:`, que formam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Se eu usar apenas parênteses, sem o `?:`, eles formam um grupo de captura, e este é um detalhe importante, pois o método [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna somente os grupos de captura, caso eles estejam presentes. Como eu quero todo o trecho, eu mudo para grupo de não-captura, assim o `findall` retornará toda o bloco de configuração desejado.

O método `findall` retorna uma lista com todos os trechos de configuração capturados. Apenas para entender melhor a diferença, se eu usar um grupo de captura (colocando parênteses em volta deste trecho):

```
r = re.compile('^config system interface$((?:(?!^end$).)+)^end$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
                                         ^               ^
```

O método `findall` retorna apenas o trecho correspondente, ou seja, todo o bloco de configuração, **exceto** o início ("config system interface") e o final ("end").

---

Apesar da regex funcionar, não acho que seja a solução mais adequada para este caso. Pois além de carregar o arquivo inteiro na memória (que pode ou não fazer diferença, dependendo do tamanho dos arquivos que você vai ler), a regex não é lá muito eficiente, já que o *lookahead* faz com que ela verifique o que tem na frente e depois volte (e faz isso várias vezes), para garantir que não estamos ultrapassando a linha que tem "end" ([veja um exemplo dela funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/m0vfIF/1/)).

Outra alternativa é usar `^config system interface$.*?^end$`, que é um pouco mais eficiente que o *lookahead* ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/m0vfIF/2/) e compare a quantidade de passos com a regex anterior). Agora eu simplesmente uso `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres), e o `?` logo depois faz com que o quantificador seja ["preguiçoso"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution) e só pegue o mínimo de caracteres necessários (com isso, ele só vai até a próxima linha que tenha "end"). Se você não usar o `?`, ele [pegará o máximo de caracteres possível](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e irá até o último `end` que encontrar, podendo incluir linhas de outros blocos de configuração.

---

(1): É claro que, para arquivos pequenos, não fará tanta diferença usar regex ou ler linha a linha, mas dependendo dos arquivos sendo lidos, é importante ter em mente que podem haver diferenças de acordo com a solução escolhida. Cabe a você testar cada caso.

Comment: As duas alternativas estão executando perfeitamente, porém é importante pensar no desempenho do programa. Obrigado pela atenção e pelas informações que vc explicou passo a passo. grato.

Answer (score 0):

Para testar a minha resposta salve o seu arquivo de configuração como `config.txt` e o código que segue salve como `extrair_trecho.py`

Nas variáveis `inicio` e `fim` você coloca as `strings` que marcam o início o o fim do trecho que deseja extrair do arquivo `config.txt`.

No primeiro `for` percorremos todas as linhas do `arquivo`.

Se `inicio` estiver na `linha` então `copiar = True` e as linhas serão adicionadas na lista `trecho` até que a variável `fim` seja igual a `linha`.

No último `for` todas as linhas da lista `trecho` são impressas na tela.

```
arquivo = "config.txt"
inicio = "config system interface"
fim = "end"
copiar = False
trecho = []

arq = open(arquivo, "r")

for linha in arq :

        if copiar == True:
                trecho.append(linha)

        if inicio in linha:
                copiar = True
                trecho.append(linha)

        if fim in linha:
                copiar = False

arq.close()

for linha in trecho:
        print(linha)
```

Saída:

```
config system interface

    edit "port1"

        set vdom "root"

        set ip 192.168.0.150 255.255.255.0

        set allowaccess ping https ssh http telnet

        set type physical

        set role wan

        set snmp-index 1

    next

    edit "port2"

        set vdom "root"

        set type physical

        set role wan

        set snmp-index 2

    next

end
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda!!