# Como iterar com dicionários em Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho dois arquivos e preciso gerar um terceiro a partir deles.

Primeiro arquivo chamado "de_para".

- de_para.txt

Dentro desse arquivo tenho o seguinte conteúdo de exemplo:

```
Ordem   Campo_para  Campo_de
1   nome_emp    RAZA
2   ende_emp    ENDE
3   cepe_emp    NCEP
4   cida_emp    CIDA
```

- "Ordem" seria a ordem em que os dados serão impressos nas linhas no terceiro arquivo;
- "Campo_para" é o nome da coluna que será gravada no terceiro arquivo.
- "Campo_de" é o nome da coluna que será procurada nas chaves do segundo arquivo chamado "empresas.txt"

O segundo arquivo "empresas.txt" tem a seguinte composição:

```
RAZA    ENDE    NCEP    CIDA 
empresa1    rua1    cep1    cidade1  
empresa2    rua2    cep2    cidade2 
empresa3    rua3    cep3    cidade3 
empresa4    rua4    cep4    cidade4 
empresa5    rua5    cep5    cidade5
```

Como posso fazer a iteração dessa situação?

Com esse código eu criaria a lista com as colunas do primeiro arquivo:

```
for dict_col_geempre in read_geempre:
    hash_geempre.append(dict_col_geempre.get("Campo_de"))
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer a verificação da seguinte maneira:

Preciso verificar se a coluna "`RAZA`" do segundo arquivo existe no `hash_geempre`, caso exista, pegue o valor dessa chave no segundo arquivo "empresas.txt" e assim por diante e depois grave tudo isso num terceiro arquivo de nome "empresas_validas.txt".

Daria para fazer de modo diferente. Setando uma variável para cada coluna do segundo arquivo "empresas.txt", mas pensei em fazer com um arquivo "de_para" para ficar melhor penso eu.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Primeiro leia o arquivo `de_para`, e guarde cada linha (exceto a primeira) em uma lista (usando `with` para abrir o arquivo, pois ele [garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final do bloco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052)):

```
de_para = []
with open('de_para.txt', 'r') as de_para_arq:
    next(de_para_arq) # pula primeira linha
    for linha in de_para_arq:
        de_para.append(linha.split())
# ordena a lista de acordo com o campo ordem
de_para = sorted(de_para, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
```

Eu uso [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar a linha por espaços, e o resultado é uma lista, onde o primeiro elemento é a coluna ordem, o segundo é a coluna "para" e o terceiro é a coluna "de". Cada linha do arquivo será uma lista assim, e `de_para` será uma lista contendo todas essas listas (uma para cada linha do arquivo).

Em seguida ordenei a lista `de_para` com base na primeira coluna (usando [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) para converter a string para número), para garantir que os elementos estarão na ordem correta (*se essa coluna existe, estou assumindo que as linhas não estarão necessariamente em ordem no arquivo, caso contrário não faria sentido essa coluna existir*).

---

Agora vamos ler o arquivo de empresas:

```
empresas = []
with open('empresas.txt', 'r') as empresas_arq:
    headers = next(empresas_arq).split() # nomes dos headers
    for linha in empresas_arq:
        empresa = dict()
        for header, valor in zip(headers, linha.split()):
            empresa[header] = valor
        empresas.append(empresa)
```

Primeiro eu faço `split` na primeira linha para pegar os nomes das colunas.

Depois, para cada linha do arquivo, eu percorro tanto a lista de `headers` quanto os elementos da linha (o uso de [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) permite percorrer as duas listas ao mesmo tempo, assim eu tenho o valor correspondente ao nome de cada coluna). **Essa solução assume que o arquivo é bem formado e sempre tem todas as colunas**.

No fim eu tenho uma lista de empresas, sendo que cada empresa é um dicionário, que mapeia os nomes das colunas com os respectivos valores. Por exemplo, o primeiro elemento da lista de empresas será:

```
{'RAZA': 'empresa1', 'CIDA': 'cidade1', 'ENDE': 'rua1', 'NCEP': 'cep1'}
```

Assim, eu tenho o nome da coluna atual e o respectivo valor. Cada linha do arquivo de empresas será um dicionário assim, e a lista `empresas` terá todos esses dicionários (um para cada linha do arquivo).

---

Agora é só escrever o terceiro arquivo:

```
with open('empresas_validas.txt', 'w') as out:
    # escreve os headers
    out.write(' '.join(para for _, para, _ in de_para))
    out.write("\n")
    for emp in empresas:
        out.write(' '.join(emp[de] for _, _, de in de_para))
        out.write("\n")
```

Primeiro eu escrevo os headers, usando os nomes que estão na lista `de_para`. Eu uso `join` para unir os nomes, separando-os por espaço. Para facilitar, use a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Depois, para cada empresa, eu pego o valor da coluna "de" que está na lista `de_para` (como a lista foi ordenada, eu garanto que os campos são escritos na ordem desejada). O resultado será o arquivo:

```
nome_emp ende_emp cepe_emp cida_emp 
empresa1 rua1 cep1 cidade1 
empresa2 rua2 cep2 cidade2 
empresa3 rua3 cep3 cidade3 
empresa4 rua4 cep4 cidade4 
empresa5 rua5 cep5 cidade5
```

---

Se quiser, também pode trocar os loops que leem os arquivos por *list* e *dict comprehensions*:

```
with open('de_para.txt', 'r') as de_para_arq:
    next(de_para_arq) # pula primeira linha
    de_para = [ linha.split() for linha in de_para_arq ]
# ordena a lista de acordo com o campo ordem
de_para = sorted(de_para, key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

with open('empresas.txt', 'r') as empresas_arq:
    headers = next(empresas_arq).split() # nomes dos headers
    empresas = [ { header: valor for header, valor in zip(headers, linha.split()) } for linha in empresas_arq ]

with open('empresas_validas.txt', 'w') as out:
    # escreve os headers
    out.write(' '.join(para for _, para, _ in de_para))
    out.write("\n")
    out.write("\n".join( ' '.join(emp[de] for _, _, de in de_para) for emp in empresas))
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado @hkotsubo, funcionou perfeitamente do modo que eu preciso.
Parabéns pela dedicação e tempo disposto a explicar muito bem detalhado o processo.

Comment: Tenho uma dúvida quanto a essa linha:

out.write(' '.join(emp[de] for _, _, de in de_para))

Que fica na parte da escrita do arquivo.

Preciso validar ou tratar o campo "de" antes da gravação, como faria nesse caso?

Comment: @CleberNandi Depende do que quer fazer. Se quer testar uma condição, pode fazer `out.write(' '.join(emp[de] for _, _, de in de_para if condicao))` (a condição pode ser qualquer expressão válida de um `if`, aí ele só vai pegar as chaves que satisfazem a condição), ou então `out.write(' '.join(emp.get(de, valor_default) for _, _, de in de_para))` - nesse caso, `emp.get(de, valor_default)` retorna o valor_default se a chave `de` não existir.

Comment: Tentei entender sozinho mas não consegui.
Poderia me ajudar a entender a linha:

out.write(' '.join(emp[de] for _, _, de in de_para))

Especificamente o "for _, _, de in de_para".
Não entendi o por que desses dois underlines, o "de" entendi, mas os underlines não.

Outra coisa que preciso fazer, tentei e me enrolei é alterar essa linha que passei acima para criar uns validadores antes de gravar a linha.

Comment: Tentei isso mans não deu:

                for _, _, Campo_Concorrente in geempre_list:
                    campo = emp.get(Campo_Concorrente, "NULO")
                    empresa_linha_list.append(campo)
                # out.write("\n".join(emp.get(Campo_Concorrente, "NULO") for _, _, Campo_Concorrente in geempre_list))
                    out.write("\t".join(linha for linha in empresa_linha_list))
                    out.write("\n")
Grato.

Comment: Cada elemento do de_para é uma lista com 3 elementos, então `for a, b, c in de_para` já faz com que a, b e c sejam os elementos de cada lista. Geralmente usa-se `_` para indicar que aquele valor não interessa e só vou usar os outros (é uma convenção da linguagem, poderia ser qualquer nome, mas usa-se `_` para indicar que aquele valor não será usado)

Comment: @CleberNandi De qualquer forma, não entendi exatamente qual o problema que está tendo. Eu sugiro que faça [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com o problema específico. É que o site funciona assim: uma pergunta para cada problema específico. No caso - até onde entendi - já é algo diferente do problema relatado aqui (embora relacionado, mas diferente). É até melhor outra pergunta porque tem mais espaço que nos comentários, e ainda dá pra formatar o código (ainda mais em Python, que identação faz toda a diferença para entender o código)

Comment: Grato.
Farei outra pergunta.

Comment: @CleberNandi Outra vantagem de fazer outra pergunta, é que ela fica visível na página principal para todos os usuários, e aumenta suas chances de ter uma resposta. Já aqui nos comentários, menos gente vai ver... Não esqueça de colocar todo o contexto necessário (nem todos vão saber ou lembrar que vc já fez essa pergunta aqui, faça a outra pergunta de forma que ela seja "independente" dessa).

Comment: Farei isso, grato. Muito agradecido.