# Como usar métodos de um objeto dentro do "with" em Python?

Tags: python

Olá, eu estou estudando um pouco mais sobre as melhores praticas de uso do Python e me deparei com um comando que eu não conheço muito bem, o `with`, então resolvi estudar um pouco melhor sobre como ele funciona, e estou tentando fazer um teste, o programa que eu escrevi é o seguinte:

```
class Teste(object):
def __init__(self, var1):
    self.var1 = var1
def __enter__(self):
    print('Entrou!!')
def __exit__ (self, exception, value, traceback):
    print('Saiu!!')
def mostrar_var(self):
    print('A variavel é: {}'.format(self.var1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Teste('Olá') as objeto_teste:
        objeto_teste.mostrar_var()
```

A minha intenção nesse teste é iniciar o objeto Teste, executar o método "mostrar_var" e fechar o objeto, mas eu não estou conseguindo executar o método "mostrar_var", só iniciar e encerrar o objeto. Gostaria de uma ajuda para entender melhor o que eu estou fazendo errado e como esses métodos podem ser acessados usando o `with`. A exception que eu recebo executando esse código é a seguinte:

```
Entrou!! Saiu!! Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ZanattaJ\Desktop\teste.py", line 14, in <module>
    objeto_teste.mostrar_var() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mostrar_var'
```

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você faz algo como:

```py
with Teste('Olá') as objeto_teste:
    objeto_teste.mostrar_var()
```

O valor de `objeto_teste` será definido a partir do retorno do método `__enter__`. Como seu método não possui retorno, `None` será atribuído, por isso o erro.

Como você quer trabalhar diretamente sobre a instância gerada dentro do gerenciador de contexto, você pode retornar `self` neste método:

```py
def __enter__(self):
    print('Entrou!!')
    return self
```

Desta forma, ao executar, a saída será:

```
Entrou!!
A variavel é: Olá
Saiu!!
```

Para mais detalhes do `with`, leia [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, eu já havia dado uma lida nessa outra pergunda mas não tinha entendido, vou ler mais atenciosamente agora, mas por enquanto sua responsta já foi de grande ajuda para entender o que eu estava fazendo errado,

Answer (score 2):

Em Python "with" é um **context manager** criado para gerir "unmanaged-resources", mais detalhes [context-manager](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) e [unmanaged-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources). 
Resumindo, a utilização de gestores de contexto são muito utilizados, e devem ser em prol de uma boa gestão de memória dos servidores, uma vez que existem recursos que não são geridos pelo GC - [Garbage Collect](https://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-e-exemplo-do-gc-garbage-collector-propriedades-e-indexadores-estrutura-da-linguagem-parte-1/19835).

**Exemplo**

```
class FileManager(): 
    def __init__(self, filename, mode): 
        self.filename = filename 
        self.mode = mode 
        self.file = None

    def __enter__(self): 
        self.file = open(self.filename, self.mode) 
        return self.file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback): 
        self.file.close() 

# loading a file  
with FileManager('test.txt', 'w') as f: 
    f.write('Test') 

print(f.closed)
```

**Nota de um caso prático**

Imagina que queres aceder a recursos como por exemplo ficheiros de logs, que podem crescer exponencialmente e pode chegar a várias centenas de MB de tamanho ou até GB's, se por algum motivo existir alguma tool que abra este ficheiro para carregar todos os erros e se não não utilizares um gestor de contexto poderás 'colar' o teu servidor, por falta de memória ao abrir várias vezes o ficheiro caso o recurso não seja libertado da memória.