# Escrever em um arquivo números separados por um determinado caractere

Tags: python

Tenho que fazer um programa que escreve em disco um arquivo com números ordenados
crescentemente de 1 a 100. Cada número deve ser separado por `;`. O arquivo deve se chamar “crescente.txt”.

Eu fiz assim:

```
arquivo= open("Crescente.txt","w")
for numeros in range(1,101):
 arquivo.write(str(numeros))
 print(numeros, end=".")
arquivo.close()
```

Está dando errado: no Python aparece com pontos um entre o outro, já no arquivo salvo aparece sem ponto.

Comment: Sim, com `arquivo.write` você define o que será escrito no arquivo e você colocou apenas os números; já com o `print` você define o que será exibido no terminal e você colocou os números com um ponto ao final. O que você descreveu condiz com o código que você escreveu. Qual era o resultado esperado?

Comment: Igor, se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu (apenas uma delas) e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 3):

```
arquivo= open("Crescente.txt","w")
for numeros in range(1,101):
   arquivo.write(str(numeros) + ', ')#adiciona a vírgula
   print(numeros, end=".")
arquivo.close()
```

Se o arquivo não estiver criado o Python automaticamente cria um com o nome passado na atribuição.

[image: imagem do arquivo]

Comment: mt obg pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

O [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), por padrão, escreve no [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) (que por sua vez, mostrará a mensagem no terminal onde você está executando o Python). Ou seja, ele não escreve no arquivo (a menos que você indique, por exemplo: `print(mensagem, file=arquivo)` escreve no arquivo - considerando que `arquivo` foi obtido pelo `open`).

No seu caso, o que está sendo escrito no arquivo é somente o que é passado para `arquivo.write`. E como você só passou o número e nada mais, isso é o que será escrito no arquivo. Já no `print` você imprimiu o número seguido de um ponto, mas como já foi dito, isso não está sendo escrito no arquivo, e sim "na tela" (no terminal onde você executa o Python).

Se quer escrever todos os números no arquivo, e entre eles deve ter um `;` então faça assim:

```
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    arquivo.write(';'.join(str(n) for n in range(1, 101)))
```

O uso de [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) é interessante porque ele já fecha o arquivo no final da execução.

Em seguida eu uso [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para juntar os números, usando o `;` como o caractere que ficará entre eles. Desta forma, o conteúdo do arquivo será:

```
1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22;23;24;25;26;27;28;29;30;31;32;33;34;35;36;37;38;39;40;41;42;43;44;45;46;47;48;49;50;51;52;53;54;55;56;57;58;59;60;61;62;63;64;65;66;67;68;69;70;71;72;73;74;75;76;77;78;79;80;81;82;83;84;85;86;87;88;89;90;91;92;93;94;95;96;97;98;99;100
```

---

Como é um exercício, e esses exercícios costumam ter limitações artificiais como "não pode usar [*função pronta da linguagem*]", pode ser que não possa usar `join`. Neste caso, daria para fazer um *loop* simples:

```
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    for n in range(1, 100): # vou até o penúltimo número
        arquivo.write(f'{n};')
    arquivo.write('100')
```

Eu usei uma [*f-string*](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) para imprimir o número seguido de `;`. Este recurso está disponível a partir do Python 3.6, mas se estiver usando uma versão anterior, pode trocar para:

```
arquivo.write('{};'.format(n))
```

O detalhe é que no `for` eu fui de 1 a 99 (o `range(1, 100)` inclui os números de 1 a 99). Ou seja, o `for` escreve `1;2;3;....99;`.

Se eu fosse até 100, uma `;` seria colocada no final, após o 100. Para evitar isso, eu vou até 99 e no final (fora do *loop*) escrevo o 100 diretamente.

---

Se quiser deixar o algoritmo mais "genérico":

```
inicio = 1
fim = 100

# com join    
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    arquivo.write(';'.join(str(n) for n in range(inicio, fim + 1)))

# com loop
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    for n in range(inicio, fim): # vou até o penúltimo número
        arquivo.write(f'{n};')
    arquivo.write(str(fim))
```

Comment: Mt obg pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

```
arquivo.write('teste')
```

A linha de código acima coloca a string ***'teste'*** dentro do arquivo.

---

```
arquivo.write('teste' + ', ')
```

A linha acima coloca ***'teste, '*** dentro do arquivo. (com vírgula e espaço no fim).

Comment: obg pela pergunta

Answer (score -1):

Eu encontrei um metodo mais facil de fazer isso:

arquivoC=open("Crescente.txt","w")

for num in range(1,101): 
    arquivoC.write(str(num)+";"+"\n")  
    print(str(num)+";")

arquivoC.close()

Comment: Como assim mais fácil? Isso não é exatamente o mesmo código das demais respostas?

Comment: Mas o resultado é exatamente o mesmo

Comment: Não produz. O seu, sendo o mesmo código que [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418889/5878) adiciona uma quebra de linha que não deveria existir, pois claramente o enunciado que colocou pede que os números sejam separados por ponto-e-vírgula, não com quebras de linhas;