# Buscar uma linha específica em um arquivo .txt e alterar o conteúdo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com um arquivo contendo em cada linha um número de CPF, nome e login, separados por vírgula. Ex:

```
  12345678910, gabriel barbosa, gabriel.barbosa@ifnet.com.br
  09876543211, carlos silva, carlos098@ifnet.com.br
```

O usuário deverá poder alterar o nome, localizando-o atráves do CPF, que será informado pelo próprio. Se o CPF não existir no arquivo, o programa deve informar que não existe.

Usei este código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dois arquivos txt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arq.txt está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O novo_arquivo.txt está vazio.

Executando o código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o conteúdo do arq.txt vai para o novo_arq.txt, com as alterações no nome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí tudo bem, porém, quando vou alterar outra linha, o conteúdo de novo_arq.txt é sobrescrito e a alteração anterior é perdida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que posso fazer para resolver?

Comment: Gabriel, você poderia esclarecer melhor o que precisamente você tentou? Se possível, edite seu post apresentando ao menos uma das tentativas

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ThankfulPrimarySymbol Isso?

Comment: Gabriel, por favor coloque o código e demais arquivos como **texto**.  Colocar como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). De qualquer forma, o problema é que vc sempre lê de arq.txt e atualiza o novo_arq.txt. Se quer que o arquivo original tenha a alteração, no final vc deve renomear o novo_arq.txt para arq.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você tem é um arquivo [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (*Comma-separated values*, literalmente "valores separados por vírgulas"), então uma boa alternativa é usar o [módulo `csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para lê-lo. Um esboço inicial:

```
import csv

with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo)
    for registro in reader:
        cpf = registro[0].strip()
```

Primeiro eu abro o arquivo dentro de um bloco `with`, pois [isso me garante que o arquivo é corretamente fechado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) ao final da execução.

Depois eu uso [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) para iterar pelos registros do arquivo. No caso, a cada iteração do `for`, a variável `registro` será uma lista de strings, sendo que cada elemento da lista é um dos registros (ou seja, o primeiro elemento é o CPF, o segundo é o nome, etc).

Depois eu pego o CPF e uso [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para remover os espaços do início, pois não está claro na pergunta se eles fazem parte do arquivo ou se foi erro de digitação. De qualquer forma, agora bastaria comparar este CPF com o que foi digitado. Ficaria algo assim:

```
import csv

cpf_informado = input('informe o CPF: ')
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo)
    for registro in reader:
        cpf = registro[0].strip()
        if cpf == cpf_informado:
            print('CPF encontrado')
            break
    else:
        print('CPF não encontrado')
```

Se o CPF for encontrado, eu posso sair do *loop* com `break`. Se não for encontrado, ele cai no `else`. E repare que este `else` é do `for`, não do `if`: [em Python isso é possível](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9979970), e ele cai no `else` se o *loop* não for interrompido pelo `break` (no caso, se nenhum CPF for encontrado).

---

Você também disse que quer atualizar o nome quando o CPF for encontrado. Neste caso, uma alternativa é criar outro arquivo contendo os registros atualizados:

```
import csv

cpf_informado = input('informe o CPF: ')
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo, open('novoarquivo.txt', 'w', newline='') as novo_arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo)
    writer = csv.writer(novo_arquivo)
    encontrou = False
    for registro in reader:
        cpf = registro[0].strip()
        if cpf == cpf_informado:
            encontrou = True
            registro[1] = input('Digite o novo nome: ')
        writer.writerow(registro)

    if not encontrou:
        print('CPF não foi encontrado')
```

Agora não dá mais para usar `break` porque eu preciso continuar o *loop* escrevendo todos os registros no novo arquivo.

Esse algoritmo não ficou tão bom assim, pois caso o CPF não seja encontrado, eu criei o novo arquivo à toa. Então você poderia guardar os registros em uma lista, e só criar o novo arquivo se o CPF for encontrado:

```
import csv

cpf_informado = input('informe o CPF: ')
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo)
    encontrou = False
    registros = [registro for registro in reader]
    for registro in registros:
        cpf = registro[0].strip()
        if cpf == cpf_informado:
            encontrou = True
            registro[1] = input('Digite o novo nome: ')

    if not encontrou:
        print('CPF não foi encontrado')
    else:
        with open('novoarquivo.txt', 'w', newline='') as novo_arquivo:
            writer = csv.writer(novo_arquivo)
            for registro in registros:
                writer.writerow(registro)
```

A linha `registros = [registro for registro in reader]` cria a lista `registros`, contendo os registros do arquivo. Ela usa a sintaxe de [*list comprehension*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/112052).

Repare que agora eu só abro o novo arquivo se o CPF for encontrado. Senão, eu só imprimo a mensagem.

Só lembrando que esta solução carrega todo o arquivo na memória, então se o arquivo for muito grande, ela não é adequada, exigindo aí [outras soluções](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17444679). Mas creio que isso já foge ao escopo da pergunta.

---

Quanto ao seu outro problema, de "perder" as alterações feitas, isso acontece porque você sempre lê do arquivo original e atualiza no novo arquivo (ou seja, você lê dos dados originais, e o novo arquivo sempre tem somente a última atualização).

Neste caso, você poderia sobrescrever o próprio arquivo ao final:

```
import csv

cpf_informado = input('informe o CPF: ')
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo)
    encontrou = False
    registros = [registro for registro in reader]
    for registro in registros:
        cpf = registro[0].strip()
        if cpf == cpf_informado:
            encontrou = True
            registro[1] = input('Digite o novo nome: ')

if not encontrou:
    print('CPF não foi encontrado')
else:
    with open('arquivo.txt', 'w', newline='') as novo_arquivo:
        writer = csv.writer(novo_arquivo)
        for registro in registros:
            writer.writerow(registro)
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu leio o arquivo e gero a lista com os registros.

Depois, fora do bloco `with`, eu verifico se o CPF foi encontrado, e sobrescrevo o próprio arquivo com os novos registros. Desta forma você não "perde" as alterações feitas na próxima vez que for alterar outro registro.

Comment: O único problema é que, por exemplo, eu consigo alterar uma linha, mas se eu alterar outra linha, a linha que eu tinha alterado anteriormente volta ao estado inicial...

Comment: @GabrielBarbosa Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel, sua pergunta está um pouco confusa ou não tem informações suficientes. De qualquer forma interpretei e fiz um código simples que busca se o CPF está ou não contido no arquivo. Para testes basta colocar o código a seguir no mesmo diretório do arquivo teste.txt (ou o nome que desejar):

```
print("Hello! Type the CPF number:")
search = input()

print("Searching...")
file = open("teste.txt","r") 
for line in file.readlines():
    if (search in line):
        print("Great! We have found your search!")
        break
```

Comment: O programa deveria pedir o CPF e procurar ele no arquivo, até aí tudo bem, então ele deveria ir até a linha onde o CPF foi encontrado, e pedir um novo nome. Por exemplo, se a linha está assim: 12345678910, gabriel barbosa, gabriel.barbosa@ifnet.com.br, o nome nesse caso é 'gabriel barbosa', então ele pediria um novo nome para o usuário. Vamos supor que ele digitasse "gabriel b", então ficaria: 12345678910, gabriel b, gabriel.barbosa@ifnet.com.br

Comment: Porque vc não usou  line.split(", ") pra separar os dados ?

Answer (score -1):

Olá Gabriel Barbosa e colegas de programação.

Solução:

```py
print("Hello! Type the CPF number:")
search = input()

print("Searching...")
file = open("teste.txt", "r")

def result(search, file):
    resultado = "Not Found"
    index = 0
    lines = file.readlines()
    file_text = "".join(lines)
    for line in lines:
        dados = line.split(", ")
        cpf = dados[0].replace(" ", "")
        if (cpf == search):
            resultado = "Great! We have found your search!"
            print("Your new username:")
            value = input()
            dados[1] = value
            lines[index] = ", ".join(dados)
            file_text = "".join(lines)
            break
        index += 1
    return {
        "resultado": resultado,
        "file_text": file_text
    }


print(result(search, file)["file_text"])
```

Answer (score -1):

Mano quando você usa o with open('arquivotal', 'w'....)
Esse 'w' sobrescreve o arquivo TXT, você precisa usar o 'a' pois ele concatena o arquivo...
Assim:
with open('seuarquivo.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('o que você digitar aqui ele concatena no 
    arquivo e não apaga o que tinha antes!')
É nois...