# Armazenar Variavel em um Arquivo TXT Python

Tags: python, txt

Saudações,Fiz Esse Algoritmo **CODIGO ABAIXO:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)

for url in p:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    time.sleep(10)
    print(r)
```

Que Basicamente Armazenar a Url em Uma Lista e Depois em Um Loop imprimer o Source_Code.

Minha Dúvida e De Como Transformor A Variavel `r` em um Arquivo `TXT`

Comment: with open('arquivo', 'w') as f: f.write(r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a função `open()` passando como parâmetro o nome do arquivo e o modo de abertura, que será neste caso `"w"` para realizar escrita, dessa forma:

```
file = open("arquivo.txt","w")
```

Depois disso, salve as informações no arquivo utilizando o método `write()` e por fim, feche o arquivo com o método `close()` para salvar as alterações. Seu código ficaria assim:

```
file = open("arquivo.txt","w")
file.write(r)
file.close()
```

Comment: Aconselho a usar `with` para abrir arquivos para garantir a liberação de seus recursos. [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/6333) detalha melhor sobre o assunto