# Como acessar as linhas de um arquivo lidas por readlines()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando utilizar o `readlines`, mas dá um erro que não estou entendendo o motivo, vejam:

```py
arquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r")
loginarquivo = arquivo.readlines()[0]
senhaarquivo = arquivo.readlines()[1]
arquivo.close()
```

Neste ponto quando eu dou o `print` no `loginarquivo`, o retorno é a primeira linha do arquivo `cadastros.txt` e funciona normalmente. Porém a segunda variável `senhaarquivo` não consegue ler a segunda linha do arquivo `cadastros.txt` retornando um erro de **list index out of range**.

E o mais curioso é que se eu colocar na linha `senhaarquivo = arquivo.readlines()[1]` o valor de zero entre os `[]` solicitando que ele leia a primeira linha do arquivo que acabou de funcionar com a variável `loginarquivo`, ele irá retornar novamente o **list index out of range**.

Por fim eu percebi que se eu fizer da seguinte maneira:

```py
arquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r")
loginarquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
senhaarquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r").readlines()[1]
arquivo.close()
```

Aí funciona porém não acho que seja a melhor solução entre estas duas, fora que não faz sentido pra mim que funcione escrevendo `open("cadastros.txt, "r")"` mas não funciona quando eu insiro a variável `arquivo` sendo este o mesmo valor dela e ainda acredito que desta segunda maneira ficaríamos com várias instâncias do arquivo `cadastros.txt` abertas na memória.

Poderiam explicar por que o erro ocorre e como fazer funcionar da maneira mais otimizada neste caso a linha `senhaarquivo = arquivo.readlines()[1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método `readlines` vai efetuar a leitura completa do arquivo, retornando uma lista com todas as linhas encontradas, e com isso, ele fica posicionado no final do arquivo.

Ao chamar o método duas vezes, você já estará no final do arquivo após a primeira chamada, não existirá mais nenhuma linha a ser lida, logo o método retorna uma lista vazia e nesse momento que você tem o erro, tentando acessar o índice 1 de uma lista vazia.

---

Para compreender melhor, faça o seguinte teste, exiba no console o valor do retorno do método `readlines` sendo chamada duas vezes seguidas:

```
arquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r")
print(arquivo.readlines()) #Lista das linhas
print(arquivo.readlines()) #Lista vazia
arquivo.close()
```

---

Para corrigir o erro, existem muitas formas diferentes, uma delas seria guardar o retorno do método `readlines` em uma variável e depois acessar os índices dessa variável:

```
arquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r")
linhas = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()

loginarquivo = linhas[0]
senhaarquivo = linhas[1]

print(loginarquivo)
print(senhaarquivo)
```

Uma outra forma, seria utilizar o método `readline`, veja que ele está no singular, ele retorna apenas uma linha:

```
arquivo = open("cadastros.txt", "r")

loginarquivo = arquivo.readline()
senhaarquivo = arquivo.readline()

arquivo.close()

print(loginarquivo)
print(senhaarquivo)
```

> ***Obs:*** Perceba também nesse exemplo que após chamar o método `readline`, o arquivo fica posicionado na próxima linha, não no final do arquivo, com isso eu posso chamar o método novamente.

[Veja esses exemplos online](https://repl.it/repls/SociableGorgeousSquare).

---

> Documentação:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Answer (score 3):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437436/112052) já explicou muito bem o problema de usar [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) várias vezes, mas faltou um pequeno detalhe: tanto `readlines` quando [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline) não eliminam as quebras de linha do arquivo, e as strings retornadas terão esses caracteres.

Por exemplo, se o conteúdo do arquivo for:

```
login
senha
```

E eu lê-lo com `readlines`:

```
with open('cadastros.txt', 'r') as arq:
    linhas = arq.readlines()
    print(linhas)
```

A saída será:

```
['login\n', 'senha']
```

Repare que no `login` há um `\n` no final, que corresponde ao caractere [*LINE FEED*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0a/index.htm) (a quebra de linha). Então se você usar esta string como *login*, provavelmente não dará certo, pois ela terá esse caractere a mais.

> Note também que usei `with`, que [garante que o arquivo é sempre fechado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052), mesmo que ocorra um erro durante a leitura (assim não precisa chamar `close` ao final).

Neste exemplo a senha não possui o `\n` porque no arquivo que usei não dei um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> depois da senha. Mas se tivesse outra linha abaixo dela, a senha também teria o `\n`.

---

Enfim, uma maneira de eliminar as quebras de linha é ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo com [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) e em seguida usar [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) para "quebrar" este conteúdo em linhas (assim as strings não terão o `\n`):

```
with open('cadastros.txt', 'r') as arq:
    linhas = arq.read().splitlines()
    if len(linhas) >= 2: # para garantir que há pelo menos 2 linhas
        login = linhas[0]
        senha = linhas[1]
```

Se quiser, pode trocar as duas últimas linhas por um [*destructuring assignment*](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/python/destructuring-assignment-937c6ae09b2047229e22ed0a120b21be#2e06bc18-bd85-431c-a481-b14958ab3f07):

```
login, senha, *_ = linhas
```

Assim, tanto o `login` quanto a `senha` não terão as quebras de linha.

---

O problema de `readlines` e `read` é que eles carregam todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória. Se o arquivo é pequeno (por exemplo, se você "sabe" que "sempre" terá 2 linhas), não há problema. Mas se o arquivo for grande, pode não valer a pena carregar todo o seu conteúdo para ler somente duas linhas.

Se só quiser ler as duas primeiras linhas e ignorar o restante, pode usar `readline`, como já sugerido na outra resposta, mas não esqueça de eliminar a quebra de linha - uma alternativa é usar [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) para eliminá-la:

```
with open('cadastros.txt', 'r') as arq:
    login = arq.readline().rstrip('\r\n');
    senha = arq.readline().rstrip('\r\n');
```

Eu passei para `rstrip` uma string contendo todos os caracteres a serem removidos do final. No caso, usei `\n` e também o `\r` (o [CARRIAGE RETURN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0d/index.htm)), pois assim eu trato também os casos em que a quebra de linha é `\r\n` (que ocorre tradicionalmente no Windows) ou simplesmente `\r` (no MacOS) - veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4824621).