# Python está quebrando linha aonde não deveria

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tendo dificuldade com a formatação de uma string no Python. Ao processar o comando está quebrando linha aonde não deveria.

O trecho do programa é esse

```
print("neighbor",ip[i],"peer-group BLACKHOLE-ENG",file=arquivo1)
```

Ao invés de aparecer assim:

```
neighbor 10.10.10.10 peer-group BLACKHOLE-ENG
```

Está quebrando a linha e aparecendo assim no arquivo de texto:

```
neighbor 10.10.10.10 
peer-group BLACKHOLE-ENG
```

Já tentei concatenar com `++`, usar o `.format`.

A var ip[i] vem de um arquivo de texto simples no caso só tem uma coluna e um único item para teste já verifiquei esse arquivo e não tem espaço ou quebra de linha.

Segue o código completo

```
i = 0

##criando tabela simples a partir do texto##
with open("pocnagra.txt","r") as arquivo:
  ip = arquivo.readlines()

##salvando arquivo criado##
with open("script_pocnagra.txt","w") as arquivo1:

##loop do script##
  for i in range (1):
   print("configure terminal",file=arquivo1)
   print("router bgp 64578",file=arquivo1)
   print("neighbor",ip[i],"peer-group BLACKHOLE-ENG",file=arquivo1)
   print("neighbor",ip[i],"description POC-NAGRA-NULL0",file=arquivo1)
   print("end",file=arquivo1)
   print("!",file=arquivo1)
   print("configure terminal",file=arquivo1)
   print("ip route",ip[i],"255.255.255.255 181.213.140.89 name BLACKHOLE",file=arquivo1)
   print("end",file=arquivo1)
   print("!",file=arquivo1)
```

Comment: Provavelmente é porque `ip[i]` possui uma quebra de linha no final. Vc poderia usar `strip` para removê-la (e sem saber de onde vem essa informação, não dá pra sugerir muito mais que isso)

Comment: A var ip[i] vem de um arquivo de txt. O arquivo de texto só tem uma coluna com ips, mas para o teste só tem um ip nesse arquivo. Segue o script completo

Comment: Então clique em [edit], e adicione o trecho do arquivo e o código que lê os dados dele

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como acessar as linhas de um arquivo lidas por readlines()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437384/como-acessar-as-linhas-de-um-arquivo-lidas-por-readlines)

Comment: até achei o problema mas não sei resolver quando o comando with pega as linhas do arquivos de texto e gera a tabela para cada item ele está colocando quebra de forma automática

Comment: Exemplo ['8.209.89.185\n', '45.32.160.151\n', '51.159.98.148\n']

Comment: Basta percorrer a lista, e para cada elemento, chame `rstrip` para remover o `\n`. Ou use `splitlines`, como explicado no [link indicado acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/437384/como-acessar-as-linhas-de-um-arquivo-lidas-por-readlines).

Comment: Outra coisa, pra que `for i in range (1)`? Isso só vai executar uma vez, então pra que `for`? Vc só está pegando a primeira linha, é isso mesmo? Se quer pegar só a primeira, pra que ler todas as linhas do arquivo? Por fim, para escrever no arquivo pode usar `write` em vez de `print`, algo assim: https://pastebin.com/W3igeCYt