# Como adicionar texto a uma linha específica em arquivo txt em Python?

Tags: python, txt

Estou tentando armazenar dados em um arquivo txt, mas preciso gravá-los em linhas específicas. Como prosseguir?

Gostaria de fazer algo do tipo:

```
data = open('arquivo.txt', 'a')
data[linha específica].write('Texto desejado')
data.close()
```

Comment: Você poderia só gravar "\n"s até a linha que você quer, e então escrever o seu texto.

Comment: Então, G. Bittencourt, o problema é que o texto tem linhas "ocupadas" que não podem ser substituídas até a linha desejada. Estou fazendo uma espécie de listas em texto.

Comment: Ah sim, perdão, não tinha entendido assim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/439846/112052) sugere que você carregue todo o arquivo para a memória (pois é isso que [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) faz), e depois escreva todas as linhas novamente no mesmo arquivo. Pode até funcionar e não dar problema na maioria dos casos, mas há dois poréns:

- se o arquivo for muito grande, estará gastando memória à toa (podendo até estourar, dependendo do tamanho e da quantidade de arquivos sendo processados)
- ao reescrever todas as linhas novamente no mesmo arquivo, há o risco de corrompê-lo caso ocorra um erro qualquer no meio da escrita (suponha que o arquivo tem 1000 linhas e ao escrever dá um erro na terceira, o arquivo ficará corrompido, com as linhas de 3 a 1000 faltando)

Para o primeiro problema, basta percorrer o arquivo linha a linha. E para o segundo problema, basta criar um arquivo temporário, escrever nele e no final - somente se tudo der certo - renomeá-lo para o arquivo original. Assim, se ocorrer algum erro durante a escrita, somente o arquivo temporário ficará corrompido (e não tem problema, porque ele é temporário mesmo), mas o arquivo original permanecerá intacto.

Então ficaria assim:

```
import shutil, tempfile

def incluir_linha(nome_arquivo, numero_linha, conteudo):
    with open(nome_arquivo) as orig, \
         tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
        for i, line in enumerate(orig): # percorre o arquivo linha a linha
            if i == numero_linha - 1:
                out.write(f'{conteudo}\n')
            out.write(line)

    shutil.move(out.name, nome_arquivo)

# incluir o texto "xyz" na terceira linha do arquivo
incluir_linha('arquivo.txt', 3, 'xyz')
```

<sup>*Baseado em: [How to edit a file in-place](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-edit-file-in-place.html)*</sup>

Usei [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) para abrir os arquivos, pois isso garante que eles serão fechados ao final (mesmo em caso de erro, o que não acontece quando você chama [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) diretamente - a não ser que ele esteja um bloco [`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/compound_stmts.html#finally)).

Depois eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para percorrer as linhas do arquivo ao mesmo tempo em que obtenho o respectivo número dela. O detalhe é que o índice começa do zero, então a primeira linha é zero, a segunda linha é 1, etc (por isso no `if` eu subtraio 1 do `numero_linha`).

Eu também uso o [módulo `tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) para criar o arquivo temporário e [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) para renomear o arquivo ao final.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você precisar separar cada linha do seu arquivo. Para fazer isso, utilize o método `readlines` que te dará uma lista com todas as linhas separadas.

Após isso, basta inserir na lista o texto que deseja com o método `insert` e escrever as linhas dentro da lista com o método `writelines`. Veja o exemplo:

```
linha_especifica = 1
texto = "<SEU TEXTO>"

file = open('arquivo.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

lines.insert(linha_especifica, texto + "\n")

file = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')
file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
```

Comment: Obrigado, Jean!
Não tive esse insight de escrever as linhas novamente no arquivo.
Valeu :D