# Substituir trecho de uma string entre 2 índices

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, substring

Eu possuo uma cadeia de caracteres longa dentro de um arquivo txt, para exemplificar, digamos que minha string seja mais ou menos isso:

```
strg = '123456 BANANA 00 SP'
```

Na posição 14 e 15 temos o `"00"`, que vou precisar substituir lá na frente

A lógica que estou implementando é:

```
import re

#abre e começa a leitura do arquivo
arquivo = open('teste.txt','r')
conteudo = arquivo.read()

#verifica se existe a palavra BANANA
if re.search('\\bBANANA\\b', conteudo, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("ACHOU")
    encontrado = True
else:
    print("NÃO ACHOU")
    encontrado = False

#caso o retorno acima seja true, ele substitui a posição 14 e 15 pela string "22"
if encontrado:    
    splt = conteudo.replace(14:15, "22") #o que eu esperava, mas não funciona!
    print(splt)

arquivo = open('teste.txt', 'w')
arquivo.writelines(conteudo)
arquivo.close()
```

Quando eu chego na parte de dar o `replace` nas posições 14:15 por "22", eu não consigo fazer, pois aparentemente o método `replace` apenas compara as strings e a substitui, e isso não funcionaria pra mim, pois na mesma linha eu posso ter diversos "00" e ele substituiria todos por "22", porém eu preciso que ele mude somente daquela posição específica, ela não se guia por uma cadeia de caracteres.

Qual a melhor forma de eu fazer esse `replace` a partir de uma posição especifica na string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Python, [strings são imutáveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq), então não tem como substituir um pedaço dela. O jeito é criar outra string.

No seu caso, basta pegar o pedaço do início da string até o índice 13, o novo trecho que deve ser colocado, e o pedaço do índice 16 em diante, e concatená-los.

Outro detalhe é que sua variável `encontrado` me parece redundante. Se quer executar alguma coisa somente se algo for encontrado, faça-o diretamente dentro do primeiro `if`:

```
import re

conteudo = '123456 BANANA 00 SP'
if re.search(r'\bBANANA\b', conteudo, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("ACHOU")
    # já faz a substituição aqui mesmo, não precisa da variável "encontrado"
    novo_conteudo = conteudo[:14] + "22" + conteudo[16:]
    print(novo_conteudo) # 123456 BANANA 22 SP
else:
    print("NÃO ACHOU")
```

Usei a [sintaxe de *slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para pegar os trechos da string que me interessam. No caso, `conteudo[:14]` pega do início da string até o índice 13 (o valor final não é incluso) e `conteudo[16:]` pega da posição 16 até o final da string.

---

De maneira geral, para trocar do índice `start` até o índice `end`, basta fazer `string[:start] + novo_trecho + s[end + 1:]`. Se quiser, faça uma função para facilitar:

```
def replace(s, start, end, new):
    return s[:start] + new + s[end + 1:]

if re.search(r'\bBANANA\b', conteudo, re.IGNORECASE):
    print("ACHOU")
    novo_conteudo = replace(conteudo, 14, 15, '22')
    print(novo_conteudo) # 123456 BANANA 22 SP
else:
    print("NÃO ACHOU")
```

Claro que dá para melhorar, incluindo algumas verificações, como: se os índices não ultrapassam o tamanho da string, se `start` é menor que `end`, etc. Mas a ideia geral é essa.

---

Repare também que na regex eu usei um [*raw string literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640) (indicado pelo `r` antes das aspas de abertura), assim o caractere `\` não precisa ser escrito como `\\`.

Quanto ao fato de você estar lendo e escrevendo no mesmo arquivo, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440054/112052) um jeito melhor de fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Se você for aplicar diversas regras, talvez seja melhor ler linha por linha.

O replace ele irá substituir apenas o primeiro que ele encontrar, e não na string inteira. Então você teria que fazer um loop para ele substituir enquanto existe, o que não seria muito diferente de ler o arquivo linha por linha e que te permite aplicar outras regras.

Se o arquivo tem um formato padrão, você pode utilizar o `split()` e substituir os caracteres na posição que você quiser:

`teste.txt`

```
123456 BANANA 00 SP
123456 BANANA 02 RJ
123456 BANANA 03 BH:
```

`python`

```
f = open('teste.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    data = line.split() #quebra a string em uma lista
    data[2] = "XY" #substitui os caracteres que estão na posição 3
    print('arquivo:', line)
    print('dado alterado:', ' '.join(data))
```