# Adicionar character no fim da linha

Tags: python, python-3.x

Saudações,

quando vou adicionar um ";" ao final do arquivo, mesmo especificando que não é pra adicionar caso já termine com ele, ainda é adicionado:

```
newf=""
with open('teste.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        lastchar = line[-1]
        print(lastchar)
        if lastchar != ';':
         newf+=line.strip()+";\n"
        else:
         newf+=line.strip()
    f.close()
with open('teste.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(newf)
    f.close()
```

O texto que é:

```
1;2
2;2;
3;3

Fica

1;2;
2;2;;
3;3;
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Eu não consegui achar erro na lógica, o que está printando para exemplo quando se coloca lastchar?

Comment: algo como:
"nulo
nulo
3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, algumas considerações sobre o seu código:

Se você está usando um *context manager* com `with open(...`, você não precisa fechar o arquivo com `f.close()`. O *context manager* faz isso por você.

Sugiro que você não sobrescreva o arquivo de entrada, principalmente com dados em memória. Se alguma coisa der errado durante a gravação do arquivo final e o programa terminar com erro, você perde os dados processados e o arquivo original. Grave um arquivo temporário e renomeie o arquivo temporário para o original, no fim do processamento.

Na mesma linha do item anterior, não coloque tudo em memória para então começar a escrever no arquivo de destino. Isso funciona bem para um arquivo pequeno, mas se o arquivo tiver 100GB, haja memória... Grave o arquivo linha a linha.

Você também não precisa abrir um arquivo usando um *context manager*, colocar todo o resultado na memória e depois usar outro *context manager* para abrir o mesmo arquivo (ou outro) para escrever o resultado. Abra os dois arquivos, de entrada e de saída no mesmo *context manager*.

**Fazendo funcionar**

O problema é que você só está considerando o caracter de quebra de linha **depois** do `if`. Você poderia remover a quebra de linha antes de testar se o `';'` está lá.

Mas você também pode manter assim, testando a string a partir da penúltima posição, com o método `endswith()` e só remover a quebra nas linhas onde você for adicionar o `';'`. E faça só o `rstrip()`, porque o início da linha não importa.

Depois, adicione a quebra de linha de volta usando `'\n'`, só nas linhas alteradas.

Ficaria assim:

```
with open('teste.txt','r') as inFile, \
     open('teste.tmp.txt', 'w') as outFile:

    for line in inFile:
        if not line.endswith(';', -2, len(line) - 1):
            line = line.rstrip() + ';\n'
        outFile.write(line)
```

Ou, se você quiser programar no modo "garantia de emprego"... :)

```py
with open('teste.txt','r') as inFile, open('teste.tmp.txt', 'w') as outFile: outFile.write(''.join([line.rstrip() + ';\n' if not line.endswith(';', -2, (len(line) - 1)) else line for line in inFile]))
```

Comment: Um detalhe (que não é o foco da pergunta, mas é só pra deixar a resposta mais completa): faltou renomear o arquivo temporário ao final - e para criar o arquivo tmp sugiro o uso do [módulo `tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), tem um exemplo aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440054/112052

Comment: Desculpe a demora na resposta, mas funcionou corretamente e de forma muito mais simples. Passei a aderir o with não apenas em python como também em VB. Muito obrigado pelas dicas de usabilidade.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que cada final de linha do arquivo tem uma quebra de linha("\n"). Uma solução é chamar o método `replace` do `str` para substituir o "\n" por "".

Answer (score 0):

Não parece ter nenhum erro na sua lógica, mas o fato dele estar retornando falso sempre no if significa que a variável `lastchar` não é ponto e vírgula como você esperava. Muito provavelmente isso está acontecendo porque `line` tem espaços em branco no final, ou seja se você fizer `lastchar = line.rstrip()[-1]`, deve resolver o problema.