# Python - Retornar todas as cidades de um arquivo.txt em um range de porcentagem

Tags: python

Estou tendo dificuldades para retornar todas as cidades com a porcentagem dentro de um range que o usuário passou. O meu arquivo texto é composto por estas cidades e suas respectivas taxas de isolamento:

```
São Paulo = 30
Guarujá = 47
Belo Horizonte = 38
Rio de Janeiro = 45
Curitiba = 44
Fortaleza = 47
Recife = 50
```

Com isso, tenho que fazer um código que retorne todas as cidades em um período de porcentagem passado pelo usuário. Abaixo o meu código:

```
taxa1 = input("Digite um intervalo de taxa de isolamento, sendo <50%, 50% <= x <= 60% e >60%")

arquivo1 = open('arquvio.txt','r')
y = 0
for linha1 in arquivo1:
    linha1 = linha1.rstrip()
    if taxa1 in linha1:
        y = y + 1
        print ("Cidade: ", linha1)
print("\nForam encontradas", y ,"Cidades")
```

Se o usuário digitar 45 por exemplo, o código acima apenas retornaria a cidade que possui taxa de isolamento de 45%. Porém, quero que ele retorne todas as cidades abaixo de 50% uma vez que o usuário digite "<50%". Quero que o código retorne todas as cidades que tenham a taxa de isolamento entre 50% e 60%, uma vez que o usuário digite "50% <= x <= 60%", e assim por diante.

Answer (score 2):

Para comparar se o isolamento é maior, menor ou igual a determinado valor, você precisa isolá-lo da linha e convertê-lo para número. Uma alternativa é usar [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar a linha em partes, e em seguida converter a parte relevante para [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```
taxa = input("Digite um intervalo de taxa de isolamento, sendo <50%, 50% <= x <= 60% e >60%")
cont = 0
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        isolamento = int(linha.split('=')[1])
        if (taxa == '<50%' and isolamento < 50) or \
           (taxa == '50% <= x <= 60%' and 50 <= isolamento <= 60) or \
           (taxa == '>60%' and isolamento > 60):
            cont += 1

print(f'{cont} cidades com isolamento {taxa}')
```

Eu faço o `split` pelo caractere `=`, separando a linha em duas partes: a primeira com o nome da cidade e a segunda com a taxa de isolamento. Em seguida eu pego a segunda parte (`[1]` - pois em listas o primeiro índice é zero) e converto para `int`.

Depois eu contabilizo conforme o critério da taxa. Se a taxa deve levar em conta valores menores que 50, eu verifico se o isolamento é menor que 50. Se deve considerar valores entre 50 e 60, eu verifico isso, e assim por diante.

---

Fiz assim porque parece que só vai contabilizar um critério por vez. Mas se a ideia é contabilizar os 3 separadamente, então você precisa de 3 contadores:

```
faixa1 = faixa2 = faixa3 = 0
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        isolamento = int(linha.split('=')[1])
        if isolamento < 50:
            faixa1 += 1
        elif 50 <= isolamento <= 60:
            faixa2 += 1
        else:
            faixa3 += 1

if taxa == '<50%':
    # mostrar resultado da faixa1
elif taxa == '50% <= x <= 60%':
    # mostrar resultado da faixa2
elif taxa == '>60%':
    # mostrar resultado da faixa3
```

Este código não valida se a taxa de isolamento é negativa (se for, ela entrará na contagem da faixa 1).

---

Repare também que usei [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052), que garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final.

Lembrando que o código não valida o formato das linhas (se ela não estiver no formato correto, o `split` não retornará uma lista com 2 elementos e dará erro ao tentar pegar o segundo, ou se o segundo elemento não for um número, também dará erro, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Tentar analisar símbolos em um string como `"<"` ou `"%"` é, na minha opinião, mais trabalhoso do que vale a pena. Quanto mais você conseguir limitar o input do usuário, melhor.

É mais simples avisar o usuário que o primeiro input é o limite inferior e o segundo é o superior. Considere a seguinte abordagem:

1) Ler os valores do arquivo txt pra dentro de um dicionário:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: 
    dados = {line.split(' = ')[0]: int(line.split(' = ')[1]) for line in f}
```

2) Escolher o limite superior e inferior para a porcentagem:

```
limite_inf = int(input('Digite o limite inferior: '))
limite_sup = int(input('Digite o limite superior: '))
```

3) Encontrar e retornar os valores e cidades que estão dentro dos limites:

```
dados_dentro = [(c, v) for c, v in dados.items() if limite_inf < v < limite_sup]
```

4) Mostrar os resultados

```
print(f"Foram encontradas {len(dados_dentro)} Cidades:")
for cidade, valor in dados_dentro:
    print(cidade, '->', valor)
```

Código completo:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: 
    dados = {line.split(' = ')[0]: int(line.split(' = ')[1]) for line in f}

limite_inf = int(input('Digite o limite inferior: '))
limite_sup = int(input('Digite o limite superior: '))

dados_dentro = [(c, v) for c, v in dados.items() if limite_inf < v < limite_sup]

print(f"Foram encontradas {len(dados_dentro)} cidades:")
for cidade, valor in dados_dentro:
    print(cidade, '->', valor)
```

Se você realmente quiser a flexibilidade de escolher entre uma taxa pontual ou um *range* de taxas, então gere essa opções em um menu prévio, como:

```
resposta = input('''
Qual opção você deseja? Digite o número correspondente:
1) taxa pontual
2) range de taxas
sua opção: ''')
if resposta == '1':
     # código da taxa pontual
elif resposta == '2':
     # código do range de taxas
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função no seu código para encontrar todas as cidades que possuem uma taxa dentro de um determinado range definido por você ou pelo usuário.

Dentro dessa função basta percorrer as cidades e ir verificando se a taxa da cidade em questão está dentro do range definido pelo usuário com a condicional: `start <= taxa <= stop`.

Para fazer esta verificação precisaremos obter a taxa das cidades no tipo [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), separando-a do nome da cidade utilizando o método [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) e removendo a quebra de linha no final da string.

```
# A variável cidades é um iterável com todas as linhas do arquivo.

for cidade in cidades:
    taxa = int(cidade.split(" = ")[-1].replace("\n", ""))
    if start <= taxa <= stop: cidades_encontradas.append(cidade)
```

Para a função ficar mais dinâmica, podemos definir `None` como valor padrão para o ponto de parada do range. Caso o usuário não passe um valor para o parâmetro `stop`, essa variável receberá posteriormente o valor passado para o parâmetro `start`.

```
def encontrar_cidades(cidades, start, stop = None):
    cidades_encontradas = []
    stop = start if not stop else stop
```

Isso faz com que o usuário não seja obrigado a declarar um range, podendo realizar buscas de cidades que possuam uma taxa específica. Veja o código completo da função abaixo:

```
def encontrar_cidades(cidades, start, stop = None):

    cidades_encontradas = []
    stop = start if not stop else stop

    for cidade in cidades:
        taxa = int(cidade.split(" = ")[-1].replace("\n", ""))
        if start <= taxa <= stop: cidades_encontradas.append(cidade)

    return cidades_encontradas
```

---

Agora que já criamos a função responsável por encontrar as cidades com base na taxa de isolamento, precisaremos aplica-la ao programa.

Para fazer isso, basta criar algumas condicionais para cada tipo de `input` digitado pelo usuário, definindo os argumentos de `start` e `stop` com base na entrada do usuário:

```
taxa = input("Digite um intervalo de taxa de isolamento:")

if "<50%" == taxa: start, stop = 0, 50                # <50%             | (0, 50)
elif ">60%" == taxa: start, stop = 60, 100            # >60%             | (60, 100)
elif "50% <= x <= 60%" in taxa: start, stop = 50, 60  # 50% <= x <= 60%  | (50, 60)
else: start, stop = int(taxa), None                   # Taxa X           | (x, x)

cidades_encontradas = encontrar_cidades(conteudo, start, stop)               
print("\nCidades encontradas:", cidades_encontradas)
```

Como a função que criamos nos dá liberdade para utilizarmos o range que quisermos, você pode dar mais flexibilidade para o usuário pesquisar cidades com o range que ele desejar.

Veja o exemplo abaixo para entender o quero dizer:

```
if "<" == taxa[0]:
    taxa = int(taxa[1:].replace("%", ""))
    start, stop = 0, taxa
```

Neste exemplo, se o usuário digitar `"<"` antes da taxa, significa que o usuário quer cidades com a taxa menor ou igual a X. Dessa forma, não precisamos nos limitar a pesquisar por taxas `"<50%"`.

---

Lembre-se de que é importante sempre fechar o arquivo após ter feito seu uso. Para fechar o arquivo, você pode utilizar o método [`close`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm) ou o [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/157404) para fechar o arquivo automaticamente.

```
# Utilizando o método "close" para fechar o arquivo.

arquivo = open('arquivo.txt')
conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()

# Utilizando a declaração "with" para fechar o arquivo.

with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
```

Answer (score -1):

Pensei em uma solução possível, mas que só funciona caso não haja linhas em branco no arquivo de texto importado:

```
opcao = input('''
Escolha uma das opções de intervalo de isolamento (A, B ou C)
A) menor que 50%;
B) entre 50% e 60%;
C) maior que 60%
Opção escolhida:''').strip().lower()

arquivo = open('arquivo.txt','r')
y = 0
for linha in arquivo:
    isolamento = int(linha[-3:])
    if opcao == 'a':
        if isolamento < 50:
            y = y + 1
            print ("\nCidade: ", linha)
    elif opcao == 'b':
        if 50 <= isolamento <= 60:
            y = y + 1
            print("\nCidade: ", linha)
    elif opcao == 'c':
        if isolamento > 60:
            y = y + 1
            print("\nCidade: ", linha)

print("\nForam encontradas", y ,"Cidades")
```