# Quero saber se é possível diminuir meu código?

Tags: python

Estava fazendo o seguinte exercício:

> Escreva um programa que leia um arquivo e mostre as letras em ordem decrescente de frequência. Seu programa deve converter todas as entradas para Caixa baixa e apenas contar as letras de a à z. Não conte espaços, dígitos, pontuações, ou qualquer coisa que não seja uma letra do alfabeto. Encontre textos simples de diversas línguas diferentes e veja como a frequência de letras varia entre os idiomas.

Cheguei a este código e gostaria de saber como posso simplificá-lo.

```
arquivo= input("Insira o endereço de arquivo: ").strip('"')
texto= open(arquivo)
frase=[]
palavra= []
ordem= []
l= []
letras= {}

# Lê cada linha do texto
for line in texto:
    line.rstrip()
    frase= line.strip()
    
#Lê cada palavra da linha
    for i in range(len(frase)):
        palavra= frase[i].lower()
        
#Lê cada letra da palavra
        for j in range(len(palavra)):
            if palavra[j] == ' ' or palavra[j] == '\n' : continue
            letras[palavra[j]]= letras.get(palavra[j], 0)+1

#Organiza tudo em uma lista de tuples
for k,v in letras.items():
    l.append((v,k))
    
l.sort(reverse=True)
for k,v in l:
    print(k,v)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você poderia abrir o arquivo dentro de um bloco `with`, que [garante que o arquivo será fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052).

Depois, você está fazendo um *loop* a mais à toa. O `for line in texto` percorre cada linha do arquivo, e `line` será uma string. Como você quer contar as letras, basta percorrer esta string com outro `for` e verificar se cada caractere é uma letra (não há necessidade de separar a linha em palavras, pois você não quer contar as palavras e sim as letras, então tanto faz se as letras estão em uma palavra ou outra).

E para ordenar as chaves com base na quantidade, basta usar o parâmetro  `key` (não precisa criar outra estrutura para isso). Ficaria assim:

```
arquivo = # ler nome do arquivo
letras = {}
with open(arquivo) as arq:
    for line in arq: # para cada linha do arquivo
        for char in line.lower(): # para cada caractere da linha
            if 'a' <= char <= 'z': # se for letra
                letras[char] = letras.get(char, 0) + 1

# ordena o dicionário 
for letra in sorted(letras, key=letras.get, reverse=True):
    print(letra, letras[letra])
```

A ordenação usa `key=letras.get`, o que indica que vou usar o valor (e não a chave) do dicionário para a ordenação.

---

Outra alternativa é usar um [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), que serve justamente para contar ocorrências de elementos:

```
from collections import Counter

letras = Counter()
with open(arquivo) as arq:
    for line in arq:
        for char in line.lower():
            if 'a' <= char <= 'z':
                letras.update(char)

for letra, qtd in letras.most_common():
    print(letra, qtd)
```

Para ordenar, basta usar [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common), que retorna uma lista de tuplas, contendo a letra e a respectiva quantidade, já ordenadas da mais comum para a menos comum.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas!!