# Copiar linha e gravar a mesma linha em outro arquivo usando python

Tags: python, arquivo

Preciso abrir um arquivo, ler determinada linha e gravar essa mesma linha em outro arquivo. Porém, ao final da linha preciso adicionar um caractere (um asterisco "*").

```
leitura = open(arqfasta, 'r')
linha2 = leitura.readlines()[1]
leitura.close()
print(linha2)
#linha2 quanda como valor a segunda linha do arquivo fasta que contém a sequencia de aa.

arquivo = open(arqali, 'w')
arquivo.write('>P1;pep' + str(i) + '\n')
arquivo.write('sequence:pep' + str(i) + ':::::::0.00: 0.00 \n')
arquivo.write(linha2 + '*')
arquivo.close()
```

Ao executar o código, obtenho essa saída no arquivo (como está na imagem):

```
IIISVLKGSYIFTSDFIRYLGDCGLPHVVDFVRLASYNSGTK
*
```

[image]

Sendo que gostaria de obter esse asterisco ao final da string:

```
IIISVLKGSYIFTSDFIRYLGDCGLPHVVDFVRLASYNSGTK*
```

Eu não consigo entender o porque que ele coloca o caractere final (o asterisco) na próxima linha, sendo que o correto seria colocar ao final da string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines) lê todas as linhas do arquivo, retornando-as em uma lista. Mas como você só quer a segunda linha, não precisa ler todas:

```
with open(arqfasta) as leitura, open(arqali, 'w') as saida:
    next(leitura) # ignora a primeira linha
    linha2 = next(leitura).rstrip('\r\n') # lê a segunda linha
```

Como [um arquivo é iterável](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16994552), ao chamar [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) eu obtenho o próximo "item" de um iterável (que no caso do arquivo, será a próxima linha). Ou seja, na primeira vez eu obtenho a primeira linha (e como não estou guardando esse valor em nenhuma variável, o mesmo é ignorado) e na segunda vez eu obtenho a segunda linha, que é o que você quer.

Usei [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) para remover a quebra de linha do final (já que é por isso que a sua saída escrevia o asterisco em outra linha, porque as quebras de linha também são retornadas da leitura). E também usei `with` para abrir o arquivo, [pois assim ele já será fechado automaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052).

Por fim, você pode escrever no outro arquivo usando o mesmo `with`:

```
with open(arqfasta) as leitura, open(arqali, 'w') as saida:
    next(leitura)
    linha2 = next(leitura).rstrip('\r\n')
    saida.write(f'>P1;pep{i}\n')
    saida.write(f'sequence:pep{i}:::::::0.00: 0.00 \n')
    saida.write(f'{linha2}*')
```

Usei [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) para formatar a saída (disponível a partir do Python 3.6), assim você evita a concatenação de strings. Se estiver usando uma versão anterior a 3.6, pode usar [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
with open(arqfasta) as leitura, open(arqali, 'w') as saida:
    next(leitura)
    linha2 = next(leitura).rstrip('\r\n')
    saida.write('>P1;pep{}\n'.format(i))
    saida.write('sequence:pep{}:::::::0.00: 0.00 \n'.format(i))
    saida.write('{}*'.format(linha2))
```

---

Se quiser uma linha qualquer (não necessariamente a segunda), pode generalizar a solução usando o [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

n_linha = 5 # obter a quinta linha
with open(arqfasta) as leitura, open(arqali, 'w') as saida:
    try:
        linha2 = next(islice(leitura, n_linha - 1, n_linha)).rstrip('\r\n')

        saida.write('>P1;pep{}\n'.format(i))
        saida.write('sequence:pep{}:::::::0.00: 0.00 \n'.format(i))
        saida.write('{}*'.format(linha2))
    except StopIteration:
        print(f'arquivo não tem {n_linha} linhas')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a função rstrip() para remover todos os espaços, novas linhas e tubulações.

Sempre que quiser "ver" se existe qualquer tipo de espaço em branco em uma string tente trasforma-lá em uma lista:

```
palavra = 'teste \n\t\r'
print(palavra)
print([palavra])
print([palavra.rstrip()])
```

Tente:

```
leitura = open(arqfasta, 'r')
#  usando o rstrip()
linha2 = leitura.readlines()[1].rstrip()
leitura.close()
print(linha2)
#linha2 quanda como valor a segunda linha do arquivo fasta que contém a sequencia de aa.

arquivo = open(arqali, 'w')
arquivo.write('>P1;pep' + str(i) + '\n')
arquivo.write('sequence:pep' + str(i) + ':::::::0.00: 0.00 \n')
arquivo.write(linha2 + '*')
arquivo.close()
```