# Comparando strings

Tags: python, xml, txt

Ola eu tenho um  programa para verificar se existe uma string dentro de um arquivo assim:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#Bibliotecas
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

text = input("Coloque o diretorio do fisico: ").strip('"')
arquivo = open(text,"r", encoding="utf8")
for linha in arquivo:
    lista = linha
    
#localiza arquivo,lista todos os itens
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()
print('\n')

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text.strip('000').strip('.')
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

#importa XML, obtem os campos EAN,quatidade    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if lista is None:
        if lista in EAN:
            print(EAN)
            print("EAN encontrado!")
            #print("#------------------------------#")
        else:
            print(lista)
            print("EAN nao encontrado!")
            #print("#------------------------------#")
    else:
        print(lista)
        print("EAN nao encontrado!")
        #print("#------------------------------#")
#obtem o campo EAN e verifica se foi encontrado ou nao.
```

Mais o problema é que nao importa se os dados sao iguais, os codigo ainda responde que não encontra e eu nao sei o por que.

O XML:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200811625533000185550010000043291000219014" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 01</cProd>
<cEAN/>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC MISTA (FURADA + SUP. BORBOLETA)</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>20.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>22.0000</vUnCom>
<vProd>440.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib/>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>20.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>22.0000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
<imposto>
...
</imposto>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 02</cProd>
<cEAN>7898622140258</cEAN>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC DIANTEIRA</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>10.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>26.9000</vUnCom>
<vProd>269.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898622140258</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>10.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>26.9000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
```

O arquivo TXT:

```
None    
7898622140258
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu agradeço por favor

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do primeiro arquivo (o apontado por `text`)? A ideia é ver quais palavras desse arquivo aparecem no XML?

Comment: atualizei com o txt, sim essa é a ideia

Comment: Esse `None` no arquivo quer dizer que se o EAN for vazio ele também deve ser encontrado?

Comment: Esse `none` pode vim do xml por isso eu fiz um `if` para verificar se for `none` caso seja ela não sera procurado

Comment: Se `EAN` for `None` quer dizer que a tag é vazia então não precisaria nem ter isso no primeiro arquivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, isso aqui pelo jeito está errado:

```
for linha in arquivo:
    lista = linha
```

Você lê todas as linhas do arquivo, mas a cada iteração você sobrescreve o valor de `lista`. No final, ela só terá a última linha lida.

Se a ideia é ter uma lista das palavras a serem buscadas, então crie uma lista com o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
with open(text,"r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    lista = [ linha.strip() for linha in arquivo ]
```

Usei `with` para abrir o arquivo, [pois assim ele já será fechado automaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052). E usei [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para eliminar espaços no início e fim, além das quebras de linha que também são retornadas quando se lê de um arquivo.

Depois, ao ler o XML, basta ver se o `EAN` está na lista (você estava fazendo o contrário, vendo se a lista estava em `EAN`):

```
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text.strip('000').strip('.')
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

    if EAN in lista: # verifica se o EAN está na lista
        print(EAN)
        print("EAN encontrado!")
    else:
        print("EAN nao encontrado!")
```

---

Detalhe: a primeira linha do arquivo txt irá resultar na string `"None"` (e não no valor `None` do Python), então eu acho que essa linha pode ser removida de lá, pois não faz sentido. Se o valor de `EAN` for `None`, quer dizer que a tag é vazia, e ai ela nem estará na lista (ou seja, o `if EAN in lista` já é o suficiente para saber se ele está na lista ou não).

Comment: Verdade eu estava tendo a logica inversa, esse **detalhe** nao precisa ser verificado mesmo