# Procurando string dentro de outra string Python

Tags: python, xml, txt

Ola eu tenho um programa para verificar se existe uma string dentro de um arquivo assim:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#Bibliotecas
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#text = input("Coloque o diretorio do fisico: ").strip('"')
arquivo = open(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Videos\arquivo_text\contagem_11.08.20-09.03.36(2) - Copia.txt","r", encoding="utf8")
for linha in arquivo:
    lista = linha.strip('[]').strip('\n')
    #print(lista[:13])
    
#localiza arquivo,lista todos os itens
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(XML)
root = tree.getroot()
print('\n')

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    quantidade = det.find('.//nfe:qCom', ns).text.strip('000').strip('.')
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

#importa XML, obtem os campos EAN,quatidade    
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if EAN is not None:
        if EAN in lista[:13]:
            print(EAN)
            print("EAN encontrado!")
            #print("#------------------------------#")
        else:
            print(EAN)
            print("EAN INVALIDO!")
            #print("#------------------------------#")
    else:
        print(EAN)
        print("EAN INVALIDO!")
        #print("#------------------------------#")

#obtem o campo EAN e verifica se foi encontrado ou nao.
```

ele estava funcionado mais eu precisei mudar um pouco a logica e por isso comecei a utilizar `if EAN in lista[:13]:`
no lugar de `if EAN in lista:` pois como o retorno e só de valores numéricos erá possível ele se confundir. Mas não consigo fazer mais funcionar eu dei um `print(lista[:13])`é o que me parece que o retorno do txt esta ok.
O XML:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200811625533000185550010000043291000219014" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 01</cProd>
<cEAN/>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC MISTA (FURADA + SUP. BORBOLETA)</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>20.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>22.0000</vUnCom>
<vProd>440.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib/>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>20.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>22.0000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
<imposto>
...
</imposto>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
<prod>
<cProd>ET-CAM 02</cProd>
<cEAN>7898622140258</cEAN>
<xProd>CAMERA ESTAC DIANTEIRA</xProd>
<NCM>85258029</NCM>
<CEST>2106300</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>UNI</uCom>
<qCom>10.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>26.9000</vUnCom>
<vProd>269.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>7898622140258</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>UNI</uTrib>
<qTrib>10.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>26.9000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
</prod>
```

O arquivo TXT:

```
None    20
7898622140258   10
7898622140630   10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que já falei em [outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/469818/112052), esse `for` está errado:

```
for linha in arquivo:
    lista = linha.strip('[]').strip('\n')
```

Desta forma, a variável `lista` é sobrescrita a cada iteração do `for`, e no final ela só terá uma única string, correspondente à última linha do arquivo.

E eu também já sugeri que use `with`, pois assim [o arquivo é fechado automaticamente ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052). Enfim, se a ideia é ter uma linha do arquivo em cada linha, guarde tudo em uma lista.

E se o conteúdo do arquivo é esse:

```
None    20
7898622140258   10
7898622140630   10
```

E você só quer a primeira parte, pode usar [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar em 2 partes, e só pegar a primeira. Usando `[:13]` vai acabar pegando a primeira linha inteira, pois ela tem menos que 13 caracteres.

Outro detalhe é que na primeira linha o `None` será convertido para a string `"None"`, e não o valor `None` do Python. Mas se o valor do `EAN` for `None`, ele já não estará na lista, e no seu código você parece tratar `None` como inválido, então eu acho que a primeira linha pode ser removida do arquivo:

```
with open('contagem.txt', "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    lista = [ linha.split()[0] for linha in arquivo ]

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('nfe.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

    if EAN in lista:
        print(f"EAN encontrado: {EAN}")
    else:
        print(f"EAN INVALIDO: {EAN}")
```

Se `EAN` for `None`, ele não estará na lista, e aí ele já será inválido. Não precisa de um `if` específico para este caso.

E usando `split`, eu já separo cada linha em duas partes (usando os espaços como separador), e aí eu pego somente a primeira, que parece ser a parte que interessa (lembrando que a primeira linha do txt pode ser eliminada).

---

Só tem um detalhe: se o arquivo tiver alguma linha vazia, o `split` retornará uma lista vazia e dará erro ao acessar o índice zero. Então você pode incluir um tratamento para isso:

```
def tratar_linha(linha):
    dados = linha.split()
    if len(dados) > 0:
        return dados[0]
    return None

lista = []
with open('contagem.txt', "r", encoding="utf8") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        dado = tratar_linha(linha)
        if dado is not None:
            lista.append(dado)
```

Assim você só adiciona os dados se tiver algo na linha.

Comment: sobre o `None` eu tinha esse por que pode vim um valor vazio do xml

Comment: @ValterFerreira Mas um valor vazio no XML é válido ou inválido?

Comment: um valor vazio no XML é invalido e eu tbm testei o que me mostrou me retornando o seguinte erro: `File "c:/Users/Expedição/Videos/python/Consulta_Interface.py", line 7, in <listcomp>
    lista = [ linha.split()[0] for linha in arquivo ]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @ValterFerreira Esse erro acontece se tiver uma linha em branco no arquivo, pois aí o  `split` retorna uma lista vazia. De qualquer forma, se `None` ou vazio é inválido, o código que eu fiz já serve, pois esses valores não estarão na lista

Comment: @ValterFerreira Atualizei a resposta com uma alternativa para tratar as linhas em branco (mas acho que o ideal seria removê-las do arquivo)

Comment: @ValterFerreira Ops, estava incompleto, agora sim atualizei o código completo

Comment: Eu entendi que esse acontece por causa que a lista não pode armazenar vazio né, mas vem um vazio do xml, não sendo possível fazer um `split` pois da este erro acima, entao como eu resolvo? converto a lista em uma string?

Comment: @ValterFerreira O split não é no xml, é no txt. Eu leio o txt e construo a lista com os valores **válidos**, por isso não precisa ter vazio nem None nessa lista. No xml, se o campo vem vazio, o valor dele será `None`, e como na lista eu não coloquei `None`, ele não vai entrar no `if EAN in lista` e será considerado inválido (como parece ser o que vc quer). Não é isso que vc precisa?

Comment: agora sim entendi eu nao tinha visto a alteração desculpa