# Ler arquivo com list comprehension só funciona na primeira vez

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

```
fhand = open('text.txt', mode = 'r')
txtfile = [item.split()[0] for item in fhand]
txtfile2 = [item.split()[1] for item in fhand]
print(txtfile)
print(txtfile2)
```

Por que que o segundo *list comprehension* não está funcionando?

Mesmo se for exatamente igual, até o mesmo índice, o `txtfile2` sempre aparece como uma lista vazia quando coloco ele no `print`.

Comment: `fhand` é um gerador e geradores só podem ser iterados apenas uma vez. Com a primeira list comprehession você já consome todo o seu gerador, por isso o segundo fica vazio. Como está usando o mesmo valor nas duas listas, o ideal é que faça ambas as lógicas em apenas um laço de repetição.

Comment: @Woss Negativo, `fhand` é um [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper). Diferente de um objeto da classe `generator`, caso seja chamado o método `seek`, o ponteiro pode voltar para a posição inicial da *stream*.

Comment: O objetivo do programa é quebrar o texto no arquivo em linhas ou em palavras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois que você faz o primeiro `for`:

```
txtfile = [item.split()[0] for item in fhand]
```

O arquivo será lido até o fim. Então na próxima iteração não haverá mais nada a ser lido, e por isso a segunda lista fica vazia (imagine que `fhand` possui um "ponteiro interno" que indica a posição do arquivo em que ele está: ao fazer um `for`, todo o arquivo é lido e esse "ponteiro" estará apontando para o final do arquivo, por isso o segundo `for` não encontra mais nada para ler).

Nesse caso, uma alternativa é não usar *list comprehension*, e processar cada linha do arquivo de modo a obter os dados de cada uma das listas, e inseri-los separadamente:

```
txtfile = []
txtfile2 = []
with open('text.txt', mode='r') as fhand:
    for item in fhand:
        itens = item.split()
        txtfile.append(itens[0])
        txtfile2.append(itens[1])
print(txtfile)
print(txtfile2)
```

Note que usei `with`, que [garante que o arquivo será fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052).

---

Claro que se quiser, dá para fazer usando *list comprehension*:

```
with open('text.txt', mode='r') as fhand:
    txtfile, txtfile2 = map(list, zip(*[ item.split() for item in fhand ]))
```

Primeiro eu crio uma lista contendo as linhas devidamente *splitadas*, depois eu passo esta lista para [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), que retorna tuplas contendo os elementos de cada uma dessas sublistas (a primeira tupla contém o primeiro elemento do `split` de cada uma das linhas, e a segunda tupla contém o segundo), e por fim mapeio estas tuplas para `list`, para que se tornem listas, que por sua vez são colocadas em `txtfile` e `txtfile2`.

Mas na minha opinião é mais simples fazer o primeiro *loop* acima. Entendo que *list comprehensions* são legais e tal, mas você não deveria forçar o uso de algum recurso se este não se mostrar uma boa alternativa (e no caso, acredito que não seja, pois acho que o código ficou desnecessariamente mais complicado).

---

Como disseram nos comentários, uma outra alternativa é usar [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.seek) para que o "ponteiro" volte para a posição inicial do arquivo:

```
fhand = open('text.txt', mode = 'r')
txtfile = [item.split()[0] for item in fhand]

fhand.seek(0) # volta para o início do arquivo
txtfile2 = [item.split()[1] for item in fhand]
```

Só que aí você irá ler o arquivo duas vezes (e irá fazer o `split` em todas as linhas novamente), o que nesse caso me parece desnecessário, pois com a solução anterior você lê o arquivo apenas uma vez e já faz tudo que precisa.