# Python - Não funciona a partir do for

Tags: python, for

```
import os, sys, string

# coding: utf-8
from typing import TextIO

lista: TextIO = open("C:\\Users\\Eunice\\Desktop\\contas.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")

print(lista.readlines())
linha = lista.readlines()

for linha in lista:
    arquivo = open("C:\\Users\\Eunice\\Desktop\\siga\\seguindo\\user_-_data\\database\\login.ini", "w")    
    arquivo.write("[headers]" "\ntitle = Config File \n" "\ncompression = yes\n""\ncompression_level = 9\n" "\n[configuracoes]\n""\nlineedit_login = email\n""\nlineedit_senha = senha\n""\ntexteditcontas =", linha, "\n senha\n")
    arquivo = open(arquivo, "r")
    print(arquivo)
    arquivo.close()
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Eunice\Desktop\siga\siga2\seguindo.exe")`
```

Tenho esse código, até o `lista.readlines` funciona, exibe a lista, porém depois só executa o `os.startfile`, não sei o que fazer

Comment: `lista: TextIO = open(....` não deveria ser `lista = open(.....`

Comment: Basicamente, é o mesmo problema da pergunta indicada no box azul acima: quando você chama `readlines`, ele lê todo o conteúdo do arquivo, então quando chamar de novo ou fazer o `for`, não há mais nada a ser lido.

Comment: Troca o seu `for linha in lista:` por `while linha:` que vai funcionar

Comment: @Evilmaax `while linha` não resolve ([veja](https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/Loop#main.py)) - o problema é que ele usou `readlines`, que lê todo o conteúdo do arquivo, e aí quando chega no `for`, não há mais nada a ser lido. Então ou ele só chama `readlines` uma vez (e no `for` ele usa a lista retornada), ou ele não usa `readlines` e faz o `for` diretamente.

Comment: Aproveitando, considere usar `with` para abrir os arquivos, pois ele [garante que eles serão fechados ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052). E como vc abre o arquivo de saída toda hora dentro do `for`, e com a opção `w`, ele será sobrescrito a cada iteração. Se não for essa a intenção, abra apenas uma vez fora do `for`