# word_tokenize criando tokens com apenas um caractere em vez de palavras

Tags: python, nltk

Quando crio a lista abaixo, com os tokens de múltiplos textos `.txt`, o `for loop` *tokeniza* os caracteres e não as palavras propriamente ditas:

```
import glob
import nltk
      
l = []

for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\lima\\*.txt'):
    texts = open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8').read()
        for text in texts:
            tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(text, language='portuguese')
            l.extend(tokenize)

    print(l)
```

output:

```
['N', 'ã', 'o', 'f', 'o', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'n', 'ã', 'o', 'é',]
etc
```

Já tentei com o `append`, mas ele cria uma lista de listas de caracteres. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: @jfaccioni, obrigado pela dica sobre a formatação do texto como um todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read) pega todo o conteúdo do arquivo e retorna em uma única string. Ou seja, `texts` é uma string.

Ao fazer `for text in texts` você está percorrendo os caracteres de `texts`, um a um. Ou seja, a cada iteração do `for`, a variável `text` conterá apenas um caractere. Por isso que o `word_tokenize` acaba gerando *tokens* com apenas um caractere.

Se a ideia é *tokenizar* todo o texto, não faça este `for`, passe toda a string de uma vez:

```
l = []

for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\lima\\*.txt'):
    texts = open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8').read()
    tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(texts, language='portuguese')
    l.extend(tokenize)

print(l)
```

---

Se os arquivos forem muito grandes, não recomendo ler tudo de uma vez com `read()` (pois aí estará carregando todo o conteúdo para a memória). Uma opção é ler o arquivo linha a linha, e aí sim precisa de um *loop*:

```
tokens = []

for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\lima\\*.txt'):
    with open(file ,'r',encoding='utf-8') as arq: # abre o arquivo
        for linha in arq: # para cada linha do arquivo
            tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(linha, language='portuguese')
            tokens.extend(tokenize)

print(tokens)
```

Repare que é diferente do seu *loop*: no seu, o `for` itera em cada caractere da string. No meu, estou iterando por cada linha, e passando toda a linha para `word_tokenize`.

Também usei `with` para abrir o arquivo, pois isso [garante que ele será fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052) (mesmo se der erro durante a leitura). E mudei o nome da lista `l` para algo um pouco melhor - apesar de parecer besteira, [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad) (ainda mais quando esse nome é `l`, que dependendo da fonte usada, pode ser facilmente confundido com `1`, `I` ou `|`).

Comment: hkotsubo, muitíssimo obrigado pela gentileza de me explicar. Realmente, agora tudo ficou claro. Mais uma vez, muito obrigado!