# Como alinhar saídas do comando print utilizando f strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Seja o código abaixo que funciona:

```
arquivo = open("usuarios.txt","r")
leitura = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()
#print(leitura)


def converte_megabytes(bytes):
    return int(bytes) / 2 ** 20

def percentual(mega):
    mega = int(mega)
    total_espaço = 0
    for i in range(len(leitura)):
    #print(leitura[i].split()[1])
        total_espaço += int(leitura[i].split()[1])

    return f'{100*mega/total_espaço:.2f}'

def espaçoTotal():
    total_espaço = 0
    for i in range(len(leitura)):
        # print(leitura[i].split()[1])
        total_espaço += int(leitura[i].split()[1])
        total_espaço_mega = converte_megabytes(total_espaço)
    return total_espaço_mega


#print(percentual(456123789))

#print(f'{"Nr."}  {"Usuário"}      {"Espaço utilizado"}     {"% do uso"}')
print(f'{"ACME INC.":^60}')
print(f'{"RELATÓRIO DE USO DE ESPAÇO EM DISCO PELOS USUÁRIOS":^60}')
print('-' * 70)
print("Nr." + 'USUÁRIO' + ' '*19 + 'ESPAÇO USADO' + ' '*16 + '  % USO')
print('-' * 70)
for i in range(len(leitura)):
    print(f"{i+1} {leitura[i].split()[0]}       {converte_megabytes(leitura[i].split()[1]):^10.2f}MB        {percentual(leitura[i].split()[1]):^10}%")

print(f"\nEspaço total ocupado {espaçoTotal():.2f} MB")
print(f"Espaço médio ocupado {espaçoTotal()/len(leitura):.2f} MB")
```

O arquivo usuarios.txt (valores em bytes):

```
alexandre       456123789
anderson        1245698456
antonio         123456456
carlos          91257581
cesar           987458
rosemary        789456125
```

O único problema é saída que não consigo alinhar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deixar tudo alinhado na saída usando as f-strings (padrão `print(f"")`) ?

Comment: Para uma solução assim, onde tem que alinhar os elementos, seria eficaz utilizar a biblioteca Pandas. Posso enviar a solução aqui utilizando o Pandas ?

Comment: @Kaique Nakao pode sim! Agradeço> nao entendo pq negativaram a pergunta...

Comment: Este código deve dar conta do que você precisa. a sintaxe é :(caractere a ser repetido)<^> são os alinhamentos (< esquerda ^ centro > direita) e 16 são o número total de caracteres que sua linha deve ter.
:[preencher][alinhar][largura].[precisão] exemplo:    print("{0:*<16}".format(f"Espaço médio ocupado {espaçoTotal()/len(leitura):.2f} MB"))

Comment: @Gabriel Mendes   nao  entendi bem. tem como digitar como resposta?

Comment: Evite fazer o alinhamento usando o caractere espaço. Veja esse exemplo: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/relatoriotabulado

Comment: coloquei uma resposta usando `.format()` ao invés de fstrings. Espero que não seja um problema. o format está presente no python pelo menos desde as versões 2.7 e 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para processar e consolidar dados (como parece ser a ideia, já que você está calculando o total, porcentagens, média, etc), claro que você dispor de uma biblioteca como o Pandas, conforme já sugerido em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/529071/112052).

Mas para um arquivo tão pequeno e com estrutura tão simples, não precisaria disso. Dá para resolver com estruturas e funções nativas sem problema.

Primeiro, você pode calcular o total enquanto lê o arquivo. Da forma que você fez, dá muitas voltas: primeiro lê todo o arquivo, depois para cada linha você percorre todas elas para calcular o total, e esse total é recalculado toda vez para cada linha, quando você percorre os dados para imprimi-los (aliás, tem uma função para calcular o total, e a outra que, ao calcular o percentual, também calcula o total de novo). Não precisa disso: calcule o total apenas uma vez, e já aproveite para deixar os dados pré-processados (em vez de ficar chamando `split` toda hora, outra redundância desnecessária). Algo assim:

```py
def converte_megabytes(size_in_bytes):
    return int(size_in_bytes) / 2 ** 20

dados = []
total = 0
with open("usuarios.txt","r") as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo: # para cada linha do arquivo
        nome, espaco = linha.split()
        espaco = converte_megabytes(espaco)
        # insere uma tupla, contendo o nome e o espaço em MB
        dados.append((nome, espaco))
        total += espaco
```

Ou seja, para cada linha do arquivo eu chamo `split` apenas uma vez (ao invés de chamar toda hora, como você estava fazendo) e já converto o espaço ocupado em MB (pois me parece que você não está em nenhum momento usando os valores originais em bytes). Depois, insiro na lista uma tupla contendo o nome e o espaço. Assim, a lista já terá os dados no formato que preciso, e não precisarei converter toda hora (eu prefiro assim, a menos, é claro, que você precise guardar a linha inteira da forma que está no arquivo).

E repare que já vou calculando o total no mesmo *loop*, assim não preciso recalculá-lo várias vezes.

E também usei `with`, [que garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052).

Depois, para formatar, basta usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) para alinhar à esquerda ou direita, conforme a necessidade. E para deixar mais flexível, você pode definir os tamanhos de cada coluna e usá-las no próprio formato. Assim:

```py
def formatar(dados, total, cols_sizes):
    # cabeçalho (usa os tamanhos das colunas)
    formato_cabecalho = '{:{col1_size}} {:<{col2_size}} {:>{col3_size}} {:>{col4_size}}'
    print(f'{"RELATÓRIO DE USO DE ESPAÇO EM DISCO PELOS USUÁRIOS":^60}')
    print('-' * 70)
    print(formato_cabecalho.format('Nr.', 'USUÁRIO', 'ESPAÇO USADO', '% USO', **cols_sizes))
    print('-' * 70)

    # os dados desta coluna tem tamanho menor, para acomodar o " MB" depois
    cols_sizes['col3_size_data'] = cols_sizes['col3_size'] - 3
    # dados (usa os mesmos tamanhos das colunas, exceto na coluna 3, que deve acomodar o " MB")
    formato_dados = '{:>{col1_size}} {:<{col2_size}} {:>{col3_size_data}.2f} MB {:>{col4_size}.2%}'
    for i, (nome, espaco) in enumerate(dados, start=1):
        print(formato_dados.format(i, nome, espaco, espaco / total, **cols_sizes))

    print(f"\nEspaço total ocupado {total:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Espaço médio ocupado {total / len(dados):.2f} MB")

# formatar os dados, mude o tamanho das colunas conforme a necessidade
formatar(dados, total, { 'col1_size': 3, 'col2_size': 26, 'col3_size': 20, 'col4_size': 10 })
```

Ou seja, eu uso um dicionário contendo os tamanhos de cada coluna. Assim fica mais flexível e também mais fácil de alterar conforme a necessidade. Claro que você também pode usar tamanhos fixos, só ficará mais difícil para mudar (pois aí você tem que mudar no cabeçalho e nos dados).

Para cada coluna eu uso `<` ou `>`, que alinham respectivamente à esquerda e à direita (conforme [esta tabela](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#index-3)), usando o tamanho informado e preenchendo com espaços.

E repare que para porcentagem posso usar o formato `%`, assim nem precisa multiplicar por 100.

A saída é:

```
     RELATÓRIO DE USO DE ESPAÇO EM DISCO PELOS USUÁRIOS     
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Nr. USUÁRIO                            ESPAÇO USADO      % USO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 alexandre                             434.99 MB     16.85%
  2 anderson                             1187.99 MB     46.02%
  3 antonio                               117.74 MB      4.56%
  4 carlos                                 87.03 MB      3.37%
  5 cesar                                   0.94 MB      0.04%
  6 rosemary                              752.88 MB     29.16%

Espaço total ocupado 2581.58 MB
Espaço médio ocupado 430.26 MB
```

---

Se for com *f-strings*, exige uma pequena adaptação, mas ainda sim dá para usar os tamanhos das colunas como parâmetros:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def formatar(dados, total, cols_sizes):
    col1_size, col2_size, col3_size, col4_size = itemgetter('col1_size', 'col2_size', 'col3_size', 'col4_size')(cols_sizes)

    # cabeçalho (usa os tamanhos das colunas)
    print(f'{"RELATÓRIO DE USO DE ESPAÇO EM DISCO PELOS USUÁRIOS":^60}')
    print('-' * 70)
    print(f'{"Nr.":{col1_size}} {"USUÁRIO":<{col2_size}} {"ESPAÇO USADO":>{col3_size}} {"% USO":>{col4_size}}')
    print('-' * 70)

    # dados (usa os mesmos tamanhos das colunas, exceto na coluna 3, que deve acomodar o " MB")
    for i, (nome, espaco) in enumerate(dados, start=1):
        print(f'{i:>{col1_size}} {nome:<{col2_size}} {espaco:>{col3_size - 3}.2f} MB {espaco / total:>{col4_size}.2%}')

    print(f"\nEspaço total ocupado {total:.2f} MB")
    print(f"Espaço médio ocupado {total / len(dados):.2f} MB")

# a forma de chamar a função é a mesma
formatar(dados, total, { 'col1_size': 3, 'col2_size': 26, 'col3_size': 20, 'col4_size': 10 })
```

Comment: realmente usar o pandas para fazer esse alinhamento, e basicamente matar formiga com uma bazooka

Answer (score 3):

### DataFrame do Pandas

Um jeito eficaz para alinhar saídas seria utilizando a função DataFrame da biblioteca do Pandas. Essa função trabalha com dados tabulares bidimensionais, com tamanho mutável e potencialmente heterogêneos. Com o DataFrame também é capaz de calcular a média e a soma das linhas/colunas, deixando mais prático na hora de obter o espaço total ocupado e o espaço médio.

### Requerimento

Para utilizar a biblioteca Pandas, primeiramente tem que instalar ela utilizando o seguinte comando no terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```

### Arquivo importado

utilizarei o comando read_csv do Pandas para importar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Código

```
import pandas as pd

obj = pd.read_csv('usuarios.txt', names=['Nr.', 'ESPAÇO USADO (MB)', '% USO'], sep='\s+')

obj.index += 1 # Começa do índice 1
converter_mb = lambda dado: round((dado / 2 ** 20), 2) # Função para converter para MB

obj['ESPAÇO USADO (MB)'] = obj['ESPAÇO USADO (MB)'].apply(converter_mb) # Aplicando a função
total_ocupado = obj['ESPAÇO USADO (MB)'].sum()
obj['% USO'] = round((obj['ESPAÇO USADO (MB)'] * 100) / total_ocupado, 2)

print(f'{"ACME INC.":^50}')
print(f'{"RELATÓRIO DE USO DE ESPAÇO EM DISCO PELOS USUÁRIOS":^30}\n')

print(obj)
print(f'\nEspaço total ocupado: {total_ocupado:.2f} MB')
print(f'Espaço médio ocupado: {obj["ESPAÇO USADO (MB)"].mean():.2f} MB')
```

### Resultado

Após rodar o código de cima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o problema é que teríamos que modificar o arquivo original. A ideia é formatar sem alterar o arquivo...

Comment: Editei a pergunta: O arquivo original nao é separado por vírgulas...

Comment: Pronto, alterei o código e o arquivo

Comment: Obrigado. tem alguma solucao sem pandas?

Comment: Sim, tenta utilizar o código que eu postei neste site http://codepad.org/v1kraSwA

Comment: Se for pra usar o pandas, ele tem uma função DataFrame.to_string que automaticamente gera essas coisas alinhadas. Não seria mais prático?

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer o alinhamento correto o melhor é você montar suas strings usando o [pyformat](https://pyformat.info), que é nativo do python. Por exemplo, no seu código você usa:

```
print("Nr." + 'USUÁRIO' + ' '*19 + 'ESPAÇO USADO' + ' '*16 + '  % USO')
```

o texto `Nr.USUÁRIO` mais os 19 espaços em branco ocupam 28 espaços. Então você quer que o número mais o nome do usuário ocupem 28 espaços. Vamos dizer que sejam 3 espaços pro número, um espaço vazio e o nome, podendo ocupar 24 espaços. Com o pyformat isso fica `'{:3} {:24}'.format(i+1, leitura[i].split()[0])`. O que esse código diz é que o `i+1` vai entrar no lugar do primeiro colchete ocupando 3 espaços enquanto o valor de `leitura[i].split()[0]` vai entrar no segundo colchete ocupando 24 espaços. Detalhe importante é que números inteiros alinham pela direita e string pela esquerda. Então o output seria como

`1 Alexandre`

Se você quiser que o 1 seja alinhado pela direita, você precisa usar `{:<3}. E a resposta seria

`1   Alexandre`

Colocando todos os elementos uma solução pro seu problema seria:

```
string = '{:<3} {:24} {:9.2f} MB {:20.2f} %'.format(i+1, leitura[i].split()[0], leitura[i].split()[1], percentual(leitura[i].split()[1]))
print(string)
```

O outuput é:

```
Nr.USUÁRIO                   ESPAÇO USADO                  % USO
1   alexandre                   434.99 MB                16.85 %
...
```

Existem muitas outras opções e eu acho que fica mais bonito e prático com a unidade no cabeçalho ao invés de logo depois do número, mas isso é gosto pessoal.