# Erro: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, return, ado.net

Gostaria de entender porque meu código está gerando o erro

> not all code paths return a value

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class painel : Form
    {
        public painel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class componente
        {
            public int ID
            {
                get { return ID; }
                set { ID = value; }
            }

            private string nome;
            public string NOME
            {
                get { return nome; }
                set { nome = value; }
            }

            private string local_armazenamento;
            public string LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO
            {
                get { return local_armazenamento; }
                set { local_armazenamento = value; }
            }

            private string descricao;
            public string DESCRICAO
            {
                get { return descricao; }
                set { descricao = value; }
            }
        }

        private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
        {
            MySqlConnection caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
            List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
            caminho.Open();

            MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (leitor.HasRows)
            {
                while (leitor.Read())
                {
                    componente componente = new componente();

                    componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
                    componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
                    componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
                    componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
                    lista.Add(componente);
                }
                caminho.Close();
                return lista;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ObterLista(button1.Text);
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ObterLista(button1.Text);
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Return dentro do try… catch não funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48028/3635)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Porque nem todos os caminhos de execução retornam um valor esperado. Note que o único `return` existe neste código está dentro de um `if`, portanto ele só será executado condicionalmente. O que acontece se o código não entrar no `if`? Ele retorna alguma coisa? O código não diz para retornar alguma coisa. Tirando o `return` do `if` resolve o problema.

A lista ficará vazia, precisa tratar isso onde for consumir este método.

```
private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente) {
    var caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
    List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM componentes ", caminho);
    caminho.Open();
    MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (leitor.HasRows) {
        while (leitor.Read()) {
            componente componente = new componente();
            componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
            componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
            componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
            componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
            lista.Add(componente);
        }
        caminho.Close();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/ReturnResult.cs).

## Fundamentando minha escolha

Não tem porque ter um `else` em um código que retornará a mesma coisa que está dentro do `if`. Sempre que você tem dois códigos iguais um dentro do `if` e o outro dentro do `else` não tem porque duplicar o código, tire ambos do `if` e `else` e elimine a redundância.

Não não tem porque ter o `return` nem dentro do `else`, que nem precisa existir, nem dentro do `if`, porque aconteça o que acontecer `return lista` precisaria ser retornado.

Também não me parece ser bom retornar nulo. Pelo menos nada na pergunta indica que isto é desejável. Se fosse o caso seria melhor não inicializar a lista (`List<componente> list;`) no início, apenas inicializar dentro `if`, assim novamente só precisaria retornar a lista uma vez no código.

O `else` só está aumentando a [complexidade ciclomática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193665/101) sem ganho algum.

Além de eliminar a redundância pode estar contribuindo para o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), assim o `return` fica mais canônico.

Tem formas [mais simples de fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149348/101) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101)) todo o código e com [estilo melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101). Esse código terá problemas se houver uma exceção no meio da operação. [Veja como deve ser](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101).

Comment: É, de fato é isso mesmo, valeu aí. Mas agora surgiram mais problemas no código, mas isso aqui eu resolvo, obg

Comment: Eu imaginei que surgiriam, me desculpe, mas este código está bem mal escrito. Você pode postar perguntas específicas para cada erro, mas vai demorar para resolver tudo porque me parece que te falta a base.

Comment: Falta muita base, estou aprendendo a programar sozinho

Comment: @Igor procure aprender de uma forma estruturada. Se ficar como barata tonta procurando uma solução para cada problema que aparece você não vai aprender, vai só apagar incêndio. Você tem que entender o porquê de cada vírgula, cada espaço, cada palavra no código.

Answer (score 14):

Seu código precisa retornar um valor para **Todos** os casos, na sua classe ObterLista isto não acontece, quando o código entra na condição *IF* ele tem um *return*, mas para o caso de não entrar(*Else*) ele não retorna nada, oque gera a exceção, basta adicionar um *Else* que retorne um valor(uma lista nula por exemplo, mas lembre-se de tratar este valor para não gerar erros no restante do código)

```
private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
{
    MySqlConnection caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
    List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
    caminho.Open();

    MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (leitor.HasRows)
    {
        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            componente componente = new componente();
            componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
            componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
            componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
            componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
            lista.Add(componente);
        }
        caminho.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        //Trata valor a ser retornado
    }

 return lista;

}
```

Caso não seja necessário um tratamento especifico para a lista nula, basta não utilizar o Else, trocando

```
    }
    else
    {
        //Trata valor a ser retornado
    }

return lista;
```

por

```
}
return lista;
```

Evitando redundâncias desnecessárias e tendo sempre um retorno do método.

Answer (score 11):

Por causa disso:

```
        if (leitor.HasRows)
        {
            while (leitor.Read())
            {
                componente componente = new componente();

                componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
                componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
                componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
                componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
                lista.Add(componente);
            }
            caminho.Close();
            return lista;
        }
```

Se `leitor` não tiver linhas, nada é retornado. Após o `if`, coloque um `return null;` que deve resolver.

Answer (score 10):

Você só está retornando a lista no método ObterLista, se entrar no  if (leitor.HasRows), se não entra, ainda assim o método deve retornar algo. Segue alteração no código:

```
    private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
    {
        MySqlConnection caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
        List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
        caminho.Open();

        MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (leitor.HasRows)
        {
            while (leitor.Read())
            {
                componente componente = new componente();

                componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
                componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
                componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
                componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
                lista.Add(componente);
            }
            caminho.Close();
            return lista;
        }
        else return lista;

    }
```

Comment: Se o retorno do else é o mesmo do if, não precisa criar um else, pode deixar o "return lista" fora do if, economiza umas linhas de código e evita redundância.

Answer (score 9):

Ocorre porque o método ObterLista não está retornando resultado quando leitor.HasRows é igual a falso. Altere para:

```
private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
    {
        MySqlConnection caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
        List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
        caminho.Open();

        MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (leitor.HasRows)
        {
            while (leitor.Read())
            {
                componente componente = new componente();

                componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
                componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
                componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
                componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
                lista.Add(componente);
            }
            caminho.Close();
            return lista;
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Na assinatura do seu método, você diz que ele retorna uma lista de Componente.

Tente colocar a instrução de `return` fora do `if`.

Código:

```
private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
{
    MySqlConnection caminho = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
    List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
    caminho.Open();

    MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (leitor.HasRows)
    {
        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            componente componente = new componente();

            componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
            componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
            componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
            componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
            lista.Add(componente);
        }
        caminho.Close();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Tente colocar a instrução de return fora do `if`.

```
private List<componente> ObterLista(string nome_componente)
{
    MySqlConnection caminho = 
    new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");

    List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
    caminho.Open();

    MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (leitor.HasRows)
    {
        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            componente componente = new componente();

            componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
            componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
            componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
            componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
            lista.Add(componente);
        }
        caminho.Close();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List ObterLista(string nome_componente)
{
    MySqlConnection caminho = 
    new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER=LOCALHOST;DATABASE=portfolio;UID=root;PASSWORD=vertrigo");
```

`List<componente> lista = new List<componente>();
string query = "SELECT * FROM componentes ";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, caminho);
caminho.Open();

MySqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (leitor.HasRows)
{
    while (leitor.Read())
    {
        componente componente = new componente();

        componente.ID = Convert.ToInt32(leitor["id"]);
        componente.NOME = leitor["nome"].ToString();
        componente.LOCAL_ARMAZENAMENTO = leitor["local_armazenamento"].ToString();
        componente.DESCRICAO = leitor["descricao"].ToString();
        lista.Add(componente);
    }
    caminho.Close();
}
return lista;`

}

Comment: Qual o objetivo desta resposta?