# Qual o melhor método para exceções?

Tags: java, android, exceção

Qual o melhor método para pegar exceções em um app Android, tipo `try/catch`, `throws` ou `throw`.

Exceções tipo, campos que o usuário deixou em branco em um formulário.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 7):

Não existe melhor "método" para capturar exceções, existe só uma forma:

```
try {
    //faz coisas aqui
} catch (SpecificException ex) {
    //faz algo para se recuperar da falha ou indicar o erro em log ou tela
    // só entrar aqui se uma exceção deste tipo ou derivada dela for lançada no bloco try
}
```

É possível ter vários `catch`, sendo que sempre deve [capturar as exceções mais específicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30124/101) primeiro e as mais genéricas depois. Evite capturar `Exception` em qualquer lugar. Normalmente ela deve ser a última medida quando tudo falhou.

Também é possível [usar `finally`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42313/101) para garantir que algo seja executado independente de ter sido lançada um exceção ou não. Normalmente é usado para encerrar algum recurso aberto, como banco de dados. [Mais sobre isto em C# que é a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16065/101).

```
try {
    //faz coisas aqui
} catch (SpecificException ex) {
    //faz algo para se recuperar da falha ou indicar o erro em log ou tela
    // só entrar aqui se uma exceção deste tipo ou derivada dela for lançada no bloco try
} catch (OtherSpecificException ex) {
    //faz algo para se recuperar da falha ou indicar o erro em log ou tela
    // só entrar aqui se uma exceção deste tipo ou derivada dela for lançada no bloco try
} catch (SpecificPeroNoMuchoException ex) {
    //faz algo para se recuperar da falha ou indicar o erro em log ou tela
    // só entrar aqui se uma exceção deste tipo ou derivada dela for lançada no bloco try
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //Indicar o erro em log ou tela
    // só entrar aqui se uma exceção deste tipo ou derivada dela for lançada no bloco try
} finally {
    //aqui executa no final lançando exceção ou não
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Exception/Cascade.java).

Mas dá para [evitar o uso de exceções em muitos casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48379/101). Não capture exceções que são geradas por erros de programação. Conserte o erro. Eu acho lamentável que a resposta naquela pergunta que faz isto tenha quase o mesmo número de votos que a resposta (a minha) que resolve o problema sem deixar a exceção ocorrer. Não use exceções para dizer que o usuário deixou o campo em branco. Isto é [validação e não exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15261/101). Existem [outras formas para se evitar a exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/101). No geral, exceções devem ser apenas em casos excepcionais e não controlar o fluxo normal do programa. Para isto existe o `if`.

Pense antes de capturar um exceção, não capture se não tiver certeza que pode fazer algo útil ali. Tenha uma captura geral para pegar tudo quando esqueceu de capturar algo mais específico em local mais específico.

[Veja exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44501/101).

`throw` serve para lançar a exceção e `throws` para marcar um método que existe uma exceção ali e que ela precisa ser capturada. [Saiba mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17025/101).

[Mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/101). Ou procure na [*tag* sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Answer (score 2):

Para você validar campos não preenchidos, você não vai conseguir fazer isto com `try catch` porque o campo vazio não vai gerar uma exceção.

Use o seguinte comanda para verificar se o campo está vazio:

```
if (myEditText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
  // CAMPO ESTÁ VAZIO
}
```

Ou:

```
if (myEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
  // CAMPO ESTÁ VAZIO
}
```

Ou:

```
if (myEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
  // CAMPO ESTÁ VAZIO
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo :D
Tbm sou novo em em programação e estou focando em Android
no projeto que eu to fazendo agr eu usei o "if" que funciona como o função "SE" do excel. Vc da uma condição e ele faz algo se verdadeira, e se falso faça outra coisa
ex:

```
    if(condição){  
    //Codigo se for verdadeiro  
    } else {  
    //codigo se falso  
    }
```

oque eu fiz verifica campos vazios e ficou

```
    if (etA.gettext().toString().equals(""){   //verifica se o campo é vazio  
    //codigo do programa  
    } else { //se falso  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), “Preencha o campo vazio”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Só precisa trocar de lugar o toast, que no seu caso tem que ficar no if e não no else.